# Intersecting graphics

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, geometry, boolean-computation

Does the *Mathematica* graphics system have any concept of intersecting graphics? I've not found much in the documents so far. For example, if I want to show the intersection of two shapes:

```
Graphics[{Rectangle[], Disk[{0.2, 0}, .5]}]
```

[image: graphics without intersection]

I know I can use `Opacity`:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.8], Red, Rectangle[], Green, Disk[{0.2, 0}, .5]}]
```

[image: graphic with intersection]

But is there a way of specifying the colours of intersecting areas directly? It doesn't seem to be possible to 'address' the intersecting shapes any other way.

In the same vein, is is possible to 'extract' the graphical intersection of arbitrary shapes, without returning to the original geometry and calculating it? Could you obtain this type of entity easily given the above specification (these are just examples...!):

[image: the intersection]

I think it might be easier with raster images, but am interested for now in vector graphics.

Comment: Updated my answer to avoid accusations of "just posting links" ;-)

Comment: This will most likely come with M9: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCTa904eRfM&list=PLCD1C4A44DFA4D7C6&index=11&feature=plpp_video

Comment: Nice video  - I like his work. Hope the upgrade is cheap...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about `RegionPlot`?

```
RegionPlot[
  {
   (x - 0.2)^2 + y^2 < 0.5 && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1,
   (x - 0.2)^2 + y^2 < 0.5 && ! (0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1),
   ! ((x - 0.2)^2 + y^2 < 0.5) && 0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1
  }, 
   {x, -1, 1.5}, {y, -1, 1.5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Blue}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT** in response to Szabolcs's comment:

```
PointInPoly[{x_, y_}, poly_List] := 
 Module[{i, j, c = False, npol = Length[poly]}, 
  For[i = 1; j = npol, i <= npol, j = i++, 
   If[((((poly[[i, 2]] <= y) && (y < 
             poly[[j, 2]])) || ((poly[[j, 2]] <= y) && (y < 
             poly[[i, 2]]))) && (x < (poly[[j, 1]] - 
             poly[[i, 1]])*(y - poly[[i, 2]])/(poly[[j, 2]] - 
              poly[[i, 2]]) + poly[[i, 1]])), c = ¬ c];];
  c]
```

(from an answer I gave in [MathGroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/7bf0c7c21b8d916a/c1bbce770899082f?lnk=gst&q=sjoerd%20point%20in%20poly#c1bbce770899082f))

```
RegionPlot[{
   PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, -1}, {3, -3}}] && 
   PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {0, 0}}], 
   PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, -1}, {3, -3}}] &&
   ¬ PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {0, 0}}],
   ¬ PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, -1}, {3, -3}}] &&
   PointInPoly[{x, y}, {{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {0, 0}}]}, 
  {x, 0, 6}, {y, -4, 8}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Blue}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `RegionPlot` is cool, thanks. If you know the equations for the graphics, it's ideal.

Answer (score 36):

I'm coming to the party a bit late, but here's my approach. It should work for any two polygons, including non-convex and self-intersecting ones.

```
winding[poly_, pt_] := 
 Round[(Total@
      Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
       2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)]
cross[e1_, e2_] /; (N[Det[{Subtract @@ e1, Subtract @@ e2}]] === 0.) =
   None;
cross[e1_, e2_] := Module[{params},
   params = ((e2[[2]] - 
        e1[[2]]).Inverse[{Subtract @@ e1, -(Subtract @@ e2)}]);
   If[And @@ Thread[0 <= params <= 1], 
    Subtract @@ e1 params[[1]] + e1[[2]],
    None]];

intersection[poly1_, poly2_, p : {in1_, in2_} : {1, 1}] := 
  Module[{edges1, edges2, intersections,
    inter1, inter2, newedges1, newedges2, midpoints1, midpoints2},
   edges1 = Partition[Range[Length[poly1]], 2, 1, {1, 1}];
   edges2 = Partition[Range[Length[poly2]], 2, 1, {1, 1}];

   intersections = Table[cross[poly1[[e1]], poly2[[e2]]],
     {e1, edges1}, {e2, edges2}];
   inter1 = Flatten[Table[
      SortBy[
       Prepend[DeleteCases[intersections[[i]], None], poly1[[i]]], 
       Norm[# - poly1[[i]]] &], {i, Length[edges1]}], 1];
   inter2 = 
    Flatten[Table[
      SortBy[Prepend[DeleteCases[intersections[[All, i]], None], 
        poly2[[i]]], Norm[# - poly2[[i]]] &], {i, Length[edges2]}], 1];

   newedges1 = Partition[inter1, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
   newedges2 = Partition[inter2, 2, 1, {1, 1}];

   midpoints1 = Mean /@ newedges1;
   midpoints2 = Mean /@ newedges2;
   Flatten[{Pick[newedges1, Abs[winding[poly2, #]] & /@ midpoints1, 
       in1],
      Pick[newedges2, Abs[winding[poly1, #]] & /@ midpoints2, in2]}, 
     1] //.
    {{a___, {b__, c_List}, d___, {c_, e__}, 
       f___} :> {a, {b, c, e}, d, f},
     {a___, {b__, c_List}, d___, {e__, c_}, f___} :> {a, 
       Join[{b, c}, Reverse[{e}]], d, f},
     {a___, {c_List, b__}, d___, {c_, e__}, f___} :> {a, 
       Join[Reverse[{e}], {c, b}], d, f},
     {a___, {c_List, b__}, d___, {e__, c_}, f___} :> {a, {e, c, b}, d,
        f}
     }
   ];
```

**Some notes**

`winding` and `cross` are two helper functions. `winding` calculates the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of a point `pt` with respect to a polygon `poly` given as a list of vertex coordinates. A point lies inside a polygon if and only if the winding number is non-zero.

The function `cross` calculates the intersection point of two line segments, or returns `None` if they don't intersect.

`intersection` is the main function which calculates the intersecting polygon of two polygons `poly1` and `poly2`. It works by calculating the intersection points between the two polygons and adding these to the vertex lists of `poly1` and `poly2`. Then each of the edges of the new polygons lie either completely inside or outside of the other polygon.

The intersection of the two polygons $\text{poly1} \cap \text{poly2}$ is then the union of edges of `poly1` that lie inside `poly2` and vice versa. Similarly one can also calculate the complement of the two polygons, $\text{poly1} \backslash \text{poly2}$ and $\text{poly1} \backslash \text{poly2}$, and the union $\text{poly1} \cup \text{poly2}$. These four options can be set by `in1` and `in2`.

**Example**

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{ips11, ips10, ips01},
  pts = PadRight[pts, 2 n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2 n, 2}]];
  ips11 = intersection[pts[[ ;; n]], pts[[n + 1 ;;]], {1, 1}];
  ips10 = intersection[pts[[ ;; n]], pts[[n + 1 ;;]], {1, 0}];
  ips01 = intersection[pts[[ ;; n]], pts[[n + 1 ;;]], {0, 1}];
  Graphics[{
    {Yellow, Polygon[ips10]},
    {Blue, Polygon[ips01]},
    {Red, Polygon[ips11]},
    {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[pts[[ ;; n]]]}, {FaceForm[], 
     EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[pts[[n + 1 ;;]]]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]], 
  {{pts, {}}, Locator}, {{n, 5}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If this really works as indicated it needs to hit "Good Answer" status.

Comment: The `ReplaceRepeated` part looks potentially slow.  Have you tested this with largish polygons yet?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I haven't tried larger polygons yet. I agree about the `ReplaceRepeated` but it's the best I could come up with for now. If you know about a better way to join a set of edges I would be interested.

Comment: Honestly I cannot even tell what your code is doing yet.  It must have been a lot of work putting it together.  Some time later I shall work through it and see what possible improvements come to mind.  If I don't get around to it in the next couple of days please remind me.

Comment: If I am right, there is a bug with the winding function: in the `Map` it should be `If[pt == #, 0, ArcTan @@ (pt - #)]` as `ArcTan[0, 0]` is indeterminate. See this example of two intersecting triangles: `intersection[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 
   0}, {-1, Sqrt[3]}}, {1, 1}]`. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Heike I think the major drawback is the (lack of) handling of disconnected polygons in the form of `Polygon[{{{1, Sqrt[3]}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, {{-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/
   2}, {-1, Sqrt[3]}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}}]`. This quickly leads to a combinatorial explosion when one has to check each subpart in `poly1` with every other in `poly2`, if there is no pretesting for whether two polys are touching or not. Also, it leaves some redundant coordinates in the result like `{{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}}`. Of course, this might be useful for the user, but there should be some means to remove them.

Comment: The winding number routine can be improved slightly, by making use of `ListCorrelate[]`: `windingNumber[poly_?MatrixQ, pt_?VectorQ] := Round[Total @ Mod[ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly, {-1, -1}], 2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi]`

Answer (score 17):

The (undocumented!) function `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[] `` (`` Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection[] `` in older versions) seems up to the task. Using Sjoerd's example:

```
polys = {Polygon[{{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 7}, {5, -1}, {3, -3}}],
         Polygon[{{2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {0, 0}}]};

Graphics[Append[{Gray, polys}, {Blue, Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[polys]}]]
```

[image: intersecting polygons]

`Disk[]` objects are not covered by this method, but it is not too difficult to make a `Polygon[]` that approximates a `Disk[]`...

Comment: Sooner or later we will use more undocumented functions than documented ones... Very useful, +1.

Comment: Note that the intersection here is returned as multiple triangles. A single polygon can be obtained by using the option `AllTriangles->False`

Comment: ...or use `PolygonCombine[]` on the output of `PolygonIntersection[]`.

Comment: Please note that with my Mathematica 10.1 version I had to use Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`PolygonIntersection and that the function just works for 2D polygons (not for 3D ones).

Answer (score 14):

I am not aware of any built-in functionality (I might easily be wrong), but there's an example at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonIntersection.html) for calculating intersections of convex polygons.  You'd need to approximate the circle with a polygon.

Get the [notebook](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComputationalGeometry/PolygonIntersection.nb) from that page: there's an intersection calculation inside that uses the [IMTEK Mathematica supplement](http://simulation.uni-freiburg.de/downloads/ims).

Example:

```
<< Imtek`Polygon`

disk = Disk[{0.2, 0}, 0.5];
rec = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];

Graphics[{Green, rec, Red, disk, Blue, 
  Polygon@imsConvexIntersect[{imsPolygonizeCircle[Circle @@ disk, 50],
      First[rec]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for the IMTEK Mathematica Supplement - I could not resist ;-)

Comment: To use the convex intersection algorithm from the IMS, you'd need to appriximate version of the circle.

Comment: @ruebenko why isn't that in your profile?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, well I don't really have time to update and maintain this; would you like to have a go with that ;-) The IMS needs a new place to live, and should be renames to International Mathematica Supplement (them the ims prefix for the functions can stay). Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @ruebenko only if I get paid. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you will get payed in honor, and real reputation ;-)

Comment: @ruebenko why not put it in the Wolfram Library Archive? This place seems to have been all but forgotten (by both users *and* WRI) but seems like the place for a repository.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, that's a possibility. I have not made up my mind. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use image processing features such as [ImageCompose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCompose.html):

```
{
 g1 = Graphics[Rectangle[], PlotRange -> 1],
 g2 = Graphics[Disk[{0.2, 0}, .5], PlotRange -> 1],
 ImageCompose[g1, g2, Center, Center, {1, 1, 0}]
 }
```

The output of the above looks like this:

[image]

(Note that in this case your Graphics get rasterized and the result is an Image.)

Comment: Thanks - it's definitely easier with images sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

In version 10, the new [geometric computation functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html) supports this.  It operates with region objects.  Many graphics primitives, including `Disk` and `Rectangle` can be used as regions.

[Boolean operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) include `RegionUnion`, `RegionIntersect`, `RegionDifference`, `RegionSymmetricDifference` and `BooleanRegion`.

Example:

```
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[Rectangle[], Disk[{0.2, 0}, .5]], AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

[image]

In many cases these Boolean operators do not evaluate. `RegionIntersection[Rectangle[], Disk[{0.2, 0}, .5]]` can be used as a region, but it does not evaluate to another expression.  However, it is possible to get an *approximation* to the result, free of any explicit Boolean expressions, using `DiscretizeRegion`.  It is then possible to extract coordinates (e.g. the boundary) from this discretized mesh.

Answer (score 7):

You may be able to do this using [FilledCurve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html?q=FilledCurve) in version 8.  I see examples of subtraction and exclusion but not intersection.

[image]