# Packed Graph or GraphPlot output with non-square layout?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, packing

Graph or GraphPlot produce square layouts for disconnected graphs:

```
Graph[Table[i -> Mod[i^3, 100], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I´d like to get a rectangular layout with e.g. aspect ratio 1/2,
preferably in combination with the `PackingMethod ->
"ClosestPackingCenter"` option. Setting `AspectRatio` does not do what I want, because the graph is only rescaled/distorted and not redrawn on a rectanglular grid with said `AspectRatio.`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there a way to achieve something like this (emulated by a gridded copy of the first graph)?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Addition: Because of the added interactive graph functionality in newer versions, a solution leaving this functionality intact would be preferrable (and probably more compatible with future developments).

Comment: I asked this some time ago on [MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00241.html), but no luck there.

Comment: In the very worst case, you can implement your own packing method.  That's a lot of work, but Heike has implemented a pretty good packing algorithm [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/12) that can do non isotropic shapes.  I'd probably still take at least 30 minutes to understand the algorithm and adapt it to graphs.  Another idea is using nested boxes to pack them, but again---a lot of work.

Comment: I am rather hoping that I am not the only one with this desire and that someone will flourish an undocumented option to spare me the pain.

Comment: How did you work around it in the past?  Did you break the graph into two and showed them side by side?  That'd be a workable---if not pretty---solution.  (Yes, this is a very good question and there should be an option.)

Comment: Did not work around yet. It is more of a layout thing for presentations, slides and documents where a different aspect ratio is more pleasing and/or economical. Me wants a graph in Full HD on the big screen ;-)

Comment: Well, this technical question would profit too from the collision-detection required for [this artistic problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/how-to-create-word-clouds). It's a pity one cannot access the internal algorithm used by `Method -> "ClosestPackingCenter"`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, this is just a workaround.  Let's make a graph:

```
g = Graph@Table[i -> Mod[i^3, 300], {i, 1, 300}];
```

It looks like this:

```
GraphPlot[g, PackingMethod -> "ClosestPackingCenter"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's break it into two components, distributing connected components of similar sizes equally between the two:

```
cc = SortBy[ConnectedComponents@UndirectedGraph[g], Length];

c1 = Flatten[cc[[1 ;; ;; 2]]];
c2 = Flatten[cc[[2 ;; ;; 2]]];
```

Now let's show them size by side:

```
GraphicsRow[
 GraphPlot[Subgraph[g, #], PackingMethod -> "ClosestPackingCenter", 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0] & /@ {c1, c2},
 Spacings -> 0
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not perfect, but might be good enough for a paper or presentation.   This will only look good with the `ClosestPackingCenter` option but that is what you were asking for specifically.

---

Alternatively, you can use [Heike's packing algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/12).  I used the simplest version because it was faster, but you should use the updated version which produces vector images (it'll be a bit more work though).

```
images = ImageCrop@
     Rasterize[#, "Image", ImageSize -> 50, 
      ImageResolution -> 4 72] & /@ (GraphPlot[Subgraph[g, #], 
       PlotRangePadding -> 0] &) /@ Reverse[cc];

padimg = ImagePad[#, 5, White] & /@ images;

iteration[img1_, w_, fun_: (Norm[#1 - #2] &)] := 
 Module[{imdil, centre, diff, dimw, padding, padded1, minpos},
  dimw = ImageDimensions[w];
  padded1 = ImagePad[img1, {dimw[[1]] {1, 1}, dimw[[2]] {1, 1}}, 1];

  imdil = MaxFilter[Binarize[ColorNegate[padded1], 0.01], 
    Reverse@Floor[dimw/2 + 2]];
  centre = ImageDimensions[padded1]/2;

  minpos = Reverse@Nearest[Position[Reverse[ImageData[imdil]], 0], 
      Reverse[centre], DistanceFunction -> fun][[1]];
  diff = ImageDimensions[imdil] - dimw;
  padding[pos_] := Transpose[{#, diff - #} &@Round[pos - dimw/2]];

  ImagePad[#, (-Min[#] {1, 1 }) & /@ BorderDimensions[#]] &@
   ImageMultiply[padded1, ImagePad[w, padding[minpos], 1]]]

fun = Norm[{1, 1/2} (#2 - #1)] &;

Fold[iteration[##,fun]&, padimg[[1]], Rest[padimg]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Most of the code here is directly copied from her post.

---

If we make some effort to preserve sizes as well, we get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used this code to generate the images for this (with some manual tweaking):

```
plots = GraphPlot[Subgraph[g, #]] & /@ Reverse[cc];

images = ImageCrop@
     Image@Show[#, PlotRange -> 2.5 {{-0.1, 1}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
       ImageSize -> 100] & /@ plots;

padimg = ImagePad[#, 5, White] & /@ images;
```

Comment: It is especially for the papers that I tend to spend insane amounts of  time with twiddling to make it look really good - in blatant violaton of the [pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). Good idea to sort interleaving.

Comment: @Yves Here's and edit proving that Heike's packing code is applicable, but I didn't knead it into a reusable shape.  I just rasterized everything and slapped her method on it.

Answer (score 10):

You could start by getting a handle on the weakly connected graph components.

```
g = Graph[Table[i -> Mod[i^3, 100], {i, 1, 100}], 
          VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 15]

weaklyConnected = ConnectedComponents[UndirectedGraph[g]]
```

`GraphicsGrid` can arrange the components in a table.  `Spacings` allows allows you to set the approximate aspect ratio.  The following results in 8 graph components per row.

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
    Subgraph[g, #, 
      EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[{"CarvedArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .1}], 
      DirectedEdges -> True] & /@ weaklyConnected, 8], ImageSize -> 450,
      Spacings -> {Automatic, 150}]
```

[image: Graph components]

Below are 6 components per row, with `Spacings -> {150, 0}`:

[image: six components per row]