# Tiling a square

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, packing, puzzle

I wondered if there was a way to automate the process of finding a way to tile a tile into a square.

The idea is to represent the tile with a matrix of $0$s for blank space and $1$s for filled spaces like in $\{\{0,1,1\}, \{1,0,0\}\}$.

[image: The tile.]

The square (or a general rectangular area) is represented by an array as well.

The function should then have as arguments two lists (representing the tile and the area) and should find the ways (if they exist) to do the tiling.

This is quite an hard problem for me, I have tried playing with `Plus`, so that if the result matrix has $2$ it means that the tile overlaps while if it is $0$ there is a gap but I can't find a way to tell *Mathematica* that they should fit the area.

Comment: Here you have it http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_7.html

Comment: Man thanks so much!I'll read it now but at a first glance seems very useful. Thanks again!

Comment: @belisarius I think this is nice and should be posted as an asnwer

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Ok,  done. I usually don't post as an answer something that came up from a Google search ... but that also depends on how long it took me to find the answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [**this article**](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_7.html) the author solves the problem of tiling a rectangle by using pieces taken from a set of polyominoes, which are plane geometric figures formed by joining one or more equal squares edge to edge. For example, these are the pentaminoes, polyominoes formed by joining 5 squares:

[image]

Of course this problem is more difficult than the one you asked for, but it is also more interesting and ... there is Mathematica code in the article!

Comment: +1 Thank you for posting. I think that **Mathematica Journal** is great and people can find many gems there. I wish more people would read it.

Comment: Some time ago i had found that great resource,the *Mathematica Journal*,but my skills in Mathematica were really poor(and still they are :D)and so i eventually forgot it.Anyway i'm getting better and better and i think i'll start giving a deeper look to it.Thank you all for remembering me this great source!

Comment: +1 For letting me know about the existance of the Mathematica Journal.

Comment: @belisarius Tried the Mathematica Journal code, and it won't run.  Going through the issues with it show that the first line is unterminated, or...there is one undeclared variable "allPieces" that might have been meant to actually be "pieces" The function "tile" can not be included inside the module of the function "tess" because they both declare the same inputs.  Love these Journal articles, but I do wish they would post working code.  Does anyone have the actual code that runs? From all the errors in the article it's not clear exactly what is going to make it run.

Comment: @RHall I don't remember testing the code, and probably I didn't because I would posted a warning if it wasn't working. If you really want others looking into it I think a _"what is missing in this Mma journal code?"_ question could attract a lot of attention in this site

Comment: The Mathematica Journal article is no longer available through the link. I was able to get the notebook file by contacting the editor at editor@mathematica-journal.com.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelWijaya, this answer is no longer useful as the link is now dead and leads to a 404 error. *This illustrates the problem with link-only answers.*

Answer (score 32):

With some diffidence (because there appears to be a *Mathematica* bug: see below), I would like to offer an answer in the spirit of the OP's original attempt to solve the problem algebraically.

### Solution

**This problem can be formulated as a [binary integer linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns).**  The reformulation represents the square (or more generally, a rectangle as implemented below) as a vector.  Its coefficients represent occupancy: $0$ for empty, $1$ for full.  In this representation, every possible tile placement corresponds to a unique vector indicating the cells occupied by the tile.

Let's begin by generating the vectors corresponding to all possible placements of tiles in all possible orientations.  It will be convenient to specify as little as possible, beginning with a set of unique tile shapes.

**As a running example** I use the L, C, T, and Z tiles:

```
tileSet = {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}};
ArrayPlot[#, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 10 Max[Length[First[#]]]] & /@ tileSet
```

[image: Tile set]

(There is no restriction that tiles have a common bounding box, but--to make sure they can be properly positioned--it is important that their matrix descriptions not have any zero padding along outside rows or columns.)

**We need to rotate (and, if we wish, flip) all these tiles.**  An elegant way (perhaps not the simplest) is to generate the group action abstractly in terms of generators (`alpha` and `beta`).

```
apply[s_List, alpha] := Reverse /@ s;       (* Horizontal reflection *)
apply[s_List, beta] := Transpose[s];        (* Diagonal reflection *)
apply[s_List, g_List] := Fold[apply, s, g]; (* Group composition *)
group = FoldList[Append, {}, Riffle[ConstantArray[alpha, 4], beta]];
```

(`Riffle` and `ConstantArray` are just a trick, specific to [Coxeter groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), to generate a unique set of group elements.  If you don't want to allow reflections, then eliminate the four orientation-reversing group elements, which are the ones using odd numbers of generators.)

Apply the group action to the tiles and eliminate any duplicates:

```
tiles = Union[Flatten[Outer[apply[#1, #2] &, tileSet, group, 1], 1]];
ArrayPlot[#, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 10 Max[Length[First[#]]]] & /@ tiles
```

[image: All tiles]

**These tiles need to be converted from arrays** (suitable for graphical display) **into vectors** (for input to the linear program).  Because these vectors represent all possible positions (translations) of the oriented tiles into the square, here is where we specify the square's dimensions, $m$ rows by $n$ columns.  I use $6$ by $9$ for this example (which is a significant size).  `makeAllTiles` creates all possible positions of a single tile within a rectangle; mapping it over the set of all oriented tiles and flattening the result gives what we want.  (No need any more to remove duplicates, because there is no possibility of an accidental match.)

```
makeAllTiles[tile_, m_Integer, n_Integer] := 
  With[{m0 = Length[tile], n0 = Length[First[tile]]},
   Flatten[Table[ArrayPad[tile, {{i, m - m0 - i}, {j, n - n0 - j}}], 
      {i, 0, m - m0}, {j, 0, n - n0}], 1]];
allTiles = Flatten[makeAllTiles[#, 6, 9] & /@ tiles, 1];
ArrayPlot[options = Transpose[Flatten /@ allTiles], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Tile positions]

Each possible position of each possible orientation of each tile shape is represented by a column vector in this array.  The rows correspond to cells in the rectangle.

**It's now surprisingly straightforward to complete the setup:** we seek a subset of columns summing to the vector representing a filled square: all the coefficients in this sum must be $1$'s.  The subset can be picked out by an indicator vector $x$.  We therefore require its entries to be integral, bounded below by $0$, and bounded above by $1$.  A *feasible* vector, let's say, will be one where the corresponding sum fills the square, but sometimes fills its cells multiple times (due to overlap of tiles): that is, a lower bound $b$ for the result should be a $1$ in each cell of the square.  Finally, we minimize the sum of the cell values: if a solution exists, this sum will equal the number of squares.  The sum is a linear combination with unit coefficients, represented as a vector $c$.

```
b = ConstantArray[1, Length[options]]; (* Lower bounds on cell values *)
c = ConstantArray[1, Length[First[options]]]; (* Sum of cell values *)
lu = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, Length[First[options]]]; (* 0-1 constraints *)
x = Quiet[LinearProgramming[c, options, b, lu, Integers, Tolerance -> 0.0005], 
      {LinearProgramming::lpip, LinearProgramming::lpsnf}];
If[!ListQ[x] || Max[options.x] > 1, x = {}];
solution = allTiles[[Select[x Range[Length[x]], # > 0 &]]];
ArrayPlot[z = Sum[i solution[[i]], {i, 1, Length[solution]}], 
    PlotRange -> {0, Max[z]}, Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Solution]

`Solution` is a list of tiles (in their orientations and positions).

### Limitations

`LinearProgramming` (apparently) can return only one solution even when many are optimal.  To explore all solutions, or a range of solutions, may require different methods.  (There are still some tricks we can play: e.g., by permuting the order of columns in `Options`, we *might* wind up with a different solution.)

As with the systematic searching methods, when this problem gets big, the computing time grows rapidly.  You can see this is so, just by considering the quadratic growth in the list of possible positions of the tiles as the square's dimensions increase.  Computing time for the example is around one second (increasing as `Tolerance` decreases).

Finally, **I had to fudge something to get this solution**: `LinearProgramming`, with its default setting for `Tolerance`, returned a non-optimal solution! (`options.x` had some 2's in it, indicating some double overlaps.)  By starting with `Tolerance` set to $0.5$ and gradually decreasing it, within a few steps a valid solution was obtained.  (With the value set to `10^-1`, though, I raised an Assert in the underlying C code :-(.  *That* is a bug, at least in version 8.0.0.0.)

Comment: Wow!  I love answers like this.  It's humbling and enlightening all at once.

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps your dihedral groups mastering may help me [**in this question on math.se**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157993/finding-an-invariant-under-group-operations) related to [**this question**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/performance-tuning-for-game-solving-peg-solitaire) in this site

Comment: @belisarius Actually, I had been using these methods to study your peg solitaire game (and I have even simplified it using exactly the same `LinearProgramming` treatment described here).

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to minimize the number of pieces used to cover the square when you use `c={1,1,1,1...}`. If instead you tried to minimize the number of total squares by using `c=Total@options` it seems to work fine without the `Tolerance` specification. What do you think?

Comment: @Rojo That's a good idea. What I was really seeking was *any* feasible solution. I could not find an option in `LinearProgramming` to do that and so, as a work-around, was forced to find a feasible solution by optimizing *something.*

Comment: But if that's the case then the problems you experienced are not because of a bug, right? Given that one piece has 5 squares and the other 4, there are probably ways to minimize the number of pieces used while "at least" covering the square that imply some overlap

Comment: @Rojo, an Assert statement is embedded by developers to flag a mismatch between their assumptions and the runtime context: in other words, to catch *bugs*. I don't think there can be any question about that.

Comment: Yeah, you are right

Comment: I was wondering if a modification of this can be applied *in practice* to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2527/12)  The problem is a bit different there but it is essentially about tiling in an optimal way.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's an interesting idea.  I don't see any reason why it won't work: you could approximate each graph by an 'envelope' akin to a polyomino and then apply the tiling solution directly. You would need to add constraints to prevent any tile from being used more than once.

Comment: You have a number of very nicely worked out answers. Some of them would make [good blog posts](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com) too, with a few minor modifications.  Please drop me an email if you are interested :-)

Answer (score 2):

So here's a clarification to the Mathematica Journal post that David Carraher has corrected and updated so it works in Mathematica 9 posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38826/what-is-missing-in-this-mathematica-journal-article).  Now we all have working code for this cool Mathematica solution!