# Exact cover solution

Tags: matrix, combinatorics, sets

Is it possible to get a [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) solution(s) and/or number of possible solutions in Mathematica?

Comment: I saw the link. But can you bring us some toy code example?

Comment: Pentomino tiling is one of classic tasks of exact cover algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover#Pentomino_tiling

Comment: Pentomino tiling is a task of 2 subtasks: 1) generate all possible pentomino placement in matrix, e.g., generate list of matrices as a result; 2) exact cover algorithm to find all possible pentomino packings. Is it possible to solve in Mathematica?

Comment: Is that similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/tiling-a-square)?

Comment: Rojo, no, they solve that task by other methods, but thanks for your link!

Comment: The data from the wikipedia "exact cover" entry: `x = Range[7];
a = {1, 4, 7};
b = {1, 4};
c = {4, 5, 7};
d = {3, 5, 6};
e = {2, 3, 6, 7};
f = {2, 7};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Corrected the transcription of the solution, in final line.

---

This is one way to find Exact Cover solutions. It exploits the simple fact that non-disjoint (overlapping) subsets cannot be together in an exact cover solution, which must constitute a partition of the set `x`. My approach is almost certainly not the most efficient way, but it was how I was able to make sense the problem, which was new for me.

**Data**

Using the example from Wikipedia [Exact Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) entry, where `x` constitutes the set and `a..f` constitute the subsets of `x` to consider.

```
x = Range[7];
a = {1, 4, 7};
b = {1, 4};
c = {4, 5, 7};
d = {3, 5, 6};
e = {2, 3, 6, 7};
f = {2, 7};
y = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
```

**Array of Subsets and their elements**

The first array plot displays the elements of x (column headers) contained by the subsets (row headers).

```
f1[rr_] := Flatten[{# -> 1} & /@ rr];
array = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, Length[x]], #] & /@ (f1 /@ y);
t = Transpose[{Range[6],  CharacterRange["a", FromCharacterCode[96 + Length[y]]]}];

MatrixPlot[array, Mesh -> True, FrameTicks -> {{t, t}, {Range[7], Range[7]}}]
```

The following array shows the elements of `x` in each subset, `a`..`f`.

[image: array1]

**Compatibility Relations Between Subsets**

Subset a is compatible with subset b if their intersection is empty, i.e if they are disjoint.

```
a2 = Array[Boole[Intersection[y[[#1]], y[[#2]]] == {}] &, {6, 6}];
MatrixPlot[a2, Mesh -> True, FrameTicks -> {{t, t}, {t, t}}]
compatibleSets = Flatten[Position[#, 1]] & /@ a2;
```

Candidates are possible exact cover solutions (together with the row subset). We generate the subsets and then prepend the row subset.  If the row subset is not in a solution, then all candidates from the row will be rejected.  However, all solutions will emerge elsewhere, i.e from candidates in other rows.

```
candidates = Rest@Subsets[#] & /@ compatibleSets;
c5 = Union[Flatten[Transpose[{candidates, Range[6]}] /. {l_, n_Integer} :>   
  (Sort[Prepend[#, n]] & /@ l), 1]]
```

`Cases`requires that the candidates (plus header subset) have as many elements as `x` and that those elements be the same ones as in `x`.

```
Cases[c5,  z_ /; (Total[Length /@ (y[[#]] & /@ z)] == Length[x]) && 
   Union[Flatten[(y[[#]] & /@ z)]] == x]
```

If a subset shares no elements with another subset, it is compatible with it.
For example, "a" is compatible with "d".  "Compatible" is perhaps misleading since the compatibility relation, `aRb`, is commutative, but neither transitive nor reflexive!  So it's important to "read the row information" as being a statement about what that subsets the row header subset is compatible with.  One can not assume that all highlighted (orange) subsets in a row are mutually compatible.

We acknowledge that the numbers beneath the array plot below actually represent subsets (whereas in the first matrix plot, the numbers represented elements of the set, `x`).  E.g.  `{1,4}` stands for the fact that `a` is compatible with `d`.  If I had patience, I would have the code return letters rather that digits that refer to the position in y.

[image: a3]

> {{1, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {4, 6}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 5,6}, {1, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 5, 6}}
>
> {{2, 4, 6}}

Note that only 12 candidate solutions needed to actually be checked out of a possible 128.
{2,4,6}, that is, {b, d, f}, constitutes the only exact cover for the data (although this is not proven here).

This last line is sloppy; still needs to be automatized.  Its only purpose is to convert digits to the subsets they stand for.

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}[[{2, 4, 6}]]
```

> {"b","d","f"}

**Checking that `{b,d,f}` is an exact cover.**

```
Union[Join[b, d, f]] == x
```

> True

Answer (score 6):

I will use David Carraher's example to illustrate a way using integer linear programming.

```
x = Range[7];
a[1] = {1, 4, 7};
a[2] = {1, 4};
a[3] = {4, 5, 7};
a[4] = {3, 5, 6};
a[5] = {2, 3, 6, 7};
a[6] = {2, 7};
```

First we turn these subsets into 0-1 sets (think of them as bitvectors) representing whether a given element is in or not. For purposes of later using vector dot products I will transpose it. Could probably avoid that using MapIndexed later, or some such.

```
f[vec_, n_] := Table[If[MemberQ[vec, j], 1, 0], {j, n}]
b = Transpose@Table[f[a[j], 7], {j, 6}]

(* {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
  0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 
  0, 1, 0, 1, 1}} *)
```

We create a variable for each subset and restrict values to be zero (don't use that subset) or one (use it).

```
vars = Array[c, 6];
c1 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, vars];
c2 = Map[(#*(vars.b[[#]]) == #) &, x];
```

Here is thatsecond constraint set. The idea is that sums of boolean c elements times each j times bit vector elements for item j in corresponding subsets must give exactly j. (I'd like to believe that I stated that correctly. I don't believe it. But I'd like to.)

```
(* {c[1] + c[2] == 1, 2 (c[5] + c[6]) == 2, 
 3 (c[4] + c[5]) == 3, 4 (c[1] + c[2] + c[3]) == 4, 
 5 (c[3] + c[4]) == 5, 6 (c[4] + c[5]) == 6, 
 7 (c[1] + c[3] + c[5] + c[6]) == 7} *)
```

I use *Reduce* to find all solutions, then post-process to show each as a list of sublists, with sublist of the form {subset number, subset}.

```
Reduce[Join[c1, c2], vars, Integers] /. {Or -> List, 
  aa_ == 0 :> Sequence[], c[j_] == 1 :> {j, a[j]}, And -> List}

(* {{2, {1, 4}}, {4, {3, 5, 6}}, {6, {2, 7}}} *)
```

Comment: Nice. There's lots for me to learn from your example