# Is there an easy way to specify an arbitrary two-dimensional Polyomino tiling in Mathematica 8.0?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Is there an easy way to generate an arbitrary two-dimensional Polyomino tiling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino?

Specifically, I would like to generate an array of integer coordinates, for example:
{{0,1},{10,11},{15,6},...}, and then output a graphic showing a tiling pattern where a tile is centered at each integer coordinate in my array, and where each tile is labeled with its integer coordinate.

Is there a way for me to do this in three-dimensions?

I have access to Wolfram Mathematica 8.0.

Comment: This [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyomino.html] may be of help.

Comment: @dude Thanks, yeah, I read the MathWorld article, but it doesn't have any suggestions for implementations.  Given, you know, N.K.S., I'm suspicious that there should be a way to do what I'm asking in four or less lines of Mathematica.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6822/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the following articles:

- [**Tiling Rectangles with Polyominoes** *by JAIME RANGEL-MONDRAGÓN*](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_7.html)
- [**Polyominoes and Related Families** by *JAIME RANGEL-MONDRAGÓN*](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_8.html)

Here is an example of a custom function usage from 1st article producing a tiling:

[image]

Also related:

- [**Demonstrations**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=Polyomino)
- [**MathWorld**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyominoTiling.html)

Comment: The two Mathematica Journal articles are no longer available through the links. I was able to get the notebook files by contacting the editor at editor@mathematica-journal.com.

Comment: @MichaelWijaya, found the article in the Archive:  http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_7.html  and http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_8.html