# Strategies for solving problems involving searches

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-review, searching

As an example of a search-oriented problem, consider finding ***all** constrained $n$-colorings of a graph.*  An "$n$-coloring" associates one of $n \ge 1$ colors to each vertex in such a way that no edge connects vertices of the same color.  A "constrained" coloring requires that certain vertices have certain fixed colors.

For instance, here is a graph with one of its vertices already colored red; the default (cyan) vertices are as yet uncolored:

[image: Partial coloring of a graph]

There are 10 ways to color this graph using three colors; say, {red, green, blue}, while keeping the red vertex red:

[image: All constrained 3-colorings]

(Notice that the colorings are *not* up to isomorphism: all six vertices are considered to be distinct and not interchangeable.)

These solutions are found with a brute-force recursive search.  The approach exemplifies a large class of problems, such as playing games and solving puzzles.  In most interesting cases the search can take a long time (and have a large amount of output), so it is important to find appropriate data structures and efficient search methods.  **I am interested in *Mathematica*-specific advice and strategies for making such searches efficient.**

To make this question clearer and more focused, I invite your critical comments concerning this particular solution to the constrained $n$-coloring problem:

```
constrainedColorings[graph[vertices_, nbrhds_], colors_List, start_List] := Module[
   {unassigned, v, candidates},
   unassigned = Complement[vertices, start[[All, 1]]];
   If[unassigned == {}, Return[start]];
   v = First[unassigned];
   candidates = Complement[colors, v /. nbrhds /. start];
   Map[constrainedColorings[graph[vertices, nbrhds], colors, Append[start, v -> #]] &, candidates]
   ];
```

Its arguments are

- `graph`, which contains a list of the vertices and a list of rules assigning to each vertex the set of its immediate neighbors in the graph;
- `colors`, which is a list of the available colors; and
- `start`, which is a (possibly empty) list of rules assigning vertices to colors: it stipulates any constraints.  It is expected that the colors appearing in `start` are contained within `colors`.

Its output is a deeply nested list (representing the search tree) whose leaves are lists of rules assigning colors to vertices.

Like most such searches, it follows a familiar logic:

1. Determine whether the search is finished.
2. If not, make a list of possible next moves (`candidates`),
3. ... and tentatively make each move in turn, recursively searching for all solutions arising from it.
4. Return a set of all solutions found.

To illustrate its use, consider the preceding example.  It started out as a *Mathematica* `Graph` (in order to exploit its graph visualization capabilities) and was converted into a more convenient `graph` structure for this search:

```
\[Gamma] = Graph[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}, 
  {v1 \[UndirectedEdge] v2, v1 \[UndirectedEdge] v4, v1 \[UndirectedEdge] v5, 
   v2 \[UndirectedEdge] v3, v3 \[UndirectedEdge] v4, v3 \[UndirectedEdge] v5},
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> 0.4];
g = graph[VertexList[\[Gamma]], # -> Cases[EdgeList[\[Gamma]], 
       # \[UndirectedEdge] v_ | v_ \[UndirectedEdge] # -> v] & /@ VertexList[\[Gamma]]];
```

Here is the search itself, whereby the available colors are stipulated and the initial constraints are provided:

```
colorings = constrainedColorings[g, {Red, Green, Blue}, {v5 -> Red}];
```

We can flatten the output to get a list of all solutions:

```
colorings /. x : List[_Rule ..] :> coloring @@ x // Flatten
```

If you care to play with this code, you will want to draw the output:

```
display[g_Graph, c_coloring] :=  HighlightGraph[g, List @@ c /. Rule -> Style];
display[\[Gamma], #] & /@ colorings
```

Here, then, is the specific question:

- **In what ways can this code be improved to be faster, simpler, and more flexible?**

I am especially interested in advice that would apply not just to this particular problem but to the entire class of problems.  What kinds of data structures should one prefer to represent combinatorial objects: arrays, rules, something else?  Or perhaps there is no general answer?  Are there ways to expedite such searches, such as (possibly) exploiting *Mathematica's* built-in graph programming capabilities?

General replies are fine and so are answers that specifically improve the code here, provided it is clear how such improvements could be applied more generally.

Comment: Happy first question

Comment: Makes me wonder if I learned something from [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6704/109)

Comment: @Rojo Me too (meaning myself here :-))

Comment: Maybe you could add "enumeration" to the title if you mean "find all" type of problems.  Unfortunately, there are good reasons to believe that most problems of this type simply don't have an efficient solution.  But it's still an interesting question to ask how to implement a non-polynomial complexity or brute force algorithm in an efficient way in Mathematica.  Do you have the [Combinatorica book](http://www.amazon.com/Computational-Discrete-Mathematics-Combinatorics-Mathematica/dp/0521121469)?  It's a very interesting read because it explains *both* the maths and the implementations.

Comment: I'm still reading it, so I can offer little concrete advice, but the section on Pólya theory might be of some use to you.  Please email me if you're interested.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the tip--I'll keep that book in mind. I know the Polya theory, but it has not been apparent to me how to apply it to the $n$-coloring problem. I appreciate your advice to modify the title, but "enumerate" means "count" whereas I want to obtain the actual solutions, not just a count of them. This is primarily of interest  where there are relatively few such solutions. An example would be a puzzle that claims to have a unique solution, but maybe it doesn't--and we would like to exhibit them all.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I am just learning it now, and I connected your question to the book.  You're right, mathematicians are funny that way that when they say "enumeration" they mean "counting" while for the rest of us it may mean "construct one by one".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One can also go about this using integer linear programming, with an array of 0-1 variables indexed by vertices and colors. Here is one encoding of that approach.

```
constrainedColorings2[graph[vertices_, nbrhds_], colors_List, 
  start_List, v_] := Module[
  {unassigned, nv = Length[vertices], nc = Length[colors], vars, 
   fvars, c1, c2, c3, c4, pos1, pos2, constraints, solns},
  vars = Array[v, {nv, nc}];
  fvars = Flatten[vars];
  c1 = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, fvars];
  c2 = Map[Total[#] == 1 &, vars];
  c3 = Map[Table[
      pos1 = Position[vertices, #[[1]]][[1, 1]];
      pos2 = Position[vertices, #[[2, j]]][[1, 1]];
      v[pos1, k] + v[pos2, k] <= 1, {k, nc}, {j, Length[#[[2]]]}] &, 
    nbrhds];
  c4 = Map[(pos1 = Position[vertices, #[[1]]][[1, 1]];
      pos2 = Position[colors, #[[2]]][[1, 1]];
      v[pos1, pos2] == 1
      ) &, start];
  constraints = Flatten[Join[c1, c2, c3, c4]];
  solns = Solve[constraints, fvars, Integers];
  Map[Thread[vertices -> ((vars /. #).colors)] &, solns]
  ]
```

Your example, slightly altered (I'm not getting the graphing right and don't have time for that now) looks like this.

```
c2 = 
 constrainedColorings2[g, {rRed, gGreen, bBlue}, {v5 -> rRed}, v]

(* Out[220]= {{v1 -> bBlue, v2 -> gGreen, v3 -> bBlue, v4 -> gGreen, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> bBlue, v2 -> gGreen, v3 -> bBlue, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> bBlue, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> bBlue, v4 -> gGreen, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> bBlue, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> bBlue, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> bBlue, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> gGreen, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> gGreen, v2 -> bBlue, v3 -> gGreen, v4 -> bBlue, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> gGreen, v2 -> bBlue, v3 -> gGreen, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> gGreen, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> bBlue, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> gGreen, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> gGreen, v4 -> bBlue, 
  v5 -> rRed}, {v1 -> gGreen, v2 -> rRed, v3 -> gGreen, v4 -> rRed, 
  v5 -> rRed}} *)
```

Comment: +1 Linear programming is a good idea (I have used it in some of my own answers; *cf* http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/tiling-a-square/6888#6888). However, I wonder whether `Solve` and its kin are up to producing *all* solutions when the number starts getting large. I also suspect that once we get beyond the domain of toy examples, `Solve` might bog down and take a very long time.  `LinearProgramming` can be fast but I don't expect it to return more than a single solution.

Comment: Solve will use integer linear programming under the hood for this. I believe it will return all solutions. For large problems it certainly might take approximately forever to do so. In such cases I would write an explicit branching loop and use approximate rather than exact linear programming. That's not foolproof but works well in practice and can be significantly faster than Solve (which uses exact LP).

Comment: That tiling was a neat problem, by the way. Not sure how I missed it last summer. As for getting more solutions, you can set up a stack of problems with added constraints, and pop from the stack until it is exhausted (or you are). The new constraints are what keeps it from repeating solutions. You can get an example of such a stack and usage [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7517/) e.g. slide 18 of the talk notebook.

Comment: Very nice paper--worth a lot of thought.  Thanks.