# Finding the likeliest path in a Markov process

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

With *Mathematica* 9, we have the addition of various *processes*, among which the discrete Markov process. Given a transition probability matrix `m`, such a process is defined as follows:

```
m = {{1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 0, 0},
     {1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 0},
     {0, 1/2, 0, 1/4, 1/16, 3/16},
     {0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    };

proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, m];

g1 = Graph[proc]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Various properties of a given Markov process can be found using the function `MarkovProcessProperties`. `Probability` can be used (among other things) to answer questions about the likelihood to end up in a certain state after a given number of steps.

However, I did not find a function that yields the *path that is most likely to be taken* between a given a starting and ending state. How would one find this path?

Comment: Isn't that just what Viterbi's algorithm does?

Comment: @nikie I wasn't aware of that algorithm. Thanks. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) this is used for hidden markov models, but I feel that that implies it should be easily convertible to MM as well. The implementation will take a few more lines of code than the one given below, which I believe is already optimal. I may be wrong here, though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This sounds very similar to a traveling salesman problem for which we have the built-in (as of v8) `FindShortestPath` function. However, this function *minimizes* the overall path length (which is the *sum* of all sub-paths), whereas we need a functions that *maximizes* the path probability (which is the *product* of the transition probabilities along the path).

Since maximizing a product is equivalent to minimizing the sum of the negated logarithms this is easy enough. In this case:

```
g2 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[-Log[m]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sp2= FindShortestPath[g2, 1, 6]
```

> {1, 4, 5, 6}

```
HighlightGraph[g1, sp2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The shortest path in terms of the original matrix weights would have been:

```
sp1 = FindShortestPath[g1, 1, 6]
```

> {1, 3, 6}.

Test that the former is indeed more likely than the latter:

```
pathProbability[m_?MatrixQ, path_List] := Times @@ (m[[##]] & @@@ Partition[path, 2, 1])

pathProbability[m, #] & /@ {sp1, sp2}
```

> {3/64, 1/16}

---

## UPDATE

Since version 10 Mathematica has acquired tools for *hidden Markov processes*. The likeliest path can now be calculated by setting the starting and ending state to 100% emitting and all other states to hidden, non-emitting states. `FindHiddenMarkovStates` will now do the job for us using Viterbi decoding, though it doesn't really yield shorter or more elegant code. It's also a lot (by a factor of more than 10) slower.

```
hmm = HiddenMarkovProcess[1, m, {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, None, None, None, None, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}];
obs = {1, 6};
FindHiddenMarkovStates[obs, hmm]
```

> {1, 4, 5, 6}

Comment: +1 You might in many cases be interested in *all* modal paths, not just one of them.  (This is related to [my recent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19177/strategies-for-solving-problems-involving-searches).)

Comment: @whuber Interesting. Do you happen to have a link to a paper with a readable introduction to this area?