# shortest paths in probabilistically weighted edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

I understand Mathematica can find shortest paths. However, is it also able to find the most probable paths? I mean this is a case where edges are given probabilistic wights (from 0 to 1) and the most probable path from i to j is simply a multiplication (not addition) of weights queuing within the path.

---

I am not currently working on Mathematica. I understood some of its capabilities from the the documentations and tutorial guides. I am enquiring so as to confirm weather Mathematica could serve for my particular need; thence I would pay for a licence and download it.

In UCINET, for example, the users have the choice upon the type of weights (e.g cost, probability, etc.) allotted to the edges to compute 'reachability'. Reachability looks for all paths between i and j and computes the product of the path that attains the maximum value. That is: MAX(i * h1 * h2 * h3 * j), where h are the internediate nodes between i and j.

However,  UCINET only provides the reachability (product of the most probable path) but do not actually tells which path is it..

The answer I am looking for is weather Mathematica could do that or not.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to Mathematica? Your statement "I understand ..." makes me think you aren't currently working with Mathematica. So, what kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: related : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/finding-the-most-likeliest-path-in-a-markov-process

Comment: You could takes logarithms of those weights and use the regular weighted shortest paths functionality.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That's indeed what I did in the answer linked to in the above comment.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Sorry, I had missed that just before (but at least I did not miss it the first time, because I see I gave it an upvote way back then).