# What is missing in this Mathematica Journal Article?

Tags: debugging

So I had been looking to solve a little tiling problem and Google turned up this [Mathematica Journal Article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/polyominoes/polyominoes_7.html) and I noticed the code was both incomplete and incorrect, so... My Question is, What is missing to make this code actually work?

To make this process slightly less time consuming, Here's a rough interpretation of the journal post in actual code form.  Some things were changed that were obvious errors like undeclared variables and punctuation. Also there were functions inside of functions, and where it was clear (to me) that method was wrong, they were moved.

```
lexic[p_] := Sort[p, (Im[#1] < Im[#2]) || ((Im[#1] == Im[#2]) && (Re[#1] <= Re[#2])) &];

tess[{n_, m_}, poly_, justOneSolution_: False] := Module[{avail, pieces, i, j, ans = {}, tessAux, na, ma},tessAux[partial_] := Module[{f, c, candidates, newp, k},
candidates = Complement[avail, Flatten@partial];
If[candidates == {},
AppendTo[ans, partial]; If[justOneSolution, Throw[1]],
k = First@lexic@candidates;
Map[(newp = k + # - First[#];
 If[(Complement[newp, avail] == {}) && (f = 
     Flatten[{partial, newp}];
    Length@f == Length@Union@f), 
  tessAux[Append[partial, newp]]]) &, pieces]]];
{na, ma} = If[n < m, {m, n}, {n, m}];
pieces = lexic /@ Union[Flatten[pieces /@ poly, i]];
avail = Flatten[Table[i + j*i, {j, 0, na - i}, {i, 0, ma - 1}]];
Catch[tessAux[{}];
If[n < m, Map[m - 1 + i # &, ans], ans]];

getLines[tiling_] := Module[{p},
Partition[Flatten[Map[(p = #; 
Map[{If[Not[MemberQ[p, # + 1]], {# + 1 + i}, {}],
If[Not[MemberQ[p, # + i]], {# + i, # + 1 + i}, {}]} &, p]) &, tiling]], 2]];

tile[{n_, m_}, poly_, r_, justOneSolution_: False] := Module[{t, u, g},
t = tess[{n, m}, poly, justOneSolution];
g = Map[Graphics[Append[{{LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {m, n}]},
Line[{{0, n}, {0, 0}, {m, 0}}]},
lexic /@ getLines[#]]] &, t];
Show[GraphicsArray[Partition[If[Mod[Length[t], r] == 0, g,     
Join[g,Table[Graphics[Point[{0, 0}]], {r - Mod[Length[t], r]}]]], r]]]
```

]

Comment: The Mathematica Journal article is no longer available through the link. I was able to get the notebook file by contacting the editor at editor@mathematica-journal.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the original article there is a semi-colon after the final `Show` in `tile`.
Remove that semi-colon and the program should run normally.

While you're at it, replace `GraphicsArray` with `GraphicsGrid`.

You probably also noted that the article uses unusual color names that Mathematica does not recognize. (The package, `Graphics Colors` is not found.) You will need to replace the unknown color names with known ones. This does not apply to the code snippet we focused on below.

**Edit**: The following code is needed for your code.  It is given elsewhere in the article.

```
polyominoQ[p_] := 
 And @@ ((IntegerQ[Re[#]] && IntegerQ[Im[#]]) & /@ p)
rot[p_?polyominoQ] := I p
ref[p_?polyominoQ] := (# - 2 Re[#]) & /@ p

cyclic[p_] := 
 Module[{i = p, ans = {p}}, 
  While[(i = rot[i]) != p, AppendTo[ans, i]]; ans]

dihedral[p_?polyominoQ] := Flatten[{#, ref[#]} & /@ cyclic[p], 1]

canonical[p_?polyominoQ] := 
 Union[(# - (Min[Re[p]] + Min[Im[p]] I)) & /@ p]

allPieces[p_] := Union[canonical /@ dihedral[p]]

liC[z_] := Line[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ z]
polC[z_] := Polygon[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ z]

draw[p_?polyominoQ, pr_: All] := 
 Graphics[{{Brown, polC[{#, # + 1, # + 1 + I, # + I}]}, 
     liC[{#, # + 1, # + 1 + I, # + I, #}]} & /@ p, PlotRange -> pr]
```

This is the part of the code of major interest:

```
lexic[p_]:=Sort[p,(Im[#1]<Im[#2])||((Im[#1]==Im[#2])&&(Re[#1]<=Re[#2]))&]

tess[{n_,m_},poly_,justOneSolution_:False]:=Module[{avail,pieces,i,j,ans={},tessAux,na,ma},

tessAux[partial_]:=Module[{f,c,candidates,newp,k},
candidates=Complement[avail,Flatten[partial]];
If[candidates=={},AppendTo[ans,partial];If[justOneSolution,Throw[1]],
k=First[lexic[candidates]];
Map[(newp=k+#-First[#];
If[(Complement[newp,avail]=={})&&(f=Flatten[{partial,newp}];Length[f]==Length[Union[f]]),tessAux[Append[partial,newp]]])&,pieces]]];

{na,ma}=If[n<m,{m,n},{n,m}];
pieces=lexic/@Union[Flatten[allPieces/@poly,1]];
avail=Flatten[Table[i+j I,{j,0,na-1},{i,0,ma-1}]];
Catch[tessAux[{}]];
If[n<m,Map[m-1+I #&,ans],ans]]

getLines[tiling_]:=Module[{p},
Partition[Flatten[Map[(p=#;Map[{If[Not[MemberQ[p,#+1]],{#+1,#+1+I},{}],If[Not[MemberQ[p,#+I]],{#+I,#+1+I},{}]}&,p])&,tiling]],2]]

tile[{n_,m_},poly_,r_,justOneSolution_:False]:=Module[{t,u,g},
t=tess[{n,m},poly,justOneSolution];
g=Map[Graphics[Append[{{LightBlue,Rectangle[{0,0},{m,n}]},Line[{{0,n},{0,0},{m,0}}]},liC/@getLines[#]]]&,t];
Show[GraphicsGrid[Partition[If[Mod[Length[t],r]==0,g,Join[g,Table[Graphics[Point[{0,0}]],{r-Mod[Length[t],r]}]]],r]]]]
```

Testing

```
tile[{4,3},{{0,I,1}},4]
```

[image: tiling]

Comment: I get an error running this code:GraphicsGrid::list: {} is not a list of lists. >>  and  Show::gtype: GraphicsGrid is not a type of graphics. >>  Also noticing that "allPieces" is undeclared in your code also.

Comment: After your last edit here are the errors: GraphicsGrid::list: {} is not a list of lists. >> and Show::gtype: GraphicsGrid is not a type of graphics. >>

Comment: Hmm.  Let me check.  BTW, notice that I included some additional code that the main code appears to depend on. It is likely that this was the source of the error.  (GraphicsGrid has been available since v. 6.)

Comment: works now David.  Thanks!