# Scale Insetted Characters to Plot

Tags: graphics, plotting, fonts

I am trying to place a curly brace within a plot such that the top/bottom of the curly brace line up with two horizontal lines in the plot:

[image]

I have not been able to find a way to make the curly brace have the right size without setting the size explicitly by hand. Insetting a Text object doesn't work as the font size is used to scale text, and guessing the right font size is a complete guessing game. I settled upon using "Pane" with the "ResizeToFit" ImageSizeAction set, however I am not sure how to then specify the Inset size or the ImageSize for pane to get the desired results.

Here is the code I am using to generate this plot. ImageSize being set to "5" is just a guess to get approximately the right size, but ideally I want the top/bottom of the curly brace to exactly line up with the two horizontal dashed lines:

```
f = 1/x;
ϵpl = 
  Plot[{f}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]];

ϵ1pl = 
  Plot[{f}, {x, 0.2, 0.4}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1.5]]];
ϵ1dashed = 
  ListPlot[{{{0.1, f /. x -> 0.27}, {0.27, f /. x -> 0.27}}, {{0.1, 
      f /. x -> 0.3}, {0.3, f /. x -> 0.3}}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
   Joined -> True];

Show[ϵpl, ϵ1pl, ϵ1dashed, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 6}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], FontSize -> 24], 
 FrameTicks -> False, FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"r\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"ϵ\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Pane["{", ImageSize -> 5, 
    ImageSizeAction -> 
     "ResizeToFit"], {0.095, ((f /. x -> 0.27) + (f /. x -> 0.3))/
    2}, {0, 0}, {Automatic, (f /. x -> 0.27) - (f /. x -> 0.3)}]]
```

Additionally, I would like to be able to scale the curly brace such that the original aspect ratio isn't maintained (i.e. the width of the curly brace will be a fixed value, but the height can vary). What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

["Vectorizing" the font:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JoinedCurve.html)

```
curve = First[First[ ImportString[ExportString[
        Style["{",FontFamily ->"Times",FontSize -> 72],  "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
cg = Graphics[curve]
```

and then your code, replacing the Inset[] clause by

```
Inset[Pane[cg, ImageSizeAction ->  "ResizeToFit"], ....
```

Result (scales OK when resizing the Plot):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Full code follows, just in case you decide to edit your code:

```
curve = First[First[
    ImportString[
     ExportString[Style["{", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 72], 
      "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
cg = Graphics[curve];
f = 1/x;
ϵpl = 
  Plot[{f}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]];

ϵ1pl = 
  Plot[{f}, {x, 0.2, 0.4}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[1.5]]];
ϵ1dashed = 
  ListPlot[{{{0.1, f /. x -> 0.27}, {0.27, f /. x -> 0.27}}, {{0.1, 
      f /. x -> 0.3}, {0.3, f /. x -> 0.3}}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
   Joined -> True];

Show[ϵpl, ϵ1pl, ϵ1dashed, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 6}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], FontSize -> 24], 
 FrameTicks -> False, FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
   StyleBox[\"r\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
   StyleBox[\"ϵ\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Pane[cg, 
    ImageSizeAction -> 
     "ResizeToFit"], {0.095, ((f /. x -> 0.27) + (f /. x -> 0.3))/
     2}, {0, 0}, {Automatic, (f /. x -> 0.27) - (f /. x -> 0.3)}]]
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Very nice. I figured there might be an easy way to do this. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard FilledCurve[] and JoinedCurve[] are new in 8 ... and the ImportString thing is returning a FilledCurve[ blah blah]

Comment: as they say: "duh" -- I've really gotten lazy; sorry.

Comment: +1 for "Vectorizing the font", just the thing **I** was looking for.

Answer (score 26):

To make such labeling more user-friendly, I wrote this function (**edited to add rotation**):

```
stretchText[char_, pos_, scale_, angle_: 0] := 
 Module[{g, coords, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax}, 
  g = First@First@ImportString[ExportString[char, "PDF"], If[$VersionNumber >= 13, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, "PDF"],
      "TextOutlines" -> True];
  coords = 
   Apply[Join, 
    Cases[g, FilledCurve[___, p_] :> Flatten[p, 1], Infinity]];
  {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}} = 
   Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &[#] &, Transpose[coords]];
  Rotate[
   Inset[
    Graphics[g,
     PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}},
     If[ListQ[scale],
      AspectRatio -> Full,
      AspectRatio -> Automatic
      ]
     ],
    pos,
    {xMin, yMin},
    scale],
   angle]
  ]
```

Here are some features:

First, you don't have to use a `Pane` or even an `Epilog` to use it (the output of `stretchText` is already an `Inset` and can be put into a `Graphics`). Secondly, you can position whatever string you like very precisely by specifying its lower left corner as the second argument `pos`, and then its scale in the horizontal and vertical direction as the third argument `scale`. The scale is in the coordinates of the surrounding graphic by default. So if you want the text to be exactly `0.2` wide and `0.7` high in the coordinates of your actual plot, that's exactly what you enter as `scale`. No need for trial-and-error adjustments.

The `scale` can be entered as a single number (in which case it sets the text width and scales the height proportionally), or as a pair of numbers for independent scaling of width and height. The latter is really what makes `stretchText` different from normal text. The last (optional) argument in `stretchText` is the rotation angle away from the horizontal.

Here is an example that just combines a hyperbola plot with the dashed lines and the stretched `{` by using a simple `Show` statement. To make the stretching clearer, I made a movie of it. What really counts is inside the `Table`:

```
t = With[{xMax = 3, wX = .2},
   Table[
    Show[Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 5}],
     Graphics[
      stretchText["{", {xMin - wX, 1/xMax}, {wX, 1/xMin - 1/xMax}]],
     Graphics[{Red, Dashed, 
       Map[Line[{{0, 1/#}, {#, 1/#}}] &, {xMin, xMax}]}],
     PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False],
    {xMin, .7, 2.5, .2}]
   ];
```

[image: Stretching character]

As this example shows, the positioning is pretty straightforward because `stretchText` takes care of rescaling the outlined characters (it could be a whole string, too) to the given parameters.

The essential ingredient in `stretchText` is the `PDF` export/import trick to produce `FilledCurves`, so it requires Mathematica 8. The ability to combine this annotation with `Show` means that it's easy to manipulate the output with Mathematica's graphics editor too, if needed.

**Edit: note on outlining text**

The reason why I convert text to outlines here is that text glyphs in a *string* can't be scaled by independent factors in the horizontal and vertical directions. You can only scale text proportionally, and that would make it impossible to get a stretched brace.

The point lists in the `FilledCurve` for the outlined glyphs are also used here to determine a reasonably close-cropped bounding box for the text. This is only approximate because I make no distinction between control and other points, but it is very simple and seems to work well in practice.

Comment: Very nice improvement to belisarius' solution.

Comment: I've actually been doing it this way for a long time, see [my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#formulasToPDF). Too bad that "TextMode"->"Outline" only got introduced (fully) in version 8 - before that, one had to resort to more complicated work-arounds, e.g., using ghostscript; see [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#OutlineFonts). That would still be a way to crearte similar functionality in older Mathematica versions...

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. When I run Graphics[stretchText["︷", {200, -360}, {350, 30}]] it gives me an image which is heavily padded on the left. Do you know how to remove this padding?

Comment: @JonathanShock Thanks - the problem with your short `Graphics` expression is that is needs to specify `PlotRange -> {{200, 550}, {-360, -330}}` if you want the graphic to enclose the `Inset` tightly. That range is just the minimal and maximal coordinates obtained from the arguments you provided in `stretchText`.

Comment: `stretchText` don't work anymore. It can help to make a non-overlapping label [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269652/how-to-make-these-callout-labels-not-overlap)?

Comment: @yode Thanks for letting me know. Mathematica version 13 broke backward compatibility with earlier PDF import syntax, so to fix the code in version 13 and above you need to insert `{"PDF", "PageGraphics"},` before the option `"TextOutlines" -> True`

Comment: I use it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269812/21532). It looks like sometimes the edges don't show up

Answer (score 15):

You can use my `brace` function.

```
p2c[p_]:=p[[1]]+I p[[2]];
c2p[p_]:={Re[p],Im[p]};
brace[pa_,pb_,a_:1/10,t_:1/3]:=Module[{θ,ρ},
θ=Arg[p2c[pb-pa]];
ρ=Norm[p2c[pb-pa]];
{Circle[pa+a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]},a ρ,{π+θ+t π/2,(3π)/2+θ}],
  Line[{pa+a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]},(pa+pb)/2-a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]}}],
  Circle[(pa+pb)/2-a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+2a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]},a ρ,{θ,π/2+θ}],
  Circle[(pa+pb)/2+a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+2a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]},a ρ,{π/2+θ,π+θ}],
  Line[{(pa+pb)/2+a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]},pb-a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]}+a ρ{Sin[θ],-Cos[θ]}}],
  Circle[pb-a ρ{Cos[θ],Sin[θ]},a ρ,{(3π)/2+θ,2π+θ-t π/2}]}
]
```

Here, `a` is in [0,1/4] and `t` is in [0,1], which you can easily figure out how they work.
Below, you can find and example.

```
With[{pa={3,1},pb={1,5},a=1/20,t=1/3}, 
 Graphics[{Point[{pa,pb}],brace[pa,pb,a,t], 
   Text[EuclideanDistance[pa,pb],(pa+pb)/2+1/2Reverse[(pa-pb)/2]*{-1,1}]}, 
   ImageSize->200,Frame->True,PlotRange->{{0,6},{0,6}}
 ]
]
```

[image: Showing distance with a curly brace]

Comment: For the special case of a brace, I also posted an implementation [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18079/245). It differs from this in that the label is passed as an argument to the function I call `braceLabel`.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to create your own "{" character using `BSplineCurve`.

```
Graphics[{Thick, BSplineCurve[{{0.3, 2.9}, {-0.6, 2.45}, {-0.95, 1.8}, 
      {-0.2, 1.05}, {0.25,0.45}, {0., 0.}, {-0.8, -0.15}, {0., -0.35}, 
      {0.25, -0.75}, {-0.15, -1.25}, {-0.85,-1.9}, {-0.35, -2.55}, 
      {0.35, -3.}}]}
 ]
```

You can place the graphic directly in place of the "{" character and it will scale nicely.  The only issue is getting the character to look as high quality as the built in ones.  I made my poor attempt using the "Bezier" setting from Heike's answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/how-to-interactively-create-a-polygon-in-a-graphic) question.

**Note:** You will want to remove the `ImageSize` option from your `Inset`.

Here is an example using a larger brace than the one in your example as proof of concept that it scales up nicely.

[image]

**Edit:**

One can also use `Rasterize` on the character and with a little cropping achieve what you want as well.

```
ImageCrop@Image[Rasterize["{", ImageSize -> 500]]
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid rasterization, if possible. Perhaps if there's a way to vectorize font characters, that would be the ideal solution, as then the graphics can be scaled in a straight-forward way. There might be font issues when the graphic is exported if a font character is used.