# Extending a grid to avoid line breaks in text

Tags: text, grid-layouts

I was wondering what the best way is to extend the cells in a `GraphicsGrid` so that my text fits without line breaks. My problem is illustrated by the graphic produced by the code below:

```
GraphicsGrid[{
  {Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{1, -1}]}], 
   Style["Antidisestablishmentarianism", FontSize -> 30], 
   SpanFromLeft},
  {Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{1, -1}]}], 
   Style["Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", FontSize -> 30],
   SpanFromLeft}}]`
```

[image]

I've been looking for ways to extend the cells on the right of the `GraphicsGrid` so that the text fits in on one line. In the code above, I've used `SpanFromLeft` to extend the cells a little. I would have to use many `SpanFromLeft` commands in order to fit the word next to the red square. So I was hoping that someone knew of a better way of doing this.

Comment: yes, but then I can't control image size, and I need to do that

Comment: To clear things up, I meant the size of the whole Grid. Essentially what I want is for the cells on the right hand side to be wider; just wondering if there's a better way of doing this than repeated `SpanFromLeft`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell me if that fits you:

```
grid = Grid[
 {
  {Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{1, -1}]}, ImageSize -> 100], 
   Style["Antidisestablishmentarianism", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromLeft}, 
  {Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{1, -1}]}, ImageSize -> 100], 
   Style["Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", FontSize -> 30], SpanFromLeft}
 }, ItemSize -> {{10, 60}}]
```

Then taking [that answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6685/1356):

```
Show[First@
  ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], "TextOutlines" -> True] &@ grid,
  ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

Then `ImageSize` can be used as will:

[image]

Comment: That would work. I was kind of hoping there was a simple autofit option

Comment: The text autofits with `Grid`. Using the `Show[]` part allows you to change the `ImageSize`.

Comment: @Öskå After applying `ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"]] &` you have no text: every glyph is outlined. It is the standard way to outline fonts in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't get if this is a problem or not.. :)

Comment: It is a problem if one wish to export graphics in a vector format like EPS, PDF or SVG. The quality will be (generally) lost after outlining and the size of exported file will become huge as compared to non-outlined. You can use `ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], "PDF", "TextOutlines" -> False]&` with the same effect but without outlining. I think that saying "text" when you actually have no text in the output is incorrect. The OP had real text in the example provided.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't see the difference so I removed it. And you meant that the vectorization is lost I assume :)

Comment: I did not mean that vectorization is lost: after converting glyphs to outlines you get vector outlines but of much lover quality than original glyphs (which are also expressed as vectors but in another fashion, much more precise and efficient).

Comment: Check [`grid`](http://upload-it.thenicam.ch/upload/20140512_161420_94707_test0.pdf),
[`ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"]]`](http://upload-it.thenicam.ch/upload/20140512_161420_96738_test.pdf),
[`ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], "Text.." -> True]`](http://upload-it.thenicam.ch/upload/20140512_161420_74356_test1.pdf),
[`ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], "PDF", "Text.." -> False]`](http://upload-it.thenicam.ch/upload/20140512_161420_50056_test2.pdf),
[`First@ImportString[ExportString[#, "PDF"], "PDF","Text.." -> True]`](http://upload-it.thenicam.ch/upload/20140512_161420_73844_test3.pdf)

Comment: @Öskå I have checked your PDFs. Everything is as expected: `"TextOutlines" -> True` produces outlined fonts and `"TextOutlines" -> False` gives textual fonts. As to red text coloring, it looks as a bug to me.

Comment: The bug with red text coloring can be fixed by wrapping the `Style` expression with `Text`. It is certainly a bug and it is worth to report it to Wolfram support.

Comment: @Öskå, yes, that answer is great.

Comment: @Max Check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) regarding accepting answers. That concerns your two last questions with valuable answers.

Comment: ok, voted for and marked as best answer. Thanks for pointing me to those pages.