# How to make Text size consistent with ImageSize

Tags: graphics, text, scaling

I'm using *Mathematica* to create complex figures. I would like to work them out on small size images and then, just before exporting them, increase the `ImageSize`. But I find that when I change the `ImageSize`, the `Text` remains the same size and so the image does not resize proportionally. Is there a strategy for overcoming this?

[image: Small Image]
[image: Large Image]

The first image has a small `ImageSize` and the second image has a large `ImageSize`.

Comment: The issue is that the text is not implemented as vector graphics. You can make it so, though, using this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/38205

Comment: Have you tried using something like `FontSize->Scaled[.05]`?

Comment: Related:  [(2475)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2475/121), [(6661)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6661/121), [(34909)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34909/121)

Answer (score 8):

In *Mathematica* 10.1 this scales well for me:

```
Graphics[{
  {EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.01], Black}], Orange, Disk[]},
  {Thickness[0.015], Arrowheads[0.08], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1} Sqrt[2]/2`}]},
  {FontSize -> Scaled[0.05], Text["R \[LongEqual] 1", {0.5, 0.2}]}
}]
```

[image]

[image]

The critical detail being `FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]` which I see is exactly what Carl Woll already proposed in a comment. I also used [`Thickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thickness.html) rather than [`AbsoluteThickness`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteThickness.html) for the [`EdgeForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeForm.html) and [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html) so that these elements scale as well.

Other examples:

- [How can I wrap text around a circle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719/121#5724)
- [Visualize Pascal's triangle and other triangle shaped lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9959/121#11375)
- [How to write scalable Frame Labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123300/121)