# Is there a way to outline text?

Tags: graphics, text, fonts

If I have:

```
Graphics[
  {Red, EdgeForm[Directive[White, Thick]], 
  Inset[Style[Text@"Hi!", 44], {0, 0}]}, Background -> Black
]
```

I unfortunately get:
[image: hi]
Which as you can see does not have a thick white outline.  Is there a way to get around this since `EdgeForm` clearly does not work?

By the way, I would rather NOT delve into making a larger, white `"Hi"` and then putting the red one on top. That's just not elegant.

MMA 8.0.1 for students
OS Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: there  was a question on Stack Overflow strongly related to this one.

Comment: Oh, I did not know.  I sort of gave up googling for MMA help since there usually isn't anything except for stuff here.  Also, I can't find it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Import text as a [**FilledCurve**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html) in graphics, using PDF as an intermediate format. Below are modified examples from [**Documentation Center**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html#101018554):

```
text = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[Style["Hi", Italic, FontSize -> 24, 
FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
```

Outline fonts using different edge and face forms:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[White, Thick]], Red, text},
Background -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-5, 25}, {-0, 20}}]
```

[image]

3D text effect:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Opacity[0.5]], Table[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][t], 
    Translate[text, 4 {-t, t}]}, {t, 0, 1, 1/10}]}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Vitaliy, very nice!

Comment: Cool.  But is this really the only way?  It's a bit slow to convert it to a curve and I need to display the graphics quickly in my game.  The text changes based on the game's statistics, so precomputing's not an option...

Comment: @vlad you can do the curve conversion on a letter basis in advance. You'd need a kerning table as well, but that shouldn't be too difficult to generate.

Comment: @vlad, the idea by SjoerdC.deVries is indeed a good solution. Otherwise you're risking to end up "delving into making a larger, white "Hi" and then putting the red one on top" ;-)

Comment: Interestingly, the option `"TextMode" -> "Outlines"` can be omitted, as I observed in [this answer which also shows another use for outlined characters](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4387/245)

Comment: While clever it strikes me as really quite atrocious to have to do an Export->Import to get the outlines.  I keep hoping someone will find or share an internal function that does this. :-/

Comment: Congrats on 10k! :)

Comment: @R.M Thanks! Nice of you to let me know ;-)

Comment: This is now outdated, now `text = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[Style["Hi", Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Times"],"PDF"], {"PDF", "PageGraphics"},"TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];` should be used as per the documentation.

Answer (score 14):

An important issue in the question seems to be that of speed. So as Sjoerd suggested, I wrote a solution that pre-outlines all the characters in a reasonable range of ASCII characters, and then does the replacements on an arbitrary string. The characters are stored in a table `ascii`, and their graphic replacements in `asciiGraphics`. I then define the replacement rule (`rule`) which is part of the function `makeText`:

```
ascii = CharacterRange[" ", "z"]

(*
==> {" ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", \
"+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", \
"9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", \
"G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", \
"U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "[", "\\", "]", "^", "_", "`", "a", \
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", \
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
*)


asciiGraphics = 
  First@ImportString[
      ExportString[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 44], 
       "PDF"], "TextOutlines" -> True] & /@ ascii;

rule = Dispatch[Thread[ascii -> asciiGraphics]];


Clear[makeText];
Options[makeText] = {"OutlineThickness" -> 1, "OutlineColor" -> White,
   "Color" -> Red}; 
makeText[string_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DisplayForm[
  Row[Characters[string] /. rule] /. 
   FilledCurve[
     x__] :> {EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[
        OptionValue["OutlineThickness"]], 
       OptionValue["OutlineColor"]}],
     OptionValue["Color"],
     FilledCurve[x]
     }
  ]
```

The argument to `makeText` is the string to be rendered as outlined text. The thickness of the outlines is specified by the option `"OutlineThickness"`. The other two options are `"OutlineColor"` and `"Color"` (of the filled areas).

The following is a demo - you win the game by sliding the slider to the right...

```
Manipulate[
 Style[Pane[
   makeText["Player 1 has " <> ToString[Floor[p]] <> " points", 
    "OutlineThickness" -> .7], ImageSize -> 360], 
   Background -> Black,
   Magnification -> 3
 ], {p, 0, 1000}]
```

[image: manipulate]

**Edit**

In response to the question in the comment:

By using [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html?q=Dispatch&lang=en) you can eke out a faster timing, and my focus was on getting fast execution. It won't matter much if you're dealing only with a short string. But if you're trying to translate a long text into outlined characters, the replacement is sped up when you first apply `Dispatch` to the rule.

Comment: Intresting.  But what is the role of Dispatch?

Comment: By using `Dispatch` you can eke out a faster timing, and my focus was on getting fast execution. It won't matter much if you're dealing only with a short string. But if you're trying to translate a long text into outlined characters, the replacement is sped up when you first apply `Dispatch` to the rule.

Comment: @Vlad Speed is the biggest hurdle when doing anything interactive in Mathematica - I hope you'll be able to overcome that for your game...

Answer (score 12):

In version 10, we can bypass exporting to PDF and re-importing and can outline text directly using region discretization functions.  This is shown in the documentation of [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html).

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["R", FontFamily -> "Cambria"]], _Text]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The region can then be converted back to graphics, and the `FilledCurve` extracted.

**WARNING: I just realized that the following line will often crash the kernel with 10.1.0 on OS X!  Proceed with caution!**

```
Cases[Normal@Show[reg], _FilledCurve, Infinity]
```

`Normal` is for getting rid of `GraphicsComplex` inside the resulting `Graphics` object.

If there is a direct way to go from a `BoundaryMeshRegion` to a `FilledCurve`, without having to use `Show`, please let me know!

Comment: weird, `RegionBoundary[reg]//FullForm` shows the polygon data, but there is no evident way to programmatically extract it. `Apply` doesn't work.. on a `MeshRegion`

Comment: I'm amazing you can discretize a word,and how do you find the pattern of "_Text"??Do you help me discretize a Tube?Such as "Graphics3D[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .1]]"?

Comment: @yode It's in the documentation I linked to, almost this very example.  I really don't know more than what's there.

Comment: If you provide character `i`, it would generate `Polygon` instead of `FilledCurve`.

Comment: @user1950580 I've done this now where I search for either of them. It suffices to get all the cases I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```wl
Graphics[{Haloing[White], Text[Style["Hi", 40, Red]]}, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]
Haloing was introduced in 13.3

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to bypass exporting to PDF and re-importing is to put the text on a background of the thickened text, and the text thickening can be achieved by the trick of translating the text around by a small amount.

For example, we have a text to outline:

```
text = Text[Style["Hello!", Italic, FontSize -> 24]];
Graphics[{White, text}, Background -> Black, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

We can use `Translate` to move the text around and `CirclePoints` to generate a set of uniformly distributed translation vectors along different directions. By dragging the text around, we effectively thicken the text.

```
Graphics[{{White, Translate[text, 0.02 #] & /@ CirclePoints[32]}}, 
 Background -> Black, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

Now we can put the original text on top of this thickened background, which effectively creates an outline effect for the text.

```
Graphics[{{White, Translate[text, 0.02 #] & /@ CirclePoints[32]}, text}, 
 Background -> Black, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

One may also adjust the thickness of the outline by changing the amount of translation for the background text.

```
Graphics[{{White, Translate[text, 0.05 #] & /@ CirclePoints[32]}, text}, 
 Background -> Black, PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

This method is much faster than the PDF export-import and the `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` methods. It applies to any text that can be displayed by the `Text` method without worrying about breaking text into characters and patching them together again (for example, preserving the spacing between characters in a row and between multiple lines can be painful).