# How do you stack 2D graphics into a 3D graphic?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Suppose you have a series of 2D graphics that depend on a parameter.  For example,

```
g[z_] := ParametricPlot[{2 Cos[t] + Cos[z t], 2 Sin[t] - Sin[z t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Hue[z/5]}, 
   Epilog -> {Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, 3], Hue[z/5], Text[Style[z, Bold, 16]]}];

Table[g@z, {z, 2, 5}]
```

[image: stack1]

How can one stack these graphics into a single 3D graphic, using the parameter as the z-axis?

Comment: See also the documentation: [Display stacked 2D plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Graphics/Graphics3D.html#95942487)

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is to covert the 2D graphics primitives to an equivalent 3D primitive using a set of rules.

It's not so simple as tacking on the z-coordinate to every list of two numbers. Sometimes your list of two numbers might not be a 2D point. So these rules must specifically target the bits which we know are coordinates.  As a start we can transform `Line` and `Text`:

```
linerule[z_] := Line[points_, stuff___] :> Line[#~Append~z & /@ points, stuff];
textrule[z_] := {
   Text[t_, {x_, y_}, stuff___] :> Text[t, {x, y, z}, stuff], 
   Text[t_, stuff___] :> Text[t, {0, 0, z}, stuff] (* default coords *)
   };
```

Some primitives like `Circle` don't have a direct 3D analogue, so we have to do a bit more work:

```
circle3d[{x_, y_}, r_, z_] := BSplineCurve[
   {{r, 0, z}, {r, r, z}, {-r, r, z}, {-r, 0, z}, {-r, -r, z}, {r, -r,
      z}, {r, 0, z}},
   SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1},
   SplineWeights -> {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1},
   SplineDegree -> 2];
circlerule[z_] := {
  Circle[{x_, y_}, r_?NumberQ, stuff___] :> circle3d[{x, y}, r, z],
  Circle[{x_, y_}, stuff___] :> circle3d[{x, y}, 1, z], (* default radius *)
  Circle[stuff___] :> circle3d[{0, 0}, 1, z] (* default coords and radius *)
  }
```

This spline construction is just from the help on `BSplineCurve`. It only works for a full circle, not arcs. For a full treatment of circles in space see [(10957)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957).

Further rules for `Point`, `GraphicsComplex`, `Polygon`, etc., are left as an exercise to the reader.

Now we can put it together to make our 3D graphic.  `FullGraphics` is used to get Mathematica to provide the 2D primitives.

```
allrules[z_] := Flatten@Through[{linerule, textrule, circlerule}[z]];

Graphics3D[Table[First@FullGraphics@g@z /. allrules[z], {z, 2, 5}], BoxRatios -> {1,1,2}]
```

[image: stack2]

(This Q&A brought to you by the moderators' tireless efforts in cleaning up old and dead questions).

Answer (score 7):

You could  also do:

```
g[z_] := ParametricPlot3D[{{2 Cos[t] + Cos[z t], 2 Sin[t] - Sin[z t], 
     z}, {3 Cos[t], 3 Sin[t], z}, {Cos[t], Sin[t], z}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Hue[z/5]}, Black, Black}];
```

then,

```
plt = Show[Table[g@z, {z, 2, 5}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can rescale as desired wrt box ratios or z.

The following is a ham-fisted way to put text in... the "4" is not ideal but a quick way to deal with filled curve of "4". Others will have nicer and better approaches.

Some code to get process text

```
t[s_, z_] := 
 With[{g = 
    Show[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
      Text[Style[s, FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontSize -> 3]], _Text]]},
  p = {##, z} & @@@ g[[1, 1]];
  res = Cases[g, (Polygon | Line)[x__] :> x, Infinity];
  If[Length@res == 1, {Hue[z/5], 
    Polygon@p[[res[[1, 1]]]]}, {{Hue[z/5], 
     Polygon[p[[res[[1]]]]]}, {FaceForm[White], 
     Polygon[p[[res[[2]]]]]}}]
  ]
```

Visualizing:

```
txt = Graphics3D[Table[t[ToString@j, j], {j, 2, 5}]];
Show[plt, txt, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Post script: I borrowed the `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` from a recent [MSE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/1997) and copied (& pasted) and adapted...though I admit not best use.