# How to remove a LocalSymbol (or CloudSymbol)?

Tags: programming, symbols, wolfram-cloud

In version 10.2 `LocalSymbol` can be used to create a persistent store of a variable.  Once this is created I don't see a method to remove it.  How are are they removed.

```
LocalSymbol["MySolution"] = 7
```

This will create a "MySolution" file in `$LocalSymbolBase`.  All these attempts to remove it fail.

```
ClearAll[LocalSymbol["MySolution"]]

LocalSymbol["MySolution"] =.

Remove[LocalSymbol["MySolution"]]

DeleteFile[FileNameJoin[{$LocalSymbolBase, "MySolution"}]]
```

How are these symbols cleaned up?  Similarly, how would you clean up a `CloudSymbol`?

Comment: Perhaps `DeleteFile[LocalObject["MySolution", $LocalSymbolBase]` ?

Comment: @ilian Yes, that does work. Thanks.  Not very intuitive, though.  I hope this is added to `LocalSymbol`'s documentation. Or better yet a DeleteLocalSymbol or RemoveLocalSymbol function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cloud symbols are stored in cloud objects (under [`$CloudSymbolBase`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24CloudSymbolBase.html)) and local symbols are stored in local objects 
(under [`$LocalSymbolBase`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24LocalSymbolBase.html)), which can be addressed using [`CloudObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html) and [`LocalObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalObject.html) respectively.

[`DeleteFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteFile.html) can be used for both cloud and local objects, for example

```
DeleteFile[CloudObject["MySolution", $CloudSymbolBase]]

DeleteFile[LocalObject["MySolution", $LocalSymbolBase]]
```

Comment: Is [this bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/12) known to WRI? I received no response when I reported it in July and it still crashes in v10.2 (CASE:3386543).

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it is fixed.

Comment: @ilian Oh,you mean that you are a officail-person of wolfram-research?I'm a Chinese user,I want to post a annoy bug that the function of search is so bad in our local version of 10.2,even that I cannon search the MorphologicalTransform in the offical-documentation.And another bug is about the image-tool,it is a good tool to get a mask of pictrue.But it will freezed in evey time I take a draw.Fixed it as soon as,please.