# Random points around the given curve

Tags: plotting, random, regions

How to plot a random points around the following [Helix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html) curve?

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 π, 4 π}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[Large]}, 
 Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image: helix]

Maximal distance from the given curve to random points is $0.5$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `RandomPoint[]` with `TubeMesh[]` (routines from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119886) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11452)) does the job:

```
helix = First[Cases[Normal[ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 π, 4 π},
                                           MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 75]],
                   Line[l_] :> l, ∞]];

tube = TubeMesh[helix, 1/2, "CapForm" -> "Round"];
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; 
Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[1], Point[RandomPoint[tube, 5000]]}]]
```

[image: random points around helix]

Comment: I find it terribly amusing that this has more votes than the answer I linked to, which has the actual routines. :P

Answer (score 8):

**This answer is based on a different line of reasoning than [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133685/22013).**

---

```
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 Pi, 
    4 Pi}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[Large]}, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 150];
```

After inspecting `FullForm @ plot`, one can extract a `Line` with `Cases[FullForm @ plot, _Line, Infinity]` and transform it to a `Cylinder` (`Tube` would be more straightforward, but it's not a `Region`):

```
Show[plot /. Line[z_] :> Cylinder[Partition[z, 2, 1], 0.5], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks good, so

```
reg = Cases[FullForm @ plot, _Line, Infinity] /. 
   Line[z_] :> Cylinder[Partition[z, 2, 1], 0.5] // First
```

and then

```
points = RandomPoint[reg, 1000];
```

to give

```
Show[plot, ListPointPlot3D @ points]
```

[image]

---

```
line = Cases[FullForm @ plot, _Line, Infinity][[1]];
dist = RegionDistance[line, #] & /@ points; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {63.0501, Null}

```
Histogram @ dist
```

[image]

The distance from the curve has a peculiar distribution, though.

---

---

**Previous answer**

Employing `RandomPoint @ Ball`:

```
Clear[plot, data, line, dist]

f[t_] := {6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}

c = ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, -2 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[Large]}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 150];

plot = ListPointPlot3D @ (data = 
  Table[RandomPoint @ Ball[f[t], 0.5], {t, -2 Pi, 4 Pi, 0.01}]);

Show[c, plot]
```

[image]

---

Checking the distance distribution:

```
line = Cases[FullForm @ c, _Line, Infinity][[1]];
dist = RegionDistance[line, #] & /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {120.033, Null}

```
Length @ dist
```

> 1885

```
Histogram @ dist
```

[image]

Comment: That is the correct distribution. Consider a cross-section, which is a disk: there are a lot of points at distance $0.5$ but only one point at distance $0$ :) More formally, the probability density at $d$ is proportional to the measure of the set of points at distance $d$, which is the surface area of the tube of radius $d$ and increases linearly with $d$.

Comment: I'll put it here, I guess: it seems to me that the `Table[(* stuff *), {t, -2 π, 4 π, 0.01}]` is one source of non-uniformity in your generator, and `With[{t = RandomReal[{-2 π, 4 π}]}, RandomPoint[Ball[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, 0.5]]]` removes that non-uniformity. As for the cylinder-based approach, that misses sampling the spherical caps at both ends of the curve (think of the difference between `Tube[]` with `CapForm["Round"]` and `CapForm["Butt"]`).

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to define a random collection of points that all fall within a distance 0.5 of the curve.  If a uniform distribution within a "tube" of radius 0.5 surrounding the curve is what you want and have a newer version of *Mathematica*, then @J.M.'s answer is the way to go.

If you have an older version of *Mathematica*, here is a brute-force approach:

```
(* Random error about curve no farther than 0.5 *)
n = 1000;
(* Random points within a uniform box around curve *)
r0 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.5, 0.5}], 3 n];
rC = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.5, 0.5}], 3 n];
rS = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.5, 0.5}], 3 n];
(* Keep the first n points that are within 0.5 of the curve *)
error = Select[Transpose[{rC, rS, r0}], Norm[#] <= 0.5 &, n];

(* Random position along curve *)
rt = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-2 π, 4 π}], n];

(* Show resulting cloud of points and curve *)
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 π, 4 π},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[Large]},
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 150],
 ListPointPlot3D[Transpose[{6 Cos[rt], 6 Sin[rt], rt}] + error, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]
```

[image: 3D points and curve]

Comment: Rejection sampling is nice if you don't have anything else. On that note: `error = Select[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {3 n, 3}], Norm[#] <= 0.5 &, n];` looks to be a shorter way to go about your initial sampling.

Comment: @J.M.  Agreed.  Other than good examples like yours, I wonder how someone who uses *Mathematica* for statistical analysis would stumble across the "mesh" functions which can make random sampling in regions much simpler than a brute-force algebraic approach.  I guess that's my main issue with *Mathematica*.  There's so much in areas that I would unlikely venture into but could simplify my life greatly.

Comment: For reference, here's another equivalent sampling approach: `With[{t = RandomReal[{-2 π, 4 π}], v = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3], y = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1]]}, {6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t} + r v/Sqrt[y^2 + v.v]]` (`r` being the radius of the tubular neighborhood).

Answer (score 4):

```
f[t_] := {6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}

c = ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, -2 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[Large]}, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 150];
```

The idea is to:

1. pick randomly a parameter `t0` on the curve;
2. make a vector `f'[t0]` tangent to the curve at `t0`;
3. choose a random vector `n`;
4. create with a cross product a vector `cross` of length `0.5`, and perpendicular to `f'[t0]` and `n`;
5. choose a random point on a line joining the points `f[t0]` and `f[t0] + cross`.

The above is gathered as

```
rand := Block[{t0, n, cross},
  t0 = RandomReal[{-2 Pi, 4 Pi}];
  n = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
  cross = Normalize @ Cross[n, f'[t0]]/2;
  RandomPoint @ Line[{f[t0], f[t0] + cross}]
  ]
```

Generate `1000` such points:

```
plot = ListPointPlot3D @ (data = Table[rand, {1000}]);

Show[c, plot]
```

[image]

Distribution of the distances of the points to the curve (see also [my second answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133699/22013)):

```
line = Cases[FullForm @ c, _Line, Infinity][[1]];
dist = RegionDistance[line, #] & /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {62.6192, Null}

```
Histogram @ dist
```

[image]

is uniform.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, this is the *incorrect* distribution for this problem. See the figures at the beginning of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html; you are creating the left distribution rather than the right.

Comment: @Rahul The OP only wrote that he wants "random points around the curve". He didn't specify according to which distribution. I gave three different methods that give three sets of points sampled from different distributions. How can you say which one is "correct"? In other words: is a Gaussian distribution "more correct" than a triangular distribution? Your plea (and downvote, if it was yours) is unjustified in the context of the question.

Comment: Technically you are correct, and technically [this](http://xkcd.com/221/) is a random number generator. However I would downvote it too if it was posted as a way to generate a random number between 1 and 10.

Comment: @Rahul So [this](https://imgur.com/a/N4hBp) is a random distribution for you, but [this](https://imgur.com/a/APg28) is not? And <"technically you are correct", but I'll downvote anyway> - congrats on that reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows.

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]},
PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[Large]},
Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 150];
b = Table[{6 Cos[t], 6 Sin[t], t}, {t, -2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi], .1}];
c = Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.5, 0.5}], 3], {t, -2 \[Pi], 
4 \[Pi], .1}];
Show[a, ListPointPlot3D[b + c]]
```

[image]

Addition.

```
c = Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.5^(1/2)/3, 0.5^(1/2)/3}], 
3], {t, -2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi], .1}];
N[0.5^(1/2)/3]
```

> 0.235702

is exacter.