# 3D Printing 1D Contour Plot

Tags: plotting, 3d-printing

I know for surfaces Mathematica 11 has thickening options for 3D printing.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/increase-3d-graph-thickness-for-3d-printing-in-mathematica) for example.

If I have an *explicit* parametrization of a *spatial* curve, like the twisted cubic, I can create a tube like this and export to stl:

```
Export["twistedcubictube.stl" , ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] + x, Cos[t] + x^2, x^3}, {x, -2, 2}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]]
```

However, I do not see how to create such a tube if my curve(s) are obtained *implicitly* through ContourPlot (in the *plane*).

Anyone have any ideas?

As a test case, I would like to create small tubes around these curves:

```
ContourPlot[{-2 + y^2 - z, 1 - 2 y^2 + y^2 z + z - z^2}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

and 3D Print them.

**UPDATE:** I just did this which seems to be working (3D printer is trying to print as I type...might still need to play with the thicknesses to get it to actually print):

```
Export["test.stl", ContourPlot3D[{-2 + y^2 - z, 1 - 2 y^2 + y^2 z + z - z^2}, {x,  0, .1}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Extrusion -> 0.05]]
```

But that solves the problem by turning the curves into a thin surface and then thickening up that thin surface.  That should work in general, but I would still like to know how to create a tubular neighborhood around an *implicitly* defined curve in *Mathematica* (in the plane or in space).

Comment: `Cases[Normal@
   ContourPlot[{-2 + y^2 - z, 1 - 2 y^2 + y^2 z + z - z^2}, {y, -5, 
     5}, {z, -5, 5}], 
  Line[x_] :> Tube[x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ} :> {a, b, 0}, .2], 
  Infinity] // Graphics3D[#, Boxed -> False] &`?

Comment: That looks good!  I am trying it now.

Comment: You could combine the methods of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972) with the methods of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119886) to get your 3D-printable tubes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cases[Normal @ ContourPlot[{-2 + y^2 - z, 1 - 2 y^2 + y^2 z + z - z^2},
   {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}], Line[x_] :> 
  Tube[x /. {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ} :> {a,0,b}, .05], Infinity] // 
 Graphics3D[#, Boxed -> False] &
```

[image]