# How to print greek letters in wrapped text

Tags: graphics, fonts, character-encoding

Here some code for creating wrapped text

```
Clear["Global`*"];

text[txt_, p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
With[{l = text[txt]}, {{l /. {x_Real, 
   y_Real} :> (p1 + y)/p2 {Sin[1/p3 x + p4], Cos[1/p3 x + p4]}}}] 
text[txt_String] := 
   text[txt] = 
   Cases[First[
   First[ImportString[
  ExportString[
   Style[txt, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 9.5], "PDF"], 
  "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]], 
   FilledCurve[a__] :> {EdgeForm[Black], Black, FilledCurve[a]}, 
   Infinity]
```

which works fine with English letters

```
 g1 = Graphics[text["HAPPY BIRTHDAY JOHN", 33, 30, 15, -1]]
```

[image]

However if we use Greek letters

```
g2 = Graphics[text["ΧΡΟΝΙΑ ΠΟΛΛΑ ΓΙΑΝΝΗ", 33, 30, 15, -1]]
```

[image]

these are not printed in the correct format. Why? is there a way to print them correctly?

I use Mathematica v9.0.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine in 11.2 macOS 10.13

Comment: It also works fine on 9.0 in Windows.

Comment: @M.R. You are right! I also tested it in another computer with Win7 and v11.0 and the Greek letters are printed fine.

Comment: Try the discretize region approach. The PDF export probably messed things up.

Comment: @b3m2a1 What exact;y do you mean? Could you please post a simple answer?

Comment: I simply meant use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/38205) process to get your text graphics.