# Label area on plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I created the following plot using *Mathematica*:

[image: Mathematica plot]

```
(* defining functions *)
msp[h_, a_, b_, c_] := 
   Piecewise[{{c + b*(1.5*h/a - 0.5*(h/a)^3), h <= a}, {0, h == 0}}, b + c];
mex[h_, a_, b_, c_] := Piecewise[{{c + b*(1 - Exp[(-3*h)/a]), h != 0}}, 0];
mga[h_, a_, b_, c_] := Piecewise[{{c + b*(1 - Exp[(-(3*h)^2)/a^2]), 0 < h}}, 0];

(* plot *)
Show[Plot[{msp[x, 2, 3, 1], mex[x, 2, 3, 1], mga[x, 2, 3, 1]}, {x, 0, 2.5},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 5}}], ImageSize -> {500, 400}]
```

I would like to mark the y axis from 0 to 1 and the x axis from 0 to 2 using curly braces like it is done here (E(x)):

[image: Example]

Is it possible to do this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: I don't know, but would you consider an alternative way of highlighting a region, say `Show[your stuff, Graphics[{Pink, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]}]]` ?

Comment: Related question: [Scale Insetted Characters to Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4374/245)

Comment: The linked question only answers my question for vertical braces, but I would also like to draw them horizontally to mark areas on the x-axis. @b.gatessucks Thanks for that, but I already have an alternative. However, I would like to use the braces instead.

Comment: @spinut Did you look at [the angle argument in this answer?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4387/1517)

Comment: @ssch This answer actually provided the best solution for me: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4377/5321 Thanks for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The comments seemed to have covered most of the question, but the specific issue of how to best use a curly brace to label an interval in a plot may deserve a more detailed answer. It seems to me that this kind of brace is very commonly needed and represents something in between an arrow and a text label. It's like an arrow in that it has to stretch while maintaining the size of its curly ends.

So I implemented a curly brace by using the `Arrow` command with "curly" `Arrowheads`. In addition, one of the four arrow heads in this construction can also be used to insert a **text label**. While the `Graphics` in `Arrowheads` is scaled in relation to the image size, any *text* appearing in it does *not* get rescaled. This is a feature that works to our advantage here.

```
braceLabel[{p1_, p2_}, lbl_, scale_: .02] := {
  Arrowheads[{
    {
     scale, 0,
     {Graphics@Circle[{1, -1}, 1, {Pi/2, Pi}], -1}
     },
    {
     scale, 1,
     {Graphics[{Circle[{-1, 1}, 1, {-Pi/2, 0}], 
        Inset[lbl, {0, 2}]}], 1}}
    }],
  Arrow[{p1, (p1 + p2)/2}],
  Arrowheads[{
    {scale, 0,
     {Graphics@Circle[{1, 1}, 1, {Pi, 3 Pi/2}], -1}},
    {scale, 1,
     {Graphics@Circle[{-1, -1}, 1, {0, Pi/2}], 1}}
    }],
  Arrow[{(p1 + p2)/2, p2}]
  }
```

Here is an example showing how to choose the arguments of the `braceLabel`:

```
With[{
  startPoint = {0, 0},
  endPoint = {3, 1}, 
  scale = .02
 },
 Graphics[
  braceLabel[
   {startPoint, endPoint},
   Style["label", Larger],
   scale
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: brace]

In `braceLabel`, the last argument (`scale`) is optional.

To illustrate how the scaling of various parts (curly ends, label and stretching) are all automatically taken care of by `Arrow` with the various offsets I chose, here is a movie where I change some parameter periodically:

[image: parameterChanges]

It was generated with this command:

```
pl = Table[
   Plot[{msp[x, 2, 3, 1], mex[x, 2, 3, 1], mga[x, 2, 3, 1]}, {x, 0, 
     2.5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 5}},
    Epilog -> {
      Red,
      braceLabel[
       {{.5, .9}, stretch {.9, 1.9}},
       Style["label", Larger],
       .02
       ],
      Blue,
      braceLabel[
       {{1, 1}, {2, 1}},
       Style["label", Larger],
       .015 stretch]
      }
    ],
   {stretch, 1, 2, .1}];

Export["m.gif", Join[pl, Most[Reverse[pl]]], 
 "AnimationRepitions" -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> .07]
```

The label text can be styled, as shown. It can also be rotated by enclosing it, e.g., in `Rotate["A", -90 Degree]`.

On an unrelated note - the question title could also be interpreted in a more general way. Then it should be mentioned that standard arrows and text labels can easily be added using the [Drawing Tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html).

Comment: This is a great solution and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Congrats on the 20k! :)

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks - and spinut, I'm glad it helped.