# Export in Manipulate, infinite loop

Tags: export, manipulate, infinite-loop

I want to  make export of a plot inside Manipulate, but only once. However, this code runs infinitely and does export infinitely:

```
Manipulate[Module[{pl},
  pl = Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}];
  Export["pl.pdf", pl];
  pl]
 , {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

If I remove Export[] from Manipulate, problem disappears, but I need it inside Manipulate for other reason;)

Can we control number of evaluations of certain code inside Manipulate?

Comment: Can you please add version information? Which OS and which Mathematica version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

It is a Dynamic problem. Export seems to be tagged dynamic somewhere. This is workaround. When I saw this, I remembered similar problem few days ago, and I used the same trick given there and it worked.

I set `SynchronousUpdating -> False` and `ContinuousAction -> False` else it will be very slow since you'll be trying to make a pdf file for each small tick change. Now a PDF file will be created when you release the mouse only from the slider.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; (*so we know where the PDF file is *)

Manipulate[

 Module[{x},
  pl = Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}];
  myExport["myPlot.pdf", pl];
  pl
  ],

 {a, 1, 4},
 {b, 0, 10},

 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 ContinuousAction -> False,

 Initialization :> 
  (
   myExport[type_String, p_] := myExport[type, p] = Export[type, p]
   )
 ]
```

reference: [Manipulate keeps updating due to a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29627/manipulate-keeps-updating-due-to-a-function/0#0)

**Update**

The problem as I saw it, is *why* Manipulate continue to update when using an `Export` when though `Export` is clearly not updating any of the control variables. On V 9.01, these are animations showing the problem. First animation is the original code posted above, and the second one, after adding `SynchronousUpdating -> False`.

The real question I assumed why: Why does this happen.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What about this (sans `Module`):

```
Manipulate[pl = Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}, 
Button["Export", Export["pl.pdf", pl]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "Clean clean" ♪ ♫ +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard whuzzat (non sequitur)?

Comment: Well, I looked at your answer and thought "that's clean."  Then I thought of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpmoadE1y-I&hd=1).  Yes, I know I'm weird. :o)

Comment: LOL! Now I have to get that out of my head, thank you :-)

Comment: But really the question was on `why` using `Export` was causing a Continuous updating since it should not be the case. I say this is bug or bad design somewhere in export. The 2 solutions given are simply work around. The problem itself has not gone away, because again, calling `export[]` should not have caused this. Even when adding `SynchronousUpdating -> False` which means do not time out, the Continuous updating is still there.

Comment: @Nasser Wait a minute, you mean it's exporting even when you're not moving the sliders?  I do not have that problem in v7.

Comment: I mean, if you add `SynchronousUpdating -> False` and do nothing, you'll see the cell bar on the right busy. even if you wait 20 minutes, it is still busy. Clearly the PDF has been exported by now. Yet it is busy. So this means it is calling itself again and again, but that should NOT be the case, as one is not touching the sliders. That is what I mean. The problem has not been solved. These are just work arounds. `If a dynamic object has the setting SynchronousUpdating->False, the front end will queue up its evaluation, and allow it to be performed asynchronously`

Comment: @Nasser I am presuming the OP simply wants to export at will at some point and not automaically after each update.

Comment: Well, they did put the `Export` inside the Manipulate expression. So this meant to me, they wanted to export a new pdf file for each change in the plot they make when moving the slider. Else why put the export inside? But this is besides the issue. The real problem remains. Manipulate should not be updating all the time as it does, in particular, when adding `SynchronousUpdating->False`. This is my point. Export is not updating the control variables any where. So there is no reason for Manipulate to keep calling itself.

Comment: @Nasser Since I'm not seeing the behavior you describe this is (apparently) version specific; please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not know what version the OP has. I'll add a comment to OP to add version information. I am on V 9.0. I'll add an animated GIF in my answer to show the problem also.