# Plot prime numbers in spiral form, in the clockwise direction

Tags: plotting, prime-numbers

I want to plot first 100 Prime numbers in circular format (on circular orbit) in Mathematica.

How can i do this?

[image]

Comment: This is closely related to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109982/how-to-make-the-digits-of-%CF%80-go-around-in-a-spiral-like-this

Comment: What that image has to do with the question? If that's the goal, take a look at `ListPolarPlot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took a bit of work to get the plot going in the clockwise direction, and to get the origin of the polar plot on the top rather than on the right, but this should do the trick,

```
With[{nprimes = 50},
 ListPolarPlot[
  Table[{Mod[π/2 - n 4 π/nprimes, 2 π], Prime[n]}, {n, 
    nprimes}], PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarTicks -> {Table[{n π/180, Mod[90 - n, 360]}, {n, 0, 360, 
      45}], Automatic},
  PolarGridLines -> Automatic,
  Joined -> True,
  Mesh -> Full,
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red],
  PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> 1.2 Prime[nprimes]]
 ]
```

[image]