# Plot a alphabetic character in 2D

Tags: plotting

I was wondering how I can graphically plot an alphabetic character, for example D, in 2 dimension, using mathematica? I was using ListPlot with specific x and y values but it's not looking anything like a D...

Help would be appriciated! :)

This is my current D:

[image]

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719)?

Comment: I looked through the link right now, but that's not how I need to make it work. Thanks though:)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: A bit unclear...  do you want 2D coordinates for a given character or simply text in 2D...  for the second, look (rather anticlimactically)  at `Text`.

Comment: Obviously `ListPlot` can work only if you add more points. Maybe you want [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4387/245)?

Comment: See [Making Formulas… for Everything—From Pi to the Pink Panther to Sir Isaac Newton](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) and [Character edge finding](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/637/character-edge-finding)

Comment: I just want to plot a D with points (x,y) values. I have five points right now, but maybe that's why I get this.

Comment: Yes, that's why you get this. But do you want a smooth curve, or just a way to calculate more points? It's not clear.

Answer (score 13):

How about discretizing the letter's boundary?

```
stringBoundary[char_String] := 
  RegionBoundary[DiscretizeGraphics[First@ImportString[ExportString[char, "PDF"]]]]

stringBoundary["D"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible in v11.0+ with `ImageMesh` and `Rasterize`. The `RasterSize` ends up  affecting mesh quality here:

```
RegionBoundary@ImageMesh@ColorNegate@Rasterize["любо",RasterSize->400]
```

[image: text boundary]

You could also just get the edge by using a `FillingTransform` to ignore the interior of shapes:

```
RegionBoundary@ImageMesh@FillingTransform@ColorNegate@Rasterize["D", RasterSize -> 400]
```

[image: hole plugged mesh]

Comment: To get the points on the D shape, just use `MeshCoordinates`.