# Obtaining Size Of Graphical Objects

Tags: graphics

I have created a panel, say `Panel[""]`. I want to know its size/dimensions. Is there any built-in function for doing that?

Comment: Do you want to interpret a `Panel` object as an image? It is not a good idea because `Panel` is a kind of dynamic expression in Mathematica. Only "static" objects have dimensions and size (for example, `Image`).

Comment: The problem here is pretty much the same as in [Computing the bounding boxes for Text objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4152/245).

Answer (score 2):

You could get the size of the rasterized panel:

```
Rasterize[Panel[""]][[2]]
```

> ImageSize -> {18, 33}

```
Rasterize[Panel["What is my size?"]][[2]]
```

> ImageSize -> {97, 33}

[image]

Comment: Does this operation Resize the actual panel ?

Comment: @santhosh I don't think so. Look at the picture above.