# How can text-specific antialiasing be disabled in Rasterize?

Tags: graphics, antialiasing

While tinkering with the code in the [Falling Matrix question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20557/playing-with-matrix-falling-code-in-mathematica/20583#20583), I was hoping to improve the rendering speed by making the rasterizations of the text grayscale. I changed the base color of the text to white and left the background black. However, this did not yield a grayscale raster. The problem seems to be that *Mathematica* tries to help with the readability of text by using special antialiasing schemes.

Consider the following test:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Rasterize[#, Background -> Black, RasterSize -> 15, 
    ImageSize -> 150] & /@ {Style["\[FilledCircle]", White], 
   Graphics[{White, Disk[]}]}]
```

[image: Antialiased disk test]

Interesting and (I think) undocumented, but the relevant question for me is: How can I control or eliminate this behavior? Adding a `ColorConvert[#,"Grayscale"]` or just taking the `Norm`s of the `ImageData` gives an acceptable result but is pretty slow.

Comment: I can confirm on mma 9.0.0 & 8.0.4 on win7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way would be to extract the text outline as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/638/5) (scroll to the end) and rasterize the resulting graphics. First, define a convenient function:

```
textGraphics[t_String | t_Style] := Graphics@First@First@
    ImportString[ExportString[t, "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"];
```

We can see this in action:

```
textGraphics /@ {Style["A", FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Times"], "B"} // Row
```

[image]

If you now try your example above and apply this function on the styled text, you should get this:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a problem when using this for characters that do not fill much of the monospace-character box. You could use an explicit `PlotRange` to restore it, but is there some a priori way to know what the correct bounding box will be?

Comment: @Xerxes Perhaps something like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4162/5

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the most practical solution is probably [@rm's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20623/12).

Mathematica simply uses your operating system's font renderer.  If you disable subpixel antialiasing at the operating system level, it will be disabled in Mathematica too.  It is possible to do this on all of Windows, OS X and Linux, but the procedures are different.   However, you may not want to do this permanently as it's going to reduce the readability of text in every program.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is closely related to my own question: [Poor anti-aliasing in Rotated text with ClearType on](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18988/121).

**EDIT**: This apparently only works in Windows systems.

The [same solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19007/121), `Opacity` of anything other than one, can be applied:

```
GraphicsRow[
 Rasterize[#, Background -> Black, RasterSize -> 15, ImageSize -> 150] & /@ {Style[
    "\[FilledCircle]", White, Opacity[0.9999]], Graphics[{White, Disk[]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Opacity[2]` also works on my system.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me (v9 Linux) using `Opacity[2]`, `Opacity[0.999]` or `FontOpacity->0.999`.

Comment: @Xerxes I'm sorry to hear that.  It does work on Windows.  I hope you find a solution; if you do please post an answer for my question too.

Comment: It doesn't work on OS X v9 either.  Just include a note that this is a solution for Windows :) (and +1)

Comment: @Xerxes Out of curiosity what happens if you `Rotate` the text by 45° before rasterizing?

Comment: @Szabolcs Same question to you, please.

Comment: +1 I tried `RGBColor[0.999,0.999,0.999]` even before I saw your answer in case that the "special" rasterizing is only used in special cases, but alas, it works for all colours)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I still get subpixel-optimized AA when using `Rotate`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Which question?

Comment: @Szabolcs I meant what happens if you `Rotate`?  Perhaps only on Windows is sub-pixel AA incomplete; by that I mean isn't used for rotated or partially transparent text.  Amusing now that those failings would have been useful here.

Comment: @Ajasja On Windows colored text still gets the ClearType treatment but rotated or different opacity text does not.  FYI.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it seems rotated text still gets subpixel antialiasing on OS X.