# Rasterize and Graphics, size difference

Tags: graphics, rasterize

I am writing my own `TreeForm` function and for this I want to make sure that framed text boxes in `Graphics` do not overlap. First, I set up a function that returns a framed box with some expression in it:

```
ExpBox[exp_]:=Text[Framed[Style[exp, 12], FrameMargins->5],FormatType->StandardForm]  
ExpBox[exp_, xy_]:=Text[Framed[Style[exp, 12], FrameMargins->5],xy,
                                                           FormatType->StandardForm]
```

I measure the width of such a box using `Rasterize`. Consider, for example, the two expressions

```
exp1=Fooooo*2;  
exp2=Bar;
```

with the width

```
w1=First@Rasterize[ExpBox[exp1], "RasterSize"]
w2=First@Rasterize[ExpBox[exp2], "RasterSize"]
```

With those values I can set up a graphics with two nonoverlapping text boxes

```
Graphics[{ExpBox[exp1, {w1/2, 0}], ExpBox[exp2, {w1 + w2/2, 0}]},
                 PlotRange -> {{0, w1 + w2}, {-20, 20}}, ImageSize -> {w1 + w2, 40}]
```

and I get (as desired)

[image: correct frames]

However, this does not work correctly as soon as a division is found within any of the expressions:

```
exp1=Fooooo/2;
```

[image: incorrect frames]

The reason seems to be that, if there happens to be a division in an expression, then the `ExpBox` is "printed" at smaller size without a containing `Graphics` function.

How can I avoid this difference? Or is there another way to get the width of such a box?

Comment: I notice that `Row[{ExpBox[Fooooo*2], ExpBox[Bar]}]` gives the same output as your original function, is there a reason not to do it like that instead?

Comment: I want to write a `TreeForm` variant and for this I also need to connect various boxes with `Line`s. I also need vertical alignment of boxes. For this I need the coordinates of the boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width returned by `Rasterize` is not always correct, as you found out, and since you aren't going to `Rasterize` before building your tree then the size of the raster graphics is irrelevant in this case.

This is the best way to get the size of the text cell (thanks to [Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4162/9490)),

```
{w1, h1} = ImageDimensions@ImageCrop@Graphics@ExpBox[Fooooo/2];
{w2, h2} = ImageDimensions@ImageCrop@Graphics@ExpBox[Bar];
```

Of course, you can just grab the width by using `First` as in your code, but I also noticed that the height needs adjusting in the latter case.

Then you can plot

```
With[{h = Max[{h1, h2}]},

 Graphics[{ExpBox[Fooooo/2, {w1/2, 0}], ExpBox[Bar, {w1 + w2/2, 0}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, w1 + w2}, h {-.5, .5}}, 
  ImageSize -> {w1 + w2, h}]
 ]
```

[image]

I'm the type that always makes a function for something I'm doing more than twice, so you can wrap it all up like this:

```
combBoxes[exps__] := Module[{widths, heights, boxes, totalsize},
  {widths, heights} = 
   Transpose@(ImageDimensions@ImageCrop@Graphics@ExpBox@# & /@ {exps});
  heights = {Total@widths, Max@heights};
  widths = 
   Total[widths[[;; #]]] - widths[[#]]/2 & /@ Range@Length@widths;
  boxes = ExpBox[#1, {#2, 0}] & @@@ Transpose[{{exps}, widths}];
  Graphics[boxes, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, heights[[1]]}, heights[[2]] {-.5, .5}}, 
   ImageSize -> heights]
  ]

combBoxes[Foooooo/2, Bar]
combBoxes[This, is, how, I, would, make, these, boxes, 
 FooooooooBaaarrrrr^2/2]
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick, thanks.

Comment: I just noticed that this solution only works if the expressions whose width is measured happen to be small enough to fit in the standard size of `Graphics`. The width of very large boxes is always measured as 360.