# Insufficient size of Graphics

Tags: graphics

The following code returns a framed text box that is longer than the standard width of `Graphics'.

```
Graphics@Text@Framed@Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18]
```

[image: incomplete framed box]

Is there a way to automatically increase the size of the `Graphics` that is returned to fit the entire framed box?

(This question is related to my question [Rasterize and Graphics, size difference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105480/rasterize-and-graphics-size-difference) and its answer. In particular, one cannot use `Rasterize' to determine the width of the box, it seems.)

Comment: Win OS 7 x 64 Mathematica v10.2 - does not reproduce whats stated in OP

Comment: I do see what the OP described (i.e. clipping of the frame on the left and right side of the picture) on MMA 10.3.1.0 on Win7-64bit. It's quite weird actually.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the front end method to determine the width does not account for the full size of the frame.

To fix/work around you can add margins to the text and rasterize before passing it to `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[
 Rasterize[
  Text[Framed[Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18], 
   ImageMargins -> 50]], RasterSize -> 800]]
```

[image: raster]

### EDIT

As @Algohi pointed out in the comments (thanks!) we could use a pure function to **automatically** determine the size of the raster, and pass to Graphics, lending to a solution using native Text object with a specified size:

```
Graphics[Text@#, Options[Rasterize@#, ImageSize]] &[
 Framed[Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18]]]
```

[image: edit raster]

Comment: This will make it automatic `Graphics[Text@#, Options[Rasterize@#, ImageSize]] &[
 Framed[Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18]]]`

Comment: @Algohi N
ice- I incorporated this into an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To make it automatic without rasterizing use `ImageSize->Full`:

```
Graphics[Text@Framed@Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18], 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

or

```
Graphics[Text@Framed@Style[FooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBarFooBar, 18], 
 ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Both options increase the maximal automatic `Graphics` size from 360 to 432 but the problem persists.

Comment: @Berg What OS are you using? On Mac the entire framed text is visible. i.e. it is not longer than the standard width of `Graphics` as per your opening sentence.

Comment: I use Win 10 with MMA 10.3.1. Also, I use a 4K display and because of that a magnification of 2 (because of the low quality user interface of MMA this sometimes breaks things).