# Reconstruct text pages cut by shredder

Tags: programming, image-processing

**Q1**: I have a page of a printed text file, but it was cut by a paper shredder (from top to bottom). You can download all the paper fragments [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/824pag34atk2e7g/file1.zip). Here are some of them. How can I reconstruct it?

[image: shredded text]

**Q2**: This time, the situation is even worse - the page was cut by a shredder twice (from top to bottom and from left to right)! ([Get the fragments here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mo1ehc2qx2lk3e0/file2.zip)).

[image: really shredded text]

My code for **Q1**:

```
filenames = FileNames["*.bmp", "C:\\Users\\Liao\\Desktop\\B\\file1"];
pics = Import /@ filenames;
binarypic = Binarize[#, 0.9] & /@ pics;
binarydata = ImageData /@ binarypic;
leftandrightdata = 
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1[[All, 1]], #1[[All, -1]]} &, binarydata];
result = {};
firstPic = Select[leftandrightdata, ! MemberQ[#[[2]], 0] &][[1, 1]];
start = leftandrightdata[[firstPic]];
DeleteCases[leftandrightdata, start] //. 
      x_ /; Length[x] > 0 :> (sort = 
   SortBy[x, HammingDistance[#[[2]], start[[3]]] &];
     AppendTo[result, start = sort[[1]]]; Rest[sort]);
Extract[pics, 
Prepend[List /@ result[[All, 1]], {firstPic}]] // ImageAssemble
```

This code maybe dizzy for you, but it doesn't matter. The core idea is simple and straightforward, which use `HammingDistance` to determine whether two images can be combined together.

But for **Q2**, I can't really find a good way to solve it.

Comment: how did you manage to put that stripes to the shredder? :p

Comment: @Kuba It's a tough work! Well, actually it's a problem from a Mathematical Contest in Modeling. Now the contest have finished, so I post it here, looking forward to funny and exellent anwsers.

Comment: You can try `ImmageAssemble` at each permutation, then `TextRecognize` -> `DictionaryLookup` -> `Length`. I think it would be fun-compact-neverending :)

Comment: @Kuba It's too horrible to imagine what will happen :p

Comment: @mm.Jang Just for curiosity. This is not a real striped paper, isn't this?

Comment: Can you upload the files in a non `.rar` format? Perhaps a `.zip` or `.tar.gz`?

Comment: @Murta I suppose not, stripes fit too well :)

Comment: @rm-rf oh,I'm sorry, I have changed the links to `.zip` format.

Comment: I came up with a clever algorithm involving constructing a graph over the pieces in Q2 and then finding its maximum-weight spanning tree. But I need the edges to be labeled, and the result of Combinatorica's `MaximumSpanningTree` discards edge labels :(

Comment: is the data from Q2 the same as Q1 ? just trying to understand how the images are organised. Are the strips cut in the same amount of squares ?

Comment: @lalmei it's 19x11

Comment: @belisarius Spoiler! that is the part of the question :p

Comment: @Kuba And that is part of my answer :)

Comment: @Kuba Now seriously, I can't find a clean way without using too much heuristics (ie guessing).

Comment: @belisarius me too, with modifying my code I was able to create one full horizontal line and couple of 2-5pieces blocks. Which is ofcourse not enough. I'm afraid pieces are too small and I failed even with extracting borders of the image. For example there is a pic with only "A" in the middle :P, well I know where it should be but how to do this automatically? But since I'm not IT/algorithms spec I just wait for someone smarter answer :)

Comment: In the blockbuster movie "The tourist" they show a computer reconstructing a letter from burnt fragments. Even in the movie it was a difficult process. And ultimately it proved useless.

Comment: @magma in the movie I think the person set it on fire too, let's hope that's not the parameters for a Q3.

Comment: @RahulNarain I was able to modify a basic maximum spanning implementation of Kruskal's algorighthm, since the "finding a cycle" part of the algorithm you can just strip any edge labels. My problem is finding a good weight for the edges (Ignoring white edges).

Comment: Andrew Glassner considered this problem in [this note](http://www.glassner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/CG-CGA-PDF-02-05-Putting-the-Pieces-Together-May02.pdf); I haven't gotten around to seeing whether any of the answers below correspond to an implementation of Glassner's ideas.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the reference! It seems his clustering algorithm is similar to what I created, with some modifications so pieces don't overlap for multiple sided pieces.  The problem with the words, is that there are great matchings between wrong pieces, in all the weights methods I tried, I will expand my post to show the problems at some point. He also suggested removing white edges from the algorithm. This is a great read!

Answer (score 57):

**Q1**

```
pics = Binarize /@ (Import /@ FileNames["*.bmp"]);

(*extracting edges*)
left = ImageData[#][[All, 1]] & /@ pics; 
right = ImageData[#][[All, -1]] & /@ pics;
```

Let's find the left edge, here I'm assuming that it is all white. So if

```
pics // First // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {72, 1980}
> ```

and an image is binarized then the left edge is:

```
Total /@ left // Position[#, 1980, 1] &
```

> ```
> {{4}}
> ```

Instead of `HammingDistance` I'm calculating `Norm`:

```
cons = {4};
Do[
   With[{dists = Norm[right[[cons[[-1]]]] - #] & /@ left}, 
        AppendTo[cons, Position[dists, Min@dists, 1][[1, 1]] ]
       ]
  , {Length@pics - 1}]

ImageAssemble@pics[[cons]]
```

[image]

Comment: Scroll down, my answer only solves simple case.

Answer (score 40):

**Greedy algorithm**
(1D & 2D)

Data loading:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
data = N@ImageData@Import[#] & /@ FileNames["*.bmp"] // Developer`ToPackedArray;
n = Length[data];
```

The matching of two edges is defined by the property

$$
\frac{\mathop{\rm Var} [e_1+e_2]}{\mathop{\rm Var} [e_1-e_2]}
$$

where $\mathop{\rm Var}[X]$ is the variance of $X$

```
r = 7;
var[list_] := 
  Total[#, {3, 4}] &[(Transpose[list, {1, 2, 4, 3}] - 
     Mean@Transpose[list, {2, 3, 1, 4}])^2];
corr[list1_, list2_] := 
  var@GaussianFilter[list1 + list2, {{0, 0, r, 0}}]/(0.0001 + 
     var@GaussianFilter[list1 - list2, {{0, 0, r, 0}}]);
```

Here `r=7` is the radius of smoothing. It is very helpfull for real images (see below). `0.0001` is a small number to prevent division by zero.

The comparison each tile with each other:

```
top = corr[ConstantArray[data[[All, 1]], n], 
   Transpose@ConstantArray[data[[All, -1]], n]];
bottom = Transpose[top];
left = corr[ConstantArray[data[[All, All, 1]], n], 
   Transpose@ConstantArray[data[[All, All, -1]], n]];
right = Transpose[left];
```

Tiles in the resulting mosaic and possible positions of the next tiles:

```
tiles = SparseArray[{}, {2 n, 2 n}];
next = {};
```

The addition of the tile `num` to the position `{i,j}` of the resulting mosaic and the update of `next` tiles:

```
add[num_, {i_, j_}] := (next = DeleteCases[next, {i, j}];
  tiles[[i, j]] = num;
  left[[num, All]] = right[[num, All]] = top[[num, All]] = bottom[[num, All]] = 0.0; 
  If[tiles[[##]] == 0 && Not@MatchQ[next, {##}], AppendTo[next, {##}];] & 
      @@@ {{i, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}})
```

Quality of the matching of all possible tiles at the position `{i,j}` is just the sum of the matching with neighbors:

```
quality[i_, j_] := 
  If[#2 != 0, #[[All, #2]], 0 #[[All, 1]]] & @@@ {{left, 
      tiles[[i, j + 1]]}, {right, tiles[[i, j - 1]]}, {top, 
      tiles[[i + 1, j]]}, {bottom, tiles[[i - 1, j]]}} // Total;
```

Addition of two tiles with the best matching:

```
(add[#1, {n, n}]; add[#2, {n, n + 1}]) & @@@ Position[left, Max[left]];
```

Addition of `n-2` remaining tiles to the best positions:

```
Do[add[#2, next[[#]]] & @@ First@Position[#, Max[#]] &[quality @@@ next], {n - 2}];
```

The result for **Q1**:

```
view[margins__] := 
 Image@Flatten[#, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] &@
  Map[If[# <= 0, 1 + 0 data[[1]], data[[#]]] &, 
   tiles[[#1 ;; #2, #3 ;; #4]] &[margins], {2}]

view[Min[#1], Max[#1], Min[#2], Max[#2]] & @@ Transpose@tiles["NonzeroPositions"]
```

[image]

Unfortunately Q2 have too many blank edges to reconstruction so I use **Lena** photo

```
data = N@ImageData /@ #[[PermutationList@RandomPermutation@Length[#]]] &@
  Flatten@ImagePartition[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 64];
```

After repeating the steps above we got the result

[image]

Without smoothing of edges (see `r` above) the matching fails because of noise and fine structure (especially in the hat).

Comment: Cool! But my bounty has expired......:-/

Comment: @mm.Jang If the bounty is expired the reputation is losted? I have never started a bounty.

Comment: Very nice! My suggestion for the blank edges may be to give them huge (unnatural) weights, that way it avoids connecting any white edges, if there is no way to move across a image with blank edges (in the case of the letter) it may be a natural gap.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your weights between edges better (specifically how those transpose's are acting on the image data), since I'm not very familiar with image analysis. Are you taking a variance over each color channel ? then summing ?

Comment: @lalmei Yes, I sum squares of every edge pixel and each color channel (`Total` with parameter `{3,4}`). `Transpose` is a bit complicated, but it helps me to subtract the mean value (also with each channel separately).

Answer (score 26):

Q2: This answer has been sitting in my trunk of files for a year and a half now. I was hoping to improve it and use it to solve the original problem but never got around to it, at the moment it solves images/photos with noisy data. Might as well post it before I forget how it even works.

So I wanted to solve this problem with a Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm. I decided to use Kruskal's algorithm, the idea being that people solve a jigsaw puzzle as they find pieces that match (maybe there is a way to parallelize this). This way you build a Forest of Trees made up of the best matches. So you can stop at any moment, and in the worst case you have a bunch of larger matched pieces.

At the time my idea was to use this algorithm for the main questions and get it to a point where matching using text recognition wasn't too time consuming since now you would have less pieces with larger pieces of words on them (make a greedy algorithm that matched the pieces to maximize the number of english words it found). But even then using text recognition at the time took a very long time.

The main problem I came into was trying to make sure that when you merge two Trees the images weren't overlapping. I made a modification to make it work, I call this the Minimum Spaning Geometrical Tree. There are two functions, one that gives the relative positions of pieces in a tree `Chargeds`. And one that checks if there is a path to a specific relative position for a piece, `ChargedPath`. Here I call the positions charges, since I envisioned this for a more generalized use (e.g. particle tracking. )

The main part of the code is to build an adjacency list like this
$$  \{ node1, \{\{"up", node2\}, \{"down", node24\}, \{"left", node64\}, \cdots   \}\}, \\ \hspace{-11.5cm} \{node2, \cdots\} $$
Except instead of "up","down","left","right", I use 1,2,3,4. (maybe not in that order)

### Weights

For weights I used the same as @ybeltukov, since it works best for noisy images.

```
r = 12;
var2[list_] := Total@(Variance[#] & /@ (Thread[list]));
corr[list1_, list2_] := 
   var2@GaussianFilter[list1 - list2, {{0, 0, r, 0}}]/
   (var2@GaussianFilter[list1 + list2, {{0, 0, r, 0}}]);
```

And I organize the edge pixels as the OP.

```
testdata = #[[PermutationList@RandomPermutation@Length[#]]] &@
 Flatten@ImagePartition[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 64];
pics = testdata;

test2 = ImageData[#] & /@ pics;
test3 = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1[[All, 1]], #1[[All, -1]], 
     #1[[1, All]], #1[[-1, All]]} &, test2];
```

Then I create a distance matrix, it checks $n^2$ distance between the edges, for left/right and up/down. It would be better organized as a bipartite graph but so it is for now. Amazingly, this is the slowest part of the code.

```
n = Length[pics]
AbsoluteTiming[
 leftrightF = 
   Table[If[i == j, 64^2, N[corr[test3[[i, 3]], test3[[j, 2]]]]], {i, 
    1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
 updownF = 
   Table[If[i == j, 64^2, N[corr[test3[[i, 5]], test3[[j, 4]]]]], {i, 
   1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
]
```

### Minimum Spaning Geometrical tree

The main ingredient of the Kruskal Algorithm is that when you connect an edge you have to make you create no loops. If there is already a path between two points adding a connection between them will lead to a loop, so this function checks if there is a path between two points. I use `Throw` and `Catch` with a `While` loop for a depth-first search, and pack it all inside the `Return`. ( There might be a more efficient way to do this with `Scan`)

```
ITAPath[INadjgraph_List, point1_Integer, point2_Integer, label_: 1] :=
        Module[{adjgraph = fillin[Function[{y}, 
        {y[[1]], Function[{x}, x[[2]] ] /@ (y[[2]])}] /@ INadjgraph], 
        stack = {}, currentpos, marked},

  marked = Table[False, {i, 1, Length[adjgraph]}];
  marked[[point1]] = True;
  stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[point1, 2]]];

  Return[
     Catch[
           If[point1 == point2, Throw[True];];
           While[Length[stack] != 0,
            currentpos = Last@stack;
            stack = Drop[stack, {-1}];
            If[!marked[[currentpos]],
              If[currentpos == point2, Throw[True];];
              marked[[currentpos]] = True;
              stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[currentpos, 2]]];
            ];
           ];
           Throw[False];
           ]];
  ];
```

This is essentially a Depth-First Search Algorithm to see if there is a path (ITAP) between two points with the adjancecy list. I use a fill function to make the edges undirected in the adjacency list. For some reason I keep the adjacency list directed. ( Actually I think this is because I think the minimum weight between two edges is not always back to the same node)

The second ingredient is to make sure the new point added to the tree does not overlap ( in 2D space) with other points already in the tree.
I do this by looking up the "charge" or position of each point in the tree relative to the new point. This is done with the ChargePath function

```
ChargedPath[INadjgraph_List, point1_Integer, charge_] :=
   Module[{adjgraph = fillin2@INadjgraph, stack = {}, currentpos, 
           marked, chargem, chargeadd, side, parent},

   marked = Table[False, {i, 1, Length[adjgraph]}];
   parent = Table[Null, {i, 1, Length[adjgraph]}];
   marked[[point1]] = True;
   chargem = {0, 0};
   stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[point1, 2]]];
   Scan[
        parent[[#[[2]]]] = {chargem, point1}; &, 
        adjgraph[[point1, 2]]];

   Return[Catch[
     If[chargem == charge, Throw[True];];
     While[Length[stack] != 0,
           {side, currentpos} = Last@stack;
           stack = Drop[stack, {-1}];

     If[!marked[[currentpos]],
        chargeadd = 
        Which[side == 1, {0, -1}, 
              side == 2, {0, 1}, 
              side == 3, {-1, 0},
              side == 4, {1, 0}];
        chargem = parent[[currentpos, 1]];
        chargem = chargeadd + chargem;
        If[chargem == charge, Throw[True];];
        marked[[currentpos]] = True;
        stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[currentpos, 2]]];
        Scan[
             parent[[#[[2]]]] = {chargem, currentpos}; &, 
             adjgraph[[currentpos, 2]]];
      ];
      ];
     Throw[False];]];
 ];
```

Again it is a Depth-First Search algorithm to quickly find if there is a point with the same "charge" or position.

These are some custodial functions to filling the adjacency list with undirected edges for traversing the graph. A function to list the charges (positions) of each node in the tree.

```
fillin[adj_] := Module[{adjtest = adj},
 Scan[Function[{y},
   Scan[Function[{x},
    If[! MemberQ[adjtest[[x, 2]], y[[1]]],
           adjtest[[x, 2]] = Append[adjtest[[x, 2]], y[[1]]];
             ];
    ], y[[2]]];
  ], adjtest];
 Return[adjtest];
];
reve[y_] := Which[y == 1, 2, y == 2, 1, y == 3, 4, y == 4, 3];

fillin2[adj_] := Module[{adjtest = adj},
 Scan[Function[{y},
 Scan[Function[{x},
    If[! MemberQ[adjtest[[x[[2]], 2]], {reve[x[[1]]], y[[1]]}],

      adjtest[[x[[2]], 2]] = 
        Append[adjtest[[x[[2]], 2]], {reve[x[[1]]], y[[1]]}];
             ];
    ], y[[2]]];
 ], adjtest];
 Return[adjtest];
 ];

 Chargeds[INadjgraph_List, point1_Integer] :=
 Module[{adjgraph = fillin2@INadjgraph, stack = {}, currentpos, 
         marked, chargem, chargeadd, side, parent},

  marked = Table[False, {i, 1, Length[adjgraph]}];
  parent = Table[Null, {i, 1, Length[adjgraph]}];
  marked[[point1]] = True;

  Return[Last@Reap[
         chargem = {0, 0};
         Sow[{point1, chargem}, 1];
         stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[point1, 2]]];

         Scan[
              parent[[#[[2]]]] = {chargem, point1}; &, 
              adjgraph[[point1, 2]]];

     While[Length[stack] != 0,
           {side, currentpos} = Last@stack;
           stack = Drop[stack, {-1}];
           If[! marked[[currentpos]],
           chargeadd = 
               Which[side == 1, {-1, 0}, 
                     side == 2, {1, 0}, 
                     side == 3, {0, 1},
                     side == 4, {0, -1}];

      chargem = parent[[currentpos, 1]];
      chargem = chargeadd + chargem;

      Sow[{currentpos, chargem}, 1];

      marked[[currentpos]] = True;
      stack = Join[stack, adjgraph[[currentpos, 2]]];
      Scan[
          parent[[#[[2]]]] = {chargem, currentpos}; &, 
          adjgraph[[currentpos, 2]]];
       ];
      ];
   ]];
  ];
```

### Building the Adjacency List

#### Update: simplified the code significantly

Building the spanning tree is the following code.

The main if statements are to separate which labels to give the new edges, since we are looking at global minima of edges(up down left right). 
Once we go to the correct label that's where we check for "no loops" (kruskal algorithm for mst) and the fact that the tree's don't overlap with due to the geometry (the new part of the algorithm), on top of a bunch of checks to make sure we only have 4 edges and that edges has not been connected already to some other part of the tree.

You can also set a max weight, so that if the weight gets larger than a certain value, then the algorithm stops and just gives the remaining Forest, which you could at that point apply some additional weights to how to match up those remaining Trees.

```
MSGT[leftright_, updown_, n_, minset_: 50., LRsidesize_: 180,UDsidesize_: 72] := 
   Module[{leftrightweights = leftright, updownweights = updown,
        Adjs = Table[{i, {}}, {i, 1, n}], minlr, minud, pos, 
        location2, location1, i, k, directions, labels, 
        Adjs2, oldimage, newimage, newcount, oldcount, t},

     (*Since the result is a tree, I can only add n-1 edges*)       

     k = n - 1;

     While[k > 0,

     (*find global minimum*) 

        minlr = Min[leftrightweights];
        minud = Min[updownweights];

     (* check if the minimum is an up down edge or left right *)
      (* Once I pass by a minimum I replace it with a large weight, It might be easier or faster to just keep track of *)
        If[minlr < minud,
        pos = Position[leftrightweights, minlr];
        leftrightweights [[First@(First@pos), Last@(First@pos)]] =LRsidesize^2;
        directions = {-1, 0};
        labels = {1, 2};
        ,
        pos = Position[updownweights, minud];
        updownweights [[First@(First@pos), Last@(First@pos)]] =UDsidesize^2;
        directions = {0, 1};
        labels = {3, 4};
         ];

         location1 = pos[[1, 1]];
         location2 =  pos[[1, 2]];


      If[location1 < location2, 
         {location1, location2} = {location1, location2} /. {location1 ->location2,location2 -> location1};
         labels = RotateLeft[labels];
         directions = -directions;
       ];

       (* if the weights are less the pre-set minimum quit *)
       If[(minlr > minset && minud > minset), Break[];];

 (* Main meat of the algorithm *)    
(* I group the checks in two sets *)   
(* first set is to check if the adjacency list is being build correctly, i.e. is it full ? does another node points to it from the opposite label etc. *)

If[(MemberQ[Adjs[[location1, 2]], {Last@labels, _}]), Continue[];];
If[(MemberQ[Adjs, {Last@labels, location2}, {3}]), Continue[];];  
If[(MemberQ[Adjs, {First@labels, location1}, {3}]), Continue[];];
If[(MemberQ[Adjs[[location2, 2]], {First@labels, _}]), 
 Continue[];];

(* The second set checks is the Path check and the charge path check *)

If[(ITAPath[Adjs, location1, location2, 1]), Continue[];];
    If[(((! 
        Or[##] & @@ (ChargedPath[Adjs, 
          location1, -directions + #] & /@ (Last@
          Thread@Last@Chargeds[Adjs, location2])) && (! 
         Or[##] & @@ (ChargedPath[Adjs, location2, 
           directions + #] & /@ (Last@
           Thread@Last@Chargeds[Adjs, location1])))))),    

 Adjs[[location1, 2]] = 
  Append[Adjs[[location1, 2]], {Last@labels, location2}];
  (* I don't add the incoming edge, but you could, I don't think it affects the algorithm *)
 (*   Adjs[[location2,2]]=Append[Adjs[[location2,2]],{First@
 labels,location1}];*)  
       k--; 
    ];
    ];

     Return[Adjs];
     ];
```

Now we can finally build the adjacency tree:

```
{ttt, res3} = AbsoluteTiming@MSGT[leftrightF, updownF, n, 3];
ttt
```

> > 0.263359

```
adjtest = 
 Function[{y}, {y[[1]], Function[{x}, x[[2]] ] /@ (y[[2]])}] /@ 
 res3;
d = DeleteDuplicates[
    Sort[#] & /@ ((#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) & /@ (Flatten[
   Thread[#] & /@ adjtest, 1]))];
GraphPlot[d]
GraphPlot[d, VertexCoordinateRules -> Rule @@@ Last@Chargeds[res3, 2]]
```

[image]

### Building the image from the Adjacency List

Using `VertexRenderingFunction` this is rather simple,

```
GraphPlot[d, VertexCoordinateRules -> Rule @@@ Last@Chargeds[res3, 2],
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[Image[pics[[#2]], 
     ImageSize -> {41, 41}], #1] &)]
```

[image]

Here is an animation of the building of the puzzle for every step in MSGT,

[image]

Comment: No judgements, but it will take me a while to go through it.

Comment: @rcollyer: I wonder if anyone can find a method to reconstruct the entire Lenna image from just the piece *Mathematica* knows... ;)

Comment: Hey lalmei, I a had just started editing your answer when I saw you were doing the same. Perhaps you can fix the indentation in the first three code blocks? By the way I love the .gif :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I fixed edited most of the code, but it might need more work, I want to do another update tomorrow. btw the frames for the gif took 6 hours to render ( I used heike's [packing algorithm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/9831) to produce each frame), but I then I ran into the size limit of gifs and had to throw away a third of the frames. Don't know why the exported gif has these edge effects in some of the frames though.

Comment: @lalmei I made a few more tiny edits. I added `AbsoluteTiming` somewhere, so that the code now completely works when copy pasting. It looks great! I don't know much about gifs unfortunately. But I often hear that in many cases gifs can be made a lot smaller. The gif looks as if it shouldn't be too big. Great that you had the perseverance to let it finish if it took 6 hours :).

Comment: @J.M. https://alchetron.com/Lena-Soderberg-430302-W#- gives the background and some of the history (as well as wikipedia). Would probably be possible to write a wolfram api call to search for similar images to the test image...

Comment: @erfink, I'm well aware of the history; ;) it was merely a joke on unreasonable expectations some people have of reconstruction algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

## Q1

Get pictures

```
smallSquare = Import /@ FileNames["*", "D:\\...file1"]
```

Get a mean `threshold` to `Binarize` those picture but ensure most information is preserved.

```
threshold = 
 Mean[Flatten[
   ImageData[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"]] & /@ smallSquare]]
```

> 0.893274

Find the leftmost picture,which picture without any text on left,top and bottom side

```
left = Select[smallSquare, 
  MatchQ[AllTrue[#, EqualTo[1]] & /@ 
     Through[{First, Last, First@*Transpose, Last@*Transpose}[
       ImageData[Binarize[#, threshold]]]], {True, True, True, 
     False}] &]
```

Based on `MatchingDissimilarity`,I find series picture adjacent to the left,and until the rightmost picture without any text on the right side.

```
While[AnyTrue[Last[Transpose[ImageData[ColorNegate@Binarize[Last[AppendTo[left, 
         First[Nearest[Complement[smallSquare, left], Last[left], 1, 
           DistanceFunction -> (N[MatchingDissimilarity @@ {Last[
           Transpose[ImageData[ColorNegate@Binarize[#1, threshold]]]], 
         First[Transpose[ImageData[ColorNegate@Binarize[#2, threshold]]]]}] &)]]]], 
       threshold]]]], EqualTo[1]]]
```

Combine all pictures

```
ImageAssemble[left]
```

[image]

---

## Q2

Well,since nobody conquer the second question yet,that is a good reason to climb this mountain.But like the [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov) said [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33727/21532)

> Unfortunately Q2 have too many blank edges to reconstruction

The same difficulty for me to hard overcome,but whatever this is a good try or start for the target

```
smallSquare = Import /@ FileNames["*", "...\\file2"]
threshold = 
  Mean[Flatten[
    ImageData[ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"]] & /@ smallSquare]];
data = ImageData[Binarize[#, threshold]] & /@ smallSquare;
UpEdge = MapIndexed[{First[#1], First[#2], {1, 0}} &, data];
DownEdge = MapIndexed[{Last[#1], First[#2], {-1, 0}} &, data];
LeftEdge = 
  MapIndexed[{First[Transpose[#1]], First[#2], {0, 1}} &, data];
RightEdge = 
  MapIndexed[{Last[Transpose[#1]], First[#2], {0, -1}} &, data];
edges = Select[Join[UpEdge, DownEdge, LeftEdge, RightEdge], 
   AnyTrue[First[#], EqualTo[0]] &];
init = 10;
mat = {{19, 19} -> {init, data[[init]]}};
margin = Select[edges, #[[2]] == init &];
Do[{stackMargin, next} = 
  First[MinimalBy[
    Catenate[
     Table[Tuples[{{currentEdge}, 
        Select[edges = 
          DeleteCases[edges, _?(#[[2]] == Last[margin][[2]] &)], 
         Last[#] == -Last[currentEdge] &]}], {currentEdge, margin}]], 
    MatchingDissimilarity @@ #[[All, 1]] &, 1]];
 nextPos = 
  Select[mat, First[Values[#]] == stackMargin[[2]] &][[1, 1]] + 
   Last[next];
 AppendTo[mat, nextPos -> {next[[2]], data[[next[[2]]]]}];
 margin = 
  Join[DeleteCases[margin, stackMargin], 
   Select[edges, (#[[2]] == next[[2]] && 
       Last[#] =!= Last[next] &)]], 11]
Image[ArrayFlatten[
  ReplacePart[
   Array[0 &, 
    Last[CoordinateBoundingBox[
      Keys[matRule = Thread[Keys[mat] -> Last /@ Values[mat]]]]]], 
   matRule]]]
```

[image]