# How to restore some upset of pictures

Tags: image-processing

I get a fish like this

[image]

Then we partition and mix it

```
slice = Partition[RandomSample[ImagePartition[ fish, 32] // Flatten], 
  8, 8, 1]
```

[image]

If you restore it straightly,the fish is in mess

[image]

So how to restore it?I just know this may be help to this

[image]

Can anybody would like to try it?

Comment: Related: [Reconstruct text pages cut by shredder](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32612/484)

Comment: @Rahul, don't you think it's a dupe?

Comment: @J.M.: If the solutions for that question work for this one, then yes. I haven't tested them, so I don't know.