# Stitching overlapping screenshots of a page

Tags: image-processing

Suppouse we have a series of screenshots of a webpage, taken by hand at different scrolling positions. All they have equal width and height and random scrolling positions.

We can imitate it as follows:

```
session = StartWebSession["Firefox"];
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching"];
webpageImage0 = WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"];
height = ImageDimensions[webpageImage0][[2]];

takeNext[n_] := 
 Table[WebExecute[session, 
   "JavascriptExecute" -> 
    "window.scrollBy(0," <> ToString[RandomInteger[{-100, height-20}]] <> ")"];
  WebExecute[session, "CapturePage"], {n}]

screenshots = takeNext[30]
```

**What would be a robust (and hopefully efficient) way to recover the complete webpage from such set of screenshots, assuming that they alltogether cover the whole page?**

Currently I've developed a solution assuming that the screenshots are strongly *successive*. It is short but very inefficient and has a problem with removing unnecessary padding added at the botttom of produced image (I think `BorderDimensions` can give wrong results in some cases):

```
combineTwo[img1_, img2_] := 
 ImageCompose @@ 
  ImageAlign[{ImagePad[img1, {{0, 0}, {height, 0}}, White], img2}, Method -> "Fourier", 
   TransformationClass -> "Translation"]

combinedImage = Fold[combineTwo, screenshots];

finalImage = ImagePad[combinedImage, -BorderDimensions[combinedImage, 0]]
```

---

Strongly related question (but with slighlty different scope):

- [How to merge several partially overlapping screenshots into one image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109196/280)

Comment: In version 13.0.1 there is a function: ImageStitch

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, but apart of the fact that it is *very* slow, I wasn't able to get it working for such a simple case.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach using built-in methods could be the following.

1. Using `ImageCorrespondingPoints` we compare the first image `i1` in a list of screenshots `imgs` to all other images.
2. We select `i2` as the image with the maximum number of corresponding points with `i1`.
3. We compute the difference between the positions (in `i1` and `i2`) of all corresponding points and take the `TrimmedMean` to a given threshold `th` to compute a shift vector `delta` between `i1` and and `i2`.
4. We use `ImageCompose` and with the shift vector `delta` to merge `i1` and `i2`. We remove `i1` and `i2` from the list of images `imgs` and prepend the merged image to the list of images `imgs`.
5. We repeat the process until the list of images `imgs` has the length of one meaning that only one merged image is left.

Here two methods which implement this approach, where `ImageJoinList` performs all the above steps and calls `ImageComposeAdd` to merge two images based on a shift vector.

```
ImageComposeAdd[i1_,i2_,delta_]:=Module[{d1,d2,ci1,ci2,cci,cpad},
  d1=ImageDimensions[i1];
  d2=ImageDimensions[i2];

  ci1=d1*#&/@{{0,0},{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}};
  ci2=d2*#+delta&/@{{0,0},{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}};
  cci={{Min[#[[All,1]]],Min[#[[All,2]]]},{Max[#[[All,1]]],Min[#[[All,2]]]},{Min[#[[All,1]]],Max[#[[All,2]]]},{Max[#[[All,1]]],Max[#[[All,2]]]}}&@Join[ci1,ci2];
  cpad=cci-ci1;
  ImageCompose[ImagePad[i1,{{-cpad[[1,1]],cpad[[-1,1]]},{-cpad[[1,2]],cpad[[-1,2]]}},Blue],i2,delta-cpad[[1]],{0,0}]
]

ImageJoinList[imgs_List,th_:0.2,printQ_:False]/;Length[imgs]>1:=Module[{i1,i2,i2idx,iRest,IRestCPs,delta},
  i1=imgs[[1]];
  iRest=imgs[[2;;]];
  IRestCPs=ParallelMap[ImageCorrespondingPoints[i1,#]&,iRest,DistributedContexts->All];
  i2idx=Last@Last@SortBy[MapIndexed[{Length[#1[[1]]],First@#2}&,IRestCPs],First];
  i2=iRest[[i2idx]];
  iRest=Drop[iRest,{i2idx}];
  delta=TrimmedMean[First[-Differences[IRestCPs[[i2idx]]]],th];
  If[printQ,Print[MapThread[HighlightImage[#1,#2]&,{{i1,i2},IRestCPs[[i2idx]]}]~Join~{delta}]];
  ImageJoinList[{ImageComposeAdd[i1,i2,delta]}~Join~iRest,th,printQ]
]
ImageJoinList[imgs_List,th_,printQ_]/;Length[imgs]==1:=First@imgs
```

Here an example using a data set of 10 screenshots (generated with the code from the question) which is feed into `ImageJoinList` in random order:

```
screenshots = takeNext[10]
ImageJoinList[RandomSample[screenshots], 0.2, True]
```

The result of each stage of the iteration is printed. Here one example

> [image: Match]

where the corresponding points are plotted over the images in pink and the shift vector is computed to be `{0.,1254.}`. Note that for this sage `ImageCorrespondingPoints` was able to find a significant number of points despite the fact, that the overlapping region is just text. The result

> [image: Result]

looks pretty good upon first inspection.

The implementation is pretty rough around the edges and it is not very fast (even when running the map over `ImageCorrespondingPoints` in parallel). One might be able to improve the reliability and performance by playing with the Options of  `ImageCorrespondingPoints`.  I think both `ImageAlign` and  `ImageStitch` use this method under hood.

`ImageCorrespondingPoints` is arguably a bit overkill if one really assumes, that all screenshots have the same size and it is just a matter of finding the right order and vertical shift. I tried writing something my self by overlaying the screenshots with a variable shift and minimizing the difference but I was not able to get this to run because the image overlay, trim and pad methods of Mathematica are horrible to use (or at least I am not familiar enough with them to even get these rather simple tasks running properly).