# Implementing fast linear search for perfect vertical image alignment

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, compile, code-request, function-compile

After experimenting with image alignment aprroaches presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266533/280) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266568/280) and some other approaches involving `ImageDistance` and `NMinimize`, I realized that the most robust approach is the direct search, and it is probably can be implemented effficiently using `Compile` or `FunctionCompile` (but my experience with them is still very limited).

Suppose we have two overlapping screenshots with equal dimensions (and equal number of channels), but originally saved in a lossy format like JPG:

```
imgs = Import /@ {"https://i.imgur.com/sXrjTom.jpg", "https://i.imgur.com/gWvFAod.jpg"};
{i1, i2} = ImageTake[#, {230, 2210}] & /@ imgs
```

We need to find the correct vertical alignment for them. Unfortunately, `ImageAlign` is not only slow, but also gives unstable results, as I describe in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266533/280) answer. So the best what we can do is to implement our own alignment algorithm.

The basic algorithm is fairly simple. Supposing that the images are *successive*, and the second image continuates the first:

1. Get `ImageDimensions` and convert our images into `ImageData`:

   ```
   {width, height} = ImageDimensions[i1];
   id1 = ImageData[i1, "Byte", Interleaving -> True];
   id2 = ImageData[i2, "Byte", Interleaving -> True];
   ```
2. Define a distance finction depending on the alignment:

   ```
   distance[align_] := 
    Total@TakeLargest[Abs[Flatten[id1[[-align ;;]] - id2[[;; align]]]], 100]
   ```
3. Calculate the distances for all alignments starting from some minimal value:

   ```
   distances = Monitor[Table[{align, distance[align]}, {align, 20, height}], align];
   ```
4. Take the alignment corresponding to the minimal distance as the correct alignment:

   ```
   MinimalBy[distances, Last]
   ```

   > ```
   > {{613, 2653}}
   > ```

   ```
   ListLinePlot[distances, PlotRange -> All]
   ```

   > [image: output]

Another obvious variation would be calculating the distances until we find the distance lesser than some predefined threshold:

```
thr = 5*width;
dist = Infinity;
align = 19;
While[dist > thr && align <= height - 1,
  align += 1;
  dist = distance[align]];
{align, dist}
```

> ```
> {613, 2653}
> ```

What would be the most efficient way to implement both these approaches as compiled functions?

Comment: I don't think that compiling would help much. I'd rather suggest to use `ParallelTable`. Another strategy might be to first blur `i1` and `i2`, e.g. with `GaussianFilter`. The would smear out the peak in the distance plot such that it might become detectable by `Table[{align, distance[align]}, {align, 20, height,step}]` with larger stepsize `step`, e.g. `step = 10`. If you have found the best `align` for the blurred data, you can refine it by search between `align-step` and `align+step`. It is also possible to do more than one level of refinement...

Comment: Another, similar strategy could be to `Downsample` or `ArrayResample` the images, derive a first guess for `align` from the downsamples, and then do a similar refinement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to speed up the search for the perfect alignment without loosing the most remarkable feature of the algorithm given in the question, which makes it robust: the true minimum is always very sharp and very low as compared to any parasite minimum.

Additional advantages of this implementation:

1. It keeps arrays packed.
2. Even without `ParallelTable`, it uses all available processor cores for the computation.

We can safely downsample both images horizontally, but not vertically. And we also can safely limit the height of the window for computing the distance:

```
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[i1];
id1 = ImageData[i1, "Byte", Interleaving -> True];
id2 = ImageData[i2, "Byte", Interleaving -> True];

Clear[distance]
distance[id1_, id2_, align_, maxWindow_, vstep_] := 
 Total@TakeLargest[
   Abs[Flatten[
     id1[[-align ;; Min[-1, maxWindow - align - 1], ;; ;; vstep]] - 
      id2[[;; Min[align, maxWindow], ;; ;; vstep]]]], 100]
```

Now

```
distances = 
    Monitor[Table[{align, distance[id1, id2, align, 200, 10]}, {align, 20, height}], 
     align]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
MinimalBy[distances, Last]
```

> ```
> 1.54873
>
> {{613, 203}}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[distances, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: output]

Even without `ParallelTable`, the minimum is found in 1.5 seconds, and it is as sharp and low, as originally!

---

**Update**

It looks like that we get much more stable results with low windows heights when instead of `Total[TakeLargest[dists, 100]]` we use `Max[Max[dists] - Min[dists], Total[TakeLargest[dists, 100]]/100.]`:

```
Clear[distance]
distance[id1_, id2_, align_, maxWindow_, vstep_] := 
 Module[{dists = 
    Abs[Flatten[
      id1[[-align ;; Min[-1, maxWindow - align - 1], ;; ;; vstep]] - 
       id2[[;; Min[align, maxWindow], ;; ;; vstep]]]]}, {align, 
   Max[Max[dists] - Min[dists], Total[TakeLargest[dists, 100]]/100.]}]

distances = 
    Monitor[Table[distance[id1, id2, align, 200, 10], {align, 1, height}], align]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
MinimalBy[distances, Last]
```

> ```
> 0.997083
>
> {{613, 3}}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[distances, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: output]

---

**Update 2**

Significant speed gains along with significantly less memory consumption can be achieved by storing the intermediate [image data as a `NumericArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268620/280) and reversing the data of the first image (to take lines from the beginning, not from the end):

```
height = ImageDimensions[i1][[2]];
vstep = 10;
id1 = Image`InternalImageData[i1, Interleaving -> True, 
   DataReversed -> True][[All, ;; ;; vstep]]
id2 = Image`InternalImageData[i2, Interleaving -> True][[All, ;; ;; vstep]]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
Clear[distance]
distance[id1_, id2_, align_, maxWindow_] := 
 Module[{dists = 
    Abs[Flatten[
      Normal@id1[[align ;; Max[1, align - maxWindow + 1] ;; -1]] - 
       Normal@id2[[;; Min[align, maxWindow]]]]]}, 
   {align, Max[Max[dists] - Min[dists], Total[TakeLargest[dists, 100]]/100.]}]

distances = Monitor[Table[distance[id1, id2, align, 200], {align, 1, height}], align]; //
  AbsoluteTiming // First
MinimalBy[distances, Last]
```

> ```
> 0.74263
>
> {{613, 3}}
> ```

**A complete implementation can be found in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/266900/280) answer.**

Answer (score 7):

Another, similar strategy could be to downsample the images by employing `ArrayResample`, derive a first guess for `align` from the downsamples, and then do a refinement. Somewhat like the following:

```
resample[a_, shrinkfactor_Integer] := Module[{m, n, l},
   {m, n, l} = Dimensions[a];
   ArrayResample[
    a, {Quotient[m, shrinkfactor], Quotient[n, shrinkfactor], l}, 
    "Bin"]
   ];

findAlignment[a_, b_] := MinimalBy[
    ParallelTable[
     {align, 
      Total[
       TakeLargest[Flatten[Abs[a[[-align ;;]] - b[[;; align]]]], 
        100]]},
     {align, 20, Min[Length[a], Length[b]]}
     ],
    Last
    ][[1, 1]];

refineAlignment[a_, b_, guess_, shrinkfactor_] := MinimalBy[
   ParallelTable[
    {align, 
     Total[TakeLargest[Flatten[Abs[a[[-align ;;]] - b[[;; align]]]], 100]]},
    {
     align, 
     Max[1, shrinkfactor (guess - 1)], 
     Min[shrinkfactor (guess + 1), Min[Length[a], Length[b]]]
     }
    ],
   Last
   ][[1, 1]];

shrinkfactor = 4;

guess = findAlignment[resample[ImageData[i1], shrinkfactor], 
    resample[ImageData[i2], shrinkfactor]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
align = refineAlignment[ImageData[i1], ImageData[i2], guess, 
    shrinkfactor] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 0.423536
>
> {0.391173, 613}

This is about 14 times as fast as calling `findAlignment[ImageData[i1], ImageData[i2]]`. Nonetheless, it still finds the same result.

Comment: Thank you, works good at my image set. However, I think that it still can be fooled by parasite minimums which in some cases become almost equal to the true alignment. This is a consequence of the fact that with `ArrayResample` we loose the most remarkable feature of the algorithm which makes it robust: the true minimum is always very sharp and very low as compared to any parasite minimum. `ArrayResample` not only introduces additional parasite minimas, but also makes the true minimum compatible with the latter.

Comment: Yes, of course. One can remedy this to some extent by taking not just the minimum alignment from the coarsened images, but, say,  the best 10 alignments.

Comment: Probably you meant `Min[Length[a], Length[b]]`, not `Max[Length[a], Length[b]]`.

Comment: Good point! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method with two caveats.

(1) It is not quite linear but rather it's softly linear (it has a logarithmic factor)..

(2) While the result will show that it works quite well, it was failing miserably when I tried it last night. I can think of a few reasons for that. In any case, I had to restart my machine today and now I get a viable result.

The rough idea is to apply a correlation to the images and see where there is a spike. We expect this to happen at a location where they overlap.

Here are some refinements (which might or might not be necessary).

(1) The image is white-dominated. This corresponds to a value of 1 in the image arrays for one of the three scales. So it can contribute unduly to the correlation values. To remove this possibility I reverse the images, that is, subtract their values from 1.

(2) I flatten the resulting arrays. I do this because I know what to make of the spike in the result. Very likely this can be done without flattening.

```
imgs = Import /@ {"https://i.imgur.com/sXrjTom.jpg", 
    "https://i.imgur.com/gWvFAod.jpg"};
{i1, i2} = ImageTake[#, {230, 2210}] & /@ imgs;
reverseImageArrays = Map[1 - ImageData[#] &, {i1, i2}];
flatarrays = Map[Flatten, reverseImageArrays];
```

I want to see where the second image shows a solid overlap with the first, so I use the second as first argument to `ListCorrelate` below. The third argument of 1 forces a cyclic use of the second argument.

```
lcorr = ListCorrelate[flatarrays[[2]], flatarrays[[1]], 1];
```

Find the location of the max value. For purposes of comparison, also find the min and the mean. The idea is that at overlaps we expect a spike and elsewhere we expect a lower fluctuation from multiplying uncorrelated values, many of which are zeros in one or both factors.

```
Mean[lcorr]
MinMax[lcorr]
maxpos = First[FirstPosition[lcorr, Max[lcorr]]]

(* Out[59]= 25498.3

Out[60]= {10112.9, 60888.6}

Out[61]= 4432321 *)
```

Now find the row where this maxes out. One thing is quite encouraging: this next computation actually gives an integer (as opposed to rational) value.

```
(maxpos - 1)/
 Apply[Times, Rest[Dimensions[reverseImageArrays[[1]]]]]

(* Out[53]= 1368 *)
```

(Why do I subtract 1 in the numerator? It had to be an increment of either a -1, 0, or 1, and that's the value that gave the integer result. Which is to say, there was a bit of voodoo in that.)

Now we can check this result.

```
Image[1 - reverseImageArrays[[1]][[1368 ;;]]]
```

[image]

```
Image[1 - 
  reverseImageArrays[[2]][[1 ;; 
     Length[reverseImageArrays[[2]]] - 1368]]]
```

[image]

Visually this seems to be about as good as can be.

Comment: Thank you very much, very interesting! However, for the first image the span should be `1368 + 1 ;;` for the exact match.

Comment: I pretty much assumed I'd have at one off-by-one error (or two, if that assumption itself was off by one).

Comment: Further to your comment, the correct row is found by `(maxpos - 1)/
 Apply[Times, Rest[Dimensions[reverseImageArrays[[1]]]]]`. I now see why this works out: just consider the case of two identical images, where we want the result to be 1. (You maybe knew this already, but I had missed it.)

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation, now it is clear: `(maxpos - 1)/  Apply[Times, Rest[Dimensions[reverseImageArrays[[1]]]]]` gives the number of rows *from the start* to the max value. In the case of identical images it is zero, and the max value is at the first element (zero shift). This explains why we must subtract 1 from `maxpos`: `maxpos = 1` corresponds to zero shift.

Comment: I've found that using the *generalized correlation* syntax it is possible (at least partially) to implement the algorithm from my answer here using `ListCorrelate`: `lst=Max/@Abs[ListCorrelate[ImageData[i2,"Byte"][[;;200,;;;;21]],ImageData[i1,"Byte"][[;;,;;;;21]],{1,-1},{},Subtract,List]];Position[lst,Min[lst]]` (returns `{{1369}}`). But unfortunately it is about 10 times slower than the implementation given in my answer...

Comment: It seems that there are two reasons for slow `ListCorrelate`: 1) It unpacks original packed arrays (my code doesn't); 2) It uses only one processor core for the computation (my code uses 4 physical cores available on my laptop, without `ParallelTable`).

Comment: (1) I do not think `ListCorrelate` unpacks packed arrays of machine reals. But it may well do something along those lines for `"Byte"` arrays. (2) You may well be correct about only using one processor core. It is FFT-based and I do not know whether our use of the MKL FFT is parallelized, or whether the MKL variant gets used under the hood in this instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, it unpacks even arrays of machine reals, just try: `On["Packing"];ListCorrelate[ImageData[i2][[;;200]],ImageData[i1],{1,-1},{},Subtract,List];`. Also look at processor and memory usage: only one core is used, and it takes huge amount of memory (4 GB), and finally **crashes the kernel**...

Comment: This unpacks because it is not using the usual correlation functions of `Times` and `Plus`. Probably also slower for that reason like (O(n1*n2) where {n1,n2} are the respective list sizes) since it won't be FFT-based. (I had failed to account for this usage difference in my previous note.)