# What is idiomatic way to extract NumericArray from Image?

Tags: image, undocumented, conversion, numeric-array

It is easy to see that `NumericArray` is a construct underlying `Image`:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", IncludeMetaInformation -> None];
ResourceFunction["ShortInputForm"][img]
```

> [image: output]

At the same time, unlike `Image`, we can directly manipulate `NumericArray` using such handy functions as `Part`, `Flatten` etc. Of course, we can convert `Image` into a packed array using `ImageData`, but resulting array will occupy much more memory than the original image:

```
ByteCount /@ {img, ImageData[img, "Byte"]}
```

> ```
> {55248, 407016}
> ```

The function [`ShortInputForm`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ShortInputForm) uses a hack identical to the [`Nucleus`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157198/280) function by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) for accessing the internal structure of atomic objects. This hack allows extracting the `NumericArray`:

```
Nucleus[img][[1]]
```

> [image: output]

But of course it would be much better to have a non-hackish way to do this, which wouldn't depend on undocumented details of implementation of `LinkWrite` and `LinkRead`, and hopefully would also be more efficient.

Hence my question: **What is the idiomatic way to extract `NumericArray` from `Image`?**

Comment: Like any `NoEntryQ` object you can grab its parts all you want via `Replace[img, _[x_, ___] :> x]`, but that's hardly idiomatic is it?  I would think you are unlikely to find a builtin solution that doesn't have the words "Private" or "Internal" in the function name.

Comment: @JasonB. I will be happy also with a function from the ``Internal` `` context. At least, do not define a special hackish function for such a basic task...

Comment: @JasonB. `Replace[img, _[x_, ___] :> x]` could be an acceptable solution, thank you! You can post this as an answer.

Comment: the `Replace` method I think is a bit heavy handed so I posted a couple of other methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the most idiomatic way to get the image data as a numeric array:

```
In[141]:= img = Import["ExampleData/coneflower.jpg", IncludeMetaInformation -> None];

In[143]:= NumericArray[ImageData[img, "Byte"]] // OutputForm

Out[143]//OutputForm= NumericArray[<113,150,3>, UnsignedInteger8]
```

This does require recreating the `NumericArray` object from the image data, so has that level of inefficiency.

If you were to go spelunking, by calling `PrintDefinitions` on `Image` to see the formatting value, you would see the suggestively named `` Image`InternalImageData ``.  Being the curious type, you would find it gives the same data as above

```
In[147]:= SameQ[%143, Image`InternalImageData[img]]

Out[147]= True
```

All the usual caveats about undocumented functionality apply (namely that this internal function could disappear in a future release).

Comment: Excellent. I would add that ``Image`InternalImageData`` accepts the usual option `Interleaving`, what is also very handy. For example: ``Image`InternalImageData[img, Interleaving -> True]``. Also it accepts the option `DataReversed`.