# Open an html saved notebook

Tags: html

I have found an `html` page clearly created using the `Save as HTML` option of `Mathematica`. Is there a way to reverse this operation? That is open the `html` file with `Mathematica` and render it as a `nb` file again?

Comment: Without proper specification via `Export`, by default almost everything important is rasterized so I don't think so. Why not embedded CDF?

Comment: @Kuba ok, I didn't realize that not only images but also expression were rasterized. What is "embedded CDF"? (I am not the author of the html page)

Comment: [CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/). Usually there are links to source notebooks but if there isn't any maybe you can ask the author? I don't believe text recognition approach will be successful with *Mathematica* syntax.

Comment: @Kuba I don't think he created the webpage himself, he probably wants to run something he found online.  Red, is this correct?  I've felt the pain of that before, uncopyable rasterized cells are very annoying.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right, but I know it, have you read all the comments? :)

Comment: @Kuba I was confused by "why not embedded CDF", it sounded like you assumed he created the document.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it was so. But then OP said "I am not the author of the html page"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created test image with [Heike's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46/heike) code from [How to create word clouds?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/5478) and I've posted it... here :):

[image]

So let's download it:

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni4Kl.png"];
```

In case of full html you can use `Import[....html, "Images"]`.

```
TextRecognize[ImageResize[pic, {Automatic, 1100}]]
```

> [image]

Not perfect but it's something. It is `String` so after corrections you can convert it to `InputForm`.

You can also play with `ImageResize`, I've choosen 1100 because it gives nice output.

I think that the first operation should be

```
StringReplace[..., {"»?" -> "#", "f?" -> "#", " . " -> "."}]
```

:)