# WordCloud out of Images or TeX

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image, word-cloud, matex

Is it possible to use the WordCloud function to create a word cloud out of LaTeX expressions or images (with transparencies) representing equations?

Comment: would this suit you? its not quite what you asked for `exp = Integrate[1/(1 - x^32), x] // Expand;
exp = List @@ exp; WordCloud[ToString[HoldForm[exp // Release]], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["GrayTones"]]`

Comment: If the question is "how to create a word cloud out of LaTeX expressions or images?" then the answer can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2334/731). You can turn LaTeX expressions into images using [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).

Comment: @C.E. According to the documentation (under Details), since v11 WordCloud should work with any expression, including graphics.  However, I can't get it to produce reasonable output when given MaTeX-generated stuff.  Of course, Heike's implementation (that you linked to) will still work.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, I don't know why I got that wrong. I can't get it to work with the expressions either, but rasterizing seems to help: `WordCloud[
 Table[Rasterize[
   MaTeX["x^{" <> ToString[n] <> "}", Magnification -> 5], 
   RasterSize -> 200], {n, 20}]]`

Answer (score 2):

[`WordCloud`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCloud.html) should work with any expression, but in practice some expressions, in particular `Graphics` containing `FilledCurve`, cause it to fail.

Here's a way around this.

Let's compile some TeX using [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX):

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]

letterGraphics = MaTeX@CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

[image]

This fails:

```
WordCloud[letterGraphics]
```

[image]

But now let us convert those special graphics primitives to pure `Polygon`s.

```
WordCloud[
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01] & /@ 
  letterGraphics]
```

[image]

If setting the [`MaxCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html) to a low enough value, it works.

I tested this in Mathematica 11.2.  Earlier versions may not do so well.