# WordOrientation does not work in v11?

Tags: bugs, word-cloud

**Bug introduced in 11.0.1 and fixed in 11.1**

---

It seems that `WordOrientation` does not work in v11. The sample code

```
input = ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}];
WordCloud[input, WordOrientation -> "Random"]
```

produces an image with horizontal words only. Is there a potential workaround?

Comment: Based on Open Cloud `WordCloud[input, WordOrientation -> {-Pi/2,Pi/2}]` also fails.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: @C.E. What is your version?  I tested with 11.0.1 macOS.  Do you still have 11.0.0?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I tested it on 11.0.0.

Comment: None of `WordOrientation` possible settings ("Random", "Vertical", {values}, ...) work for me either (v11.0.1). (Also strangely in the FE no info box is automatically popping up when pointer mouse is over it.)

Comment: So how do bug fixes work - will we have to way until v11.0.2 to see it?

Comment: You have to first report it to Wolfram [here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/), then you have to hope they get around to fixing it (this is not guaranteed).

Comment: @Lem.ma Maybe you'll be interested in [this solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2360/19960)