# Packing arbitrary shapes

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, geometry

I'm looking for a general method of packing any set of 2D glyphs. For example, say I had 30 randomly transformed english characters:

```
$letters = 
  Table[First[
    First[ImportString[
      ExportString[
       Style[c, Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
       "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]], {c, Alphabet[]}];
n = 30;
toPack = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Translate[
     Rotate[Scale[RandomChoice[$letters], RandomReal[5]], 
      RandomReal[2 Pi]], RandomReal[20, {2}]]}, {n}];
Graphics@toPack
```

[image]

How would I pack them so they are touching on their edges? Doesn't have to be optimal, just a random layout where they are touching compactly. Basically, assume they are all magnets that attract each other in 2D.

For example, with 5 shapes, here's an output I would expect:

[image]

**Update:**

I played with @ChipHurst's idea of using `WordCloud`, but it doesn't make valid tight packings, most of them aren't touching and some of them even overlap.

[image]

Comment: I assume your picture is an infeasible packing?

Comment: Sure, just starter code for generating random shapes that I'd like to layout in a packing

Comment: You can get close to what you want with `WordCloud` using random weights and `WordSpacings -> 0`. If you need them touching, perhaps you could iterate over some force field until they're close enough.

Comment: Though to avoid overlap, I had to rasterize your `toPack`. I'm not sure why.  `SeedRandom[1234];
WordCloud[
 AssociationThread[Rasterize[#, Background -> None] & /@ Graphics /@ toPack, 
  RandomReal[5, Length[toPack]]], WordSpacings -> 0]`

Comment: Ah nice trick, but the shapes might not be just letters (I picked letters arbitrarily) but arbitrary polygon shapes

Comment: @M.R. Need to solve the problem of packing arbitrary polygons?

Comment: @AlexTrounev chip solved it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps a start:

We can extract information from `WordCloud` in order to translate a collection of regions so they pack nicely.

First I'll create some `BoundaryMeshRegions` similar to how the glyphs were created by OP:

```
$letters = Table[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style[c, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]], _Text], {c, Alphabet[]}];

n = 30;

BlockRandom[
  glyphs = RandomChoice[$letters, n];
  scales = RandomReal[5, n],
  RandomSeeding -> 1234
];
```

Plot the word cloud using random orientations:

```
wc = WordCloud[AssociationThread[glyphs, scales], WordSpacings -> 0,
  WordOrientation -> "Random", RandomSeeding -> 1234]
```

[image]

Notice that the objects aren't quite touching. Luckily when we convert this scene back to a collection of regions, they will seem to be touching. I think this has to do with padding within `Inset`. Using regions in the beginning rather then just graphics makes it easier to convert the insets into explicit coordinates and avoid padding.

```
insets = Cases[wc2, _Inset, ∞];

insetToReg[mr_, c_, p_, s_] := 
  BoundaryMeshRegion[TransformedRegion[#, 
   TranslationTransform[c - RegionCentroid[BoundingRegion[#]]]], 
    MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> RandomColor[Hue[_]]}]& @ RegionResize[mr[[1]], s]

BlockRandom[Show[insetToReg @@@ insets], RandomSeeding -> 1234]
```

[image]

Or if you prefer a region instead of just a visualization:

```
RegionUnion[insetToReg @@@ insets]
```

[image]

We can do this for polygons too:

```
BlockRandom[
  polys = 
   Table[BoundaryMeshRegion[#[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]], 
       Line[Mod[Range[16], 15, 1]]] &[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {15, 2}]], n];
  scales = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n],
  RandomSeeding -> 1234
  ];
wc = WordCloud[AssociationThread[polys, scales], WordSpacings -> 0, 
   WordOrientation -> "Random", RandomSeeding -> 1234];
BlockRandom[Show[insetToReg @@@ Cases[wc, _Inset, ∞]], 
 RandomSeeding -> 1234]
```

[image]

Comment: What layout method does wordcloud use under the hood?

Comment: I don't know, but here's some good implementations you might look into: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/how-to-create-word-clouds