# Putting set elements into venn diagram

Tags: visualization, sets

My problem has two parts. Before that I have two Lists/Sets. It suppose to be created them by two initial strings.

In the first part, I need to show sets' elements in venn diagram. I can create venn diagram with following code but it is not enough for my purpose. Also, I don't want to use internet.

```
WolframAlpha["(A \[Intersection] B)", {{"VennDiagram", 1}, "Content"}]
```

I don't need coloring though. On the other hand, A and B are two different sets. I need to show their elements in appropriate places. Here is an example image:

[image]

Second part, I should show this two sets ordered in column representation. If there are matching elements, arrows should point from appropriate element of A to appropriate element of B. Here is an example image:

[image]

It is pretty challenging. Thanks everybody for their attention.

Comment: See this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2554/5 (possible duplicate) As for the second part, it depends on how your data is stored. Please include a minimal example.

Comment: I am going to give two strings such as "This is an example entry.". I saw the link before, but they don't have any element.

Comment: I tried to get more attention to this question by labelling it more appropriately as "wolfram-alpha-queries" and asking the question only in the case of Mathematica in Quora https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-visualise-set-elements-as-a-Venn-diagram-in-Mathematica where I outlined my investigation so far. I could not find anything about Set Diagram or Venn Diagram in Mathematica manual or anything in List Manipulation related to visualisation. I hope we get answer to this :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this unsophisticated attempt is a starting point.

```
whales = {"have hair", "live birth", "breathe air", "live in water", 
   "have fins", "can swim"};
fish = {"lay eggs", "have scales", "breathe water", "live in water", 
   "have fins", "can swim"};
tint = Intersection[whales, fish];
w = Complement[whales, tint];
f = Complement[fish, tint];
r1 = Disk[{-1, 0}, 2];
r2 = Disk[{1, 0}, 2];
int = RegionIntersection[r1, r2]
rd1 = RegionDifference[r1, int]
rd2 = RegionDifference[r2, int]
fun[u_, v_] := 
 Text[Column[u, BaseStyle -> {Purple, 16}], RegionCentroid[v]]
RegionPlot[{rd1, int, rd2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Blend[{Yellow, LightRed}, 1/2], LightRed}, 
 Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> MapThread[fun, {{tint, w, f}, {int, rd1, rd2}}]~Join~  
    {Text[Style["WHALE", 20], {-1, 1.7}], 
  Text[Style["FISH", 20], {1, 1.7}]}, 
     ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]