# Writing text inside Venn Diagrams

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, code-generation, writing

I found this question which is extremely cool and amazing

[How to plot Venn diagrams with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/how-to-plot-venn-diagrams-with-mathematica?noredirect=1&lq=1)

which also helped me in plotting and creating Venn Diagrams.

But there is something that is missing, and it's: "How to write something inside the diagrams?"

For example, if I wanted to write a text inside the coloured zones in the figure below, how shall I do?

Mathematica code used: the one in the accepted answer given in the linked question.

Venn Diagram:

```
VennDiagram2[3, 
Subscript[A, 1] && Subscript[A, 2] && Subscript[A, 3] || 
Subscript[A, 2]]
```

Let's for example insert RED in the bigger zone, and GREEN, VIOLET, BLUE, BLACK; WHITE and so on in the other ones..

[image]

Comment: @MarcoB Actually.. almost nothing because I have no idea how to proceed. I thought about using RegionPlot, but it seems not useful. Also I tried with the Drawing Tools, with the option "add text", but the result is a yucky thing

Comment: Take a look at `Epilog`.  You might incorporate it in the `Graphics[]` command the `VennDiagram[]` function.

Comment: You can also use `Show` to compose the Venn diagram with any other graphics. In `Graphics` you can use `Text` to draw text at the desired locations, which you can get by right-clicking in the Venn diagram and choosing "Get Coordinates".

Comment: Another Venn diagram function with labels is here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134201/8253

Answer (score 1):

For a fast way, just use the DRAWING TOOLS box.

Click with the right key (if you have a mouse) or double click in the Mac texpad, and open the drawing tools box.

Choose TEXT at the top right of the window and then choose the region of the diagram in which you want to write something.

Once you did it, go in the "TEXT" section (under the Arrowheads section) and choose for DIMENSION to enlarge, and remove the DRAW BACKGROUND by clicking on the small box of the option.

Here you are done :D

Example:

[image]