# Create a Venn Diagram

Tags: graphics

I would like to create a `Venn Diagram`, but I have not found any documentation about it.

There is a lot of information about Intersection, but not much about `⊂`.

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
b = {2, 5, 8, 4, 7};
c = {2, 8};
Graphics[{
  Circle[{0, 0}, 10],
  Circle[{0, 0}, 20],
  Circle[{0, 0}, 30],
  FontSize -> 20,
  Text["0", {0, 25}],
  Text["1", {-21.65063509, 12.5}],
  Text["2", {-3, 0}],
  Text["3", {-21.65063509, -12.5}],
  Text["4", {-12.99038106, -7.5}],
  Text["5", {0, 15}],
  Text["6", {0, -25}],
  Text["7", {12.99038106, -7.5}],
  Text["8", {3, 0}],
  Text["9", {21.65063509, -12.5}],
  Text["10", {21.65063509, 12.5}]
  }]
```

[image]

My question is whether there is a function that recognizes that:

$C\subset B$ and $B\subset A$

And still generate a diagram ...

Comment: Have you seen this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/how-to-plot-venn-diagrams-with-mathematica ?

Comment: This demonstration could be a start: http://www.demonstrations.wolfram.com/VennDiagrams/

Comment: From what I see no example shows by applying the values

Comment: Can I just do `&&` e `||`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below are two different methods for drawing a Venn diagram given a list of sets. The first method places the labels for set elements by finding an evenly distributed list of points in each region using a mesh. I then realized that, with a little coaxing, the `WordCloud` function could also be used for this task. I added a second method using that idea at the end. The second method also has options for labeling the sets and graphics styling.

---

**Fun example first!**

```
pokelists = EntityClassList["Pokemon"][[{24, 46, 47}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
VennDiagram[EntityList /@ pokelists, 
  SetLabels -> pokelists, ElementStyle -> 11, ImageSize -> 10 72
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Method 1**

In the following function, suitably spaced positions for the set element labels are found for each region by using `DiscretizeRegion` to find a mesh, extracting the list of mesh points, and then weeding out points that are too close to each other. If there aren't enough points remaining, additional points are chosen randomly without regard for overlap. Labels are kept away from the edges of the region by subtracting a thickened border region from the region to be meshed.

```
deleteNearPoints[{processed_, unprocessed_ /; Length@unprocessed < 2}, d_] :=   
  Join[processed, unprocessed]

deleteNearPoints[{processed_, unprocessed_}, d_] := deleteNearPoints[
  {
    Append[processed, First@unprocessed],
    DeleteCases[
      Rest@unprocessed,
      Alternatives @@ Nearest[Rest@unprocessed, First@unprocessed, {Infinity, d}]
    ]
  },
  d
]

VennDiagram[lists : {_List ..}] := Module[
  {d = .6, r = 1, thickness = .15, pointDistance = .1, 
   n = Length@lists, cases, labels, elements, disks, points, region, 
   outlines},
  disks = NestList[
    TransformedRegion[#, RotationTransform[2 Pi/n, {0, 0}]] &,
    Disk[{d, 0}, r],
    n - 1
    ];
  outlines = RegionUnion @@ RegionDifference @@@
    (disks /. Disk[p_, r_] -> {Disk[p, (1 + thickness) r], Disk[p, (1 - thickness) r]});
  cases = Most@Tuples[{True, False}, n];
  labels = Flatten[Table[
     If[
      (elements = Complement[
          Intersection @@ Pick[lists, case],
          Union @@ Pick[lists, Not /@ case]
          ]) == {},
      {},
      region = RegionDifference[
        RegionIntersection[Pick[disks, case]],
        RegionUnion @@ Flatten@{Pick[disks, Not /@ case], outlines}
        ];
      points = MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion[region, MaxCellMeasure -> .01];
      points = deleteNearPoints[{{}, points}, pointDistance];
      If[Length@points < Length@elements,
       Transpose@{elements, 
         Join[points, RandomPoint[region, Length@elements - Length@points]]
       },
       Transpose@{elements, RandomSample[points, Length@elements]}
       ]
      ],
     {case, cases}
     ], 1];
  Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[GrayLevel[0, .04]], EdgeForm[Black], disks, Text @@@ labels}]]
  ]
```

The OP's sets:

```
VennDiagram[{a, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some bigger sets:

```
VennDiagram[Table[RandomSample[Range[60], 40], 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
VennDiagram[Table[RandomSample[Range[60], 40], 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Too many elements to fit, resulting in overlapping labels:

```
VennDiagram[Table[RandomSample[Range[100], 80], 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some combinations of more than three sets will work, but not in general:

```
VennDiagram[{
  {0, 1, 2, 3, 13}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13}, {0, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13}, 
  {0, 7, 8, 11, 12}, {0, 9, 10, 11}
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Method 2**

I realized that one can also accomplish this task somewhat more easily and attractively using `WordCloud` to place the labels. The only complication is that *Mathematica* generates the word cloud at an arbitrary size -- it needs to be scaled and translated properly to fit on the diagram. I also remove the font scaling so that all the labels have the same font size.

```
Options[VennDiagram] = 
 Join[{SetLabels -> None, ElementStyle -> {}}, Options[Graphics]]

VennDiagram[lists : {_List ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {d = .6, r = 1, thickness = .05, n = Length@lists, cases, labels, 
   elements, disks, region, outlines, points, bounds, cloud, 
   setlabels, anchor},
  disks = NestList[
    TransformedRegion[#, RotationTransform[2 Pi/n, {0, 0}]] &,
    Disk[{d, 0}, r],
    n - 1
    ];
  setlabels = If[(labelstrings = OptionValue[SetLabels]) === None,
    {},
    Table[
     anchor = {Cos[2 Pi (i - 1)/n], Sin[2 Pi (i - 1)/n]};
     {Line[(d + r) {anchor, 1.05 anchor}],
      Text[Framed@labelstrings[[i]], 1.04 (d + r) anchor, Sign /@ -anchor]
      },
     {i, n}
     ]
    ];
  outlines = RegionUnion @@ RegionDifference @@@
     (disks /. Disk[p_, r_] -> {Disk[p, (1 + thickness) r], Disk[p, (1 - thickness) r]});
  cases = Most@Tuples[{True, False}, n];
  labels = Flatten@Table[
     If[
      (elements = Complement[
          Intersection @@ Pick[lists, case],
          Union @@ Pick[lists, Not /@ case]
          ]) == {},
      {},
      region = RegionDifference[
        RegionIntersection[Pick[disks, case]],
        RegionUnion @@ Flatten@{Pick[disks, Not /@ case], outlines}
        ];
      If[Length[elements] == 1,
       elements = Join[elements, {Invisible["a"], Invisible["b"]}]
       ];
      cloud = WordCloud[elements, region, MaxItems -> All];
      cloud = DeleteCases[cloud, FontSize -> _, Infinity] /.
        Style[args__] -> Style[args, OptionValue@ElementStyle];
      points = MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion@region;
      bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose@points;
      Inset[cloud, Mean /@ bounds, Center, -Subtract @@@ bounds]
      ],
     {case, cases}
     ];
  Show[
   Graphics[{
     FaceForm[GrayLevel[0, .04]], EdgeForm[Black],
     Style[setlabels, OptionValue@LabelStyle], disks, labels
     }, FilterRules[{opts}, Options@Graphics]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

I find the bounding box of each region by discretizing and then taking min and max of the mesh points. There is a built-in function `RegionBounds` that is supposed to accomplish this task, but it seems to be extremely slow in this case. Also, `WordCloud` does not like making clouds in a region with only one word -- I think that's a bug -- so I add a couple of invisible elements to the list for that case.

Examples:

```
VennDiagram[{a, b, c}, SetLabels -> {"A", "B", "C"}, LabelStyle -> 14, ElementStyle -> 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
VennDiagram[Table[RandomSample[Range[200], 100], 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
VennDiagram[{
  {0, 1, 2, 3, 13}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13}, {0, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13}, 
  {0, 7, 8, 11, 12}, {0, 9, 10, 11}
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wonderfu work,just a suggestion,can you label each circle?Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Bba.png) or by `Key` of `Association`,which clear the graph's structure. :)

Comment: @yode Thanks, yes, I was going to do that, but I got tired...I will add that at some point.

Comment: These deserve a good rest. :)

Comment: See my answer,just a simple try.

Comment: @yode Added options for labels and graphics styling.

Comment: Powerful edit..

Answer (score 5):

For [this request](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134014/create-a-venn-diagram#comment362123_134201)

```
VennDiagram[data : (_Association | _List)] := 
 Module[{posAss, 
   ass = If[Head[data] === Association, data, 
     AssociationThread[Range@Length[data], data]]}, 
  posAss = Map[Plus[#, RandomReal[.2, {2}]] &, 
    Merge[Association@*Thread /@ 
      Thread[Rule[Values[ass], 
        MapIndexed[
         ConstantArray[CirclePoints[Length[ass]][[First[#2]]], 
           Length[#1]] &, Values[ass]]]], Mean]];
  Show[Graphics[{Text @@@ 
      Normal[posAss], {Style[#, Red, 30, Bold] & /@ 
       Text @@@ Normal[Map[Mean, ass /. Normal[posAss]]]}, 
     Circle @@@ 
      MapAt[Plus[#, .1 #] &, 
       BoundingRegion[#, "MinDisk"] & /@ 
        Values[ass /. Normal[posAss]], {All, 2}]}]]]
```

If we have such `Association`,I give a *Venn Diagram* like following:

```
ass=<|"a"->{1,2,3,5},"b"->{5,3,9,11,12},"c"->{5,9,10,16}|>;
VennDiagram[ass]
```

[image]

Or you have a list:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 5}, {5, 3, 9, 11, 12}, {5, 9, 10, 16}};
VennDiagram[list]
```

[image]

#### Ps:Actually this diagram is expected(without that extra intersectant part):

[image]

Hope to see this diagram be improved.