# Defining a polygon by clicking on an image

Tags: image-processing, image

Imagine I have some image, $I$, and I'd like to define a polygon by sequentially clicking on the image to define vertices $(v_1, ...) \in V$, where vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ share an edge if $j = (i+1)$.  I'd like to end the vertex selection process by right clicking, or hitting something on the keypad - really anything that's convenient.  I suppose I'd like the $v_i$ to be specified in terms of image coordinates vs. image indices (if possible).

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Mathematica 9.0?

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3566/5

Comment: @Nasser Ahhh shoot, I'm sorry, I didn't look around carefully enough. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick start, to see if this is what you want. Can easily extend/clean up. To start a new polygon now or clean the old one, need to re-evaluate, just back of the envelope thing, to see first if this is what you wanted...

```
pt = {0, 0};
pts = {pt};
ClickPane[
 Dynamic[Graphics[{
    {Yellow, Disk[]},
    {Black, Point[pt]},
    {Red, Line[pts]}
    }, ImageSize -> Tiny]], (pt = #; AppendTo[pts, pt]) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and if you want to use an Image:

```
pt = {0, 0};
pts = {pt};
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
Framed@Grid[{
   {
    ClickPane[
     Dynamic[
      Show[Image[img, ImageSize -> 200],
       Graphics[{
         {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pt]},
         {Thick, White, Line[pts]}
         }, ImageSize -> Tiny]]], (pt = #; AppendTo[pts, pt]) &]
    },
   {Dynamic[pt]}
   }
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How would I define the first point by clicking only?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using Manipulate:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
create = True; color = White;
Manipulate[uS = u; 
   If[Length[uS] > 1 && Norm[uS[[-1]] - uS[[1]]] < 5, create = False;  color = Red;]; 
   Show[img, Graphics[{color, Line[u]}, PlotRange -> 2]], 
    {{u, {{0, 0}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> Dynamic[create]}]
```

In this implementation, you can use the locators to draw white lines. Add new locators by command-clicking. As soon as the final locator gets close enough (arbitrarily chosen to be "5" pixels) then the polygon turns red and the addition of new locators is suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nasser's very nice answer, one can also slightly modify the answer of Heiki from the link rm -rf posted: [Interactively extract points from a plot (ListPlot or SmoothDensityHistogram)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/interactively-extract-points-from-a-plot-listplot-or-smoothdensityhistogram) with a button that returns the vertices of the drawn polytope:

```
points = RandomSample[Transpose[{Flatten[{RandomReal[{0, 5}, 20], RandomReal[{4, 4.5}, 10]}], Flatten[{RandomReal[1, 20], RandomReal[{1.5, 2}, 10]}]}], 30];

winding[poly_, pt_] := Round[(Total@Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)]

DynamicModule[{pl, pos}, pl = ListPlot[points, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> {850, 850}];
Manipulate[pos = Pick[Range[Length[points]], Unitize[winding[poly, #] & /@ points], 1];
Show[pl, Epilog -> {{Darker[Green], PointSize[Medium], Point[points[[pos]]]}, {Black, Point[Complement[points, points[[pos]]]]}, {EdgeForm[{Red, Dashed}], FaceForm[],Polygon[poly]}}], {{poly, {}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}, Row[{Button["Copy Points", Print[pos]], Button["Get Polytope Vertices", Print[poly]], Button["Reset", poly = {}; pos = {}]}]]]
```