# Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets

Tags: graphics, filling, polygons

I am trying to fill a shape with diagonal lines. I am aware of Texture, but it rasterizes the fill pattern, which is not desirable. Here was my crack at it:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}], 
  Sequence@Table[
    Inset[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], {0, 0.1 l}, {0, 0}, 
     Scaled[{1, 1}]], {l, -10, 10}]}]
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

Ideally, I would want to just clip the insets such that they do not appear outside of the shape, rather than having to calculate the intersection between the lines and the polygon (for which I have shown a relatively simple example, in principle I'd like this to work for more complicated shapes such as FilledCurve). Note that there is a very large whitespace around the figure as well, which only appears when I include the insets.

Comment: You can use `AbsoluteOptions` to obtain the `PlotRange` of interest of the polygon (without the insets). Then, when you plot the polygon plus insets, you can use the same `PlotRange`.

Comment: Just to augment the answer by @Yu-Sung (which seems to do what you want): you can use `PlotRange` with `Graphics`, and that allows you to get rid of the white space. Maybe that's what @David already hinted at above... so you could add e.g. `PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.5}, {-.1, 1.5}}`.

Comment: @Jens, Yes, that's what I was referring to. Using `AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]` you can obtain the needed `PlotRange`. (My answer illustrates how this is used.)

Comment: @David yes, I shouldn't have doubted you. Just wanted t make sure. Another observation about @Yu-Sung's answer: it could be simplified so that it doesn't require `Inset`. Then the white-space problem would likely be fixed too.

Comment: @Jens I don't yet fully understand Yu-Sung's answers. Not sure why `Inset` was used.

Comment: @Jens, David: No, `Inset` is not needed. I was merely copying Guillonhchon's pattern. You can just put anything behind.

Comment: Actually, by using `Inset` you can localize the coordinates of patterns, so it makes the pattern more reusable. You can simply change the position (the second arg) of `Inset` to move it around.

Comment: @Yu-SungChang Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, with version 12.1 come  the directives [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) which make the task much easier:

```
Graphics[{HatchFilling["Diagonal"], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];

Graphics[{PatternFilling[img, ImageScaled[1.5]], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}] }]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{PatternFilling[#], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}] }, ImageSize -> 100] & /@ 
  {"Checkerboard", "Chevron", "ChevronLine", "Circle", "Diamond", "DiamondBox", 
   "DiamondPlate", "DiamondPoint", "Grain", "Grid", "GridPoint", 
   "Halftone", "HalftoneGrid", "Herringbone", "Hexagon", 
   "Octagon", "Plaid", "Weave", "XGrid", "XGridPoint"}  // Multicolumn[#, 5] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 42):

The following solution is hacky work-around to overcome the lack of proper pattern directives. I don't like it 100%, but still it is usable.

### Solution

The idea is simple. If you see [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilledCurve.html) documentation, it supports an object with holes:

[image: hole]

So what if you put a huge enough rectangle as an outer boundary? Then, your polygon becomes a hole and you can see through stuff behind it.

Now, few issues:

1. How big the boundary should be? Ideally, it should be always *outside* of the screen. Thankfully, it is possible by using [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageScaled.html) coordinates, which is supported by *all* 2D primitives.
2. Now your background color of the screen should be the face color of the outer polygon.
3. The hatch (pattern) should come first so that the outer polygon would be drawn on top of it.

This is the result.

```
Graphics[{
  (* The hatch comes first *)
  Sequence@
   Table[Inset[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], {0, 0.1 l}, {0, 0}, 
     Scaled[{1, 1}]], {l, -10, 10}],

  (* FaceForm color should be your "background" color: usually white *)
  FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black],

  (* FilledCurve syntax is essentially the same as Polygon if used with Line *)
  FilledCurve[{
    (* Large outer boundary. Its edges are always outside of your screen *)
    {
       Line[{ImageScaled[{-2, -2}],ImageScaled[{2, -2}],
         ImageScaled[{2, 2}],ImageScaled[{-2, 2}]}]
    },
    (* Your original polygon *)
    {
       Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}]
    }
  }]
}]
```

Here is the result:

> [image: result]

### Generalization

The following example uses two different types of patterns (an image and a graphic), and locate them in two different places.

```
Graphics[{
  (* Pattern for the first object *)
  Inset[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "MultiSpiralsPattern"}],
   {-.25, -.25}, {Left, Bottom}, {1.5, 1.5}],
  (* Pattern for the second object *)
  Inset[Graphics[Table[Circle[{i, j}, .25], {i, 10}, {j, 15}]],
   {1.5, 0}, {Left, Bottom}, {1, 1.5}],

  FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black],
  FilledCurve[{
    (* Outer polygon *)
    {Line[{ImageScaled[{-2, 2}], ImageScaled[{2, -2}], 
       ImageScaled[{2, 2}], ImageScaled[{-2, 2}]}]},
    (* The first object *)
    {Line[Table[(.5 + .25 (-1)^t) {Cos[Pi t/5], 
       Sin[Pi t/5]} + {.5, .5}, {t, 0, 9}]]},
    (* The second object *)
    {Line[{{1.5, 0}, {2.5, 0}, {2.5, 1}, {2, 1.5}, {1.5, 1}}]}
    }]
  }]
```

Here is the result:

> [image: result2]

### Pros & Cons

The benefits of this approach is:

1. You need to convert your polygon to inequalities to use `RegionPlot` or any other solutions using `Plot` with `RegionFunction` which is not always possible (such as country polygons).
2. Anything can be a pattern as long as it is behind the polygon.
3. The syntax is straightforward, as long as you stays in `Polygon` or even better `FilledCurve`. You just have to add one extra component.

The problems:

1. It is tricky to handle many objects with different patterns, especially if your object contains a concave part.
2. Circle support is hard. In fact, circles can be described as B-splines ([See the first example of **Applications** section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineCurve.html)), but combining it with the rest of `FilledCurve` can be messy.

---

In fact, if you are familiar with Mac OS's graphics API (Quartz or Cocoa), this is exactly how they deal with filled polygons with patterns ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html)). It would have been a nice addition to Mathematica's graphics if it were built-in.

As a side note, `FilledCurve` syntax is quite complex, but if you want nice graphics, it is well-worth learning. It follows the concept of *path* in many other graphics languages (Postscript, SVG, or system APIs) and conversion to it is usually straightforward.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. The only minor complaint is that there still appears to be a large whitespace around the shape, I'm guessing its because there's something screwy going on with the Inset coordinates...

Comment: Great idea! I do see one drawback: all objects that you want to hatch must have the same hatching pattern.

Comment: @Guillochon, yes it is due to your hatching patterns coordinate interfering with plot range computation. Could be a bug, although I think not. Usually when you have `Scaled` coordinates with `PlotRange->All`, FE is falling into chicken-egg trouble: To compute `Scaled` you need to know plot range. But to compute plot range, you need to know the boundaries of objects in the scene... So sometimes it does a guesstimation.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, Yes, that's why I said that I don't like it 100%. You can do different patterns by carefully laying down patterns around, but it gets quite nasty / impossible, if your object has concave parts. System API doesn't have that trouble because it draws each filled path on different buffer, then combine later.

Answer (score 25):

ragfield's solution is a good one that can easily be extended to arbitrarily complicated polygons if we create an `inPolyQ` function using winding numbers.

Here is a complicated polygon (the points only) from Mathematica's example data.

```
poly = Rescale[ExampleData[{"Statistics", "WesternUgandaBorder"}]];
```

This function determines whether a point is in the polygon.

```
inPolyQ = 
  Compile[{{polygon, _Real, 2}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
   Block[{polySides = Length[polygon], X = polygon[[All, 1]], 
     Y = polygon[[All, 2]], Xi, Yi, Yip1, wn = 0, i = 1}, 
    While[i < polySides, Yi = Y[[i]]; Yip1 = Y[[i + 1]]; 
     If[Yi <= y, 
      If[Yip1 > y, Xi = X[[i]]; 
        If[(X[[i + 1]] - Xi) (y - Yi) - (x - Xi) (Yip1 - Yi) > 0, 
         wn++;];];, 
      If[Yip1 <= y, Xi = X[[i]]; 
        If[(X[[i + 1]] - Xi) (y - Yi) - (x - Xi) (Yip1 - Yi) < 0, 
         wn--;];];]; i++]; ! wn == 0]];
```

We can use `inPolyQ` to generate our region for `RegionPlot`.

```
RegionPlot[inPolyQ[poly, x, y], {x, 0, .7}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 20,  
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, MeshShading -> {None}, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

As a proof of concept that this can be used for other sorts of textures..

```
text = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "MultiSpiralsPattern"}];

RegionPlot[inPolyQ[poly, x, y], {x, 0, .7}, {y, 0, 1.1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[text], PlotPoints -> 50, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Mathematica's graphics language lacks a clipping primitive.  However, you can sometimes simulate the same appearance using the sophisticated visualization functions.

```
RegionPlot[((0 <= x <= .5) && (0 <= y <= 1 + x)) || ((.5 < x <= 1) && 
    0 <= y <= 2 - x), {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, Mesh -> 20, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, MeshShading -> {None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you supply complicated shapes such as with `FilledCurve` to `RegionPlot`? Seemed like that was what the OP had in mind...

Comment: @R.M You can do that with my PointinPoly function used [in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/532/57).

Answer (score 14):

The `FilledCurve` approach in the accepted answer by @Yu-Sung Chang is very interesting, so I tried to make my own version of it. I defined the whole thing as a function that accepts graphics directives for the objects to be masked (`backgroundDirectives` - e.g., the fill pattern or image), and an arbitrary polygon as the mask. This includes `Polygon` with several lists as arguments, specifying a group of separate polygons which then appear as separate holes. The color of the masking foreground is specified in `maskDirectives`.

```
mask[backgroundDirectives_, p_Polygon, maskDirectives_] := 
 Module[{pts = p[[1]]},
  {backgroundDirectives,
   FaceForm[maskDirectives], EdgeForm[],
   FilledCurve[
    Prepend[Map[List, Flatten[Map[Line, {pts}, {-3}]]], {
      Line[
       {ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}],
         ImageScaled[{0, 1}]}
       ]
      }
     ]
    ]
   }
  ]
mask1 = With[{polygon = 
     Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1}}, 
       Most@Table[.3 {Cos[a], Sin[a]} + {-.3, .4}, {a, 0, 
          2 Pi, Pi/18}]}],
    plot = 
     DensityPlot[Cos[(x - y)/2], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 20}, 
      PlotPoints -> 60,
      Frame -> None,
      ImageSize -> 360]
    },
   {
    mask[Inset[Show[plot, AspectRatio -> Automatic]], polygon, Cyan],
    EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Dashed, Blue]], FaceForm[],
    polygon
    }
   ];
Graphics[mask1]
```

[image: Density plot with mask applied]

The image above shows how a background `DensityPlot` is masked by an area with two holes. Since I have separated the masking process as a function, it can be applied repeatedly, as I'm doing here with the previous output. Note that the output `mask1` didn't have head `Graphics` so it doesn't need to be inserted as an `Inset`:

```
With[{polygon = Polygon[
    Most@Table[2.2 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}]]
  },
 Graphics[{
   mask[mask1, polygon, Orange],
   EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Red]], FaceForm[],
   polygon
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Another mask applied to masked image]

By having the `mask` function operate on graphics objects, we only have to use `Inset` when calling `mask` with an *image* or `Graphics` in the background (as I did in the first graphic). We could also still use `Inset` to control the size of the background, as e.g. with `Inset[Graphics[mask1]]` in the last plot.

The second plot shows that the original background (the `DensityPlot`) is scaled to the final image dimensions by default, so the "stripes" get thicker relative to the masking polygons.

What you also see in the examples is that the `mask` doesn't draw the masking polygon(s) themselves; it only uses their shapes. That way you can decide on your own whether and how to draw the outline of the mask, e.g. as dashes as I did above.

**Edit**

The relative size of the mask and the other graphics it reveals depends on the settings for `ImageSize`. For example, the plots I posted will change if the `ImageSize` option in `plot` (contained in `mask1`) is changed, or if the output is manually resized.

Answer (score 11):

**Paint Poly with background colored stripes**

Just for fun, I painted the lines in the background color.
The unnecessary white space is avoided by using `AbsoluteOptions[g,PlotRange]` from the polygon when graphed alone.

`poly[n, color]` makes a (solid colored) polygon with n vertices.

`s[p, bc]` puts stripes of a background color `bc` on polygon `p`. `pr` is the `PlotRange` for the solid polygon (left pane, below).  This same `PlotRange` is used in the center and right panes. It crops the picture to the polygon.

```
poly[n_,color_:Blue]:=Graphics[{FaceForm[color],Polygon[RandomReal[1,{n,2}]]}]

s[p_,bc_:White]:= Module[{pr=AbsoluteOptions[p,PlotRange],pts,xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax},
  xMin=pr[[1,2,1,1]]; xMax=pr[[1,2,1,2]];
  yMin=pr[[1,2,2,1]]; yMax=pr[[1,2,2,2]];
  pts=Append[pList=InputForm[p][[1,1,2,1]],pList[[1]]];
  Show[p,
       Plot[Table[x+k,{k,yMin-xMax,xMin+yMax,.1}],{x,xMin,xMax},
           Axes-> None,PlotStyle->Directive[bc,Thickness[.06]]],
       Graphics[Line[pts]],pr[[1]],PlotRangePadding->Scaled[ .01]]]
```

Now lets look at three outputs. The middle pane may appear to have blue stripes. But the stripes are actually white.  The right pane shows the full extent of the drawn stripes (now in pink).

```
GraphicsGrid[{{p1 = poly[7], s[p1], s[p1, Pink]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: three polys]

Left: polygon
Center: blue polygon painted with white stripes
Right: blue polygon painted with pink stripes

Background is white in all 3 cases.