# RegionPlot (or FillingStyle) using hash lines?

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets)

I have a RegionPlot (and sometimes a regular Plot) where I'd like to shade two different parts of it two different ways. Since the final output will be printed in black and white, I'd really like to do this in an old fashioned way: with hash lines.

I was mainly wondering if there is some built in way to do this without developing it from scratch.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For `RegionPlot` you could use the `MeshFunctions` option for this, for example

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[Sin[x y] > 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &},
  Mesh -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/20]}, PlotStyle -> None],
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^4 < 2, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &},
  Mesh -> {Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/20]}, PlotStyle -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks and sorry for duplicating a previous post. I looked, but must not have used just the right search terms.

Comment: @texas That's okay, they are often not easy to find.  We do appreciate your trying however. :-)

Comment: Very nice! Is there a way to get away with only one `RegionPlot` command? Similar to how `PlotStyle` accepts a list of specifications for each region being plotted.