# Hatched Filling for ListPlot

Tags: plotting, filling

I am plotting to data curves using ListLinePlot. I like the look of Filling, but this is going to be printed, so I want something both black and white friendly, but giving more definition and separation than changing the opacity of the filling. Ideally, I would either have one hatched and the other filled solid gray, or both hatched in opposite directions or something such that they can be identified separately. This is what I have so far that I may just use if I can't find anything better:

```
data1 = exPDMIABSA[[1]];
data2 = exPDMIAwater[[1]];
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Dashed, Black]},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Gray]]
```

[image]

Three related questions I've found are

[RegionPlot (or FillingStyle) using hash lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/regionplot-or-fillingstyle-using-hash-lines?lq=1)

and

[Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets)

and

[How can I make hatching filling of plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-can-i-make-hatching-filling-of-plot)

but none seems to address this situation. They seem to be dealing with shapes and (region)plots and not ListPlots. While it is entirely possible that they are very closely related, I'm not sure how to use any of those answers for my situation.

Thanks

Comment: The image link is broken.

Comment: I updated it a few minutes ago, and it seems to be working for me. Is it still not working? Is it possible that my edit hasn't updated yet? @Szabolcs

Comment: It's working now.  Please use's SE's image hosting if possible (I do not know if it's possible for new users).

Comment: What I'd try is using the approach shown in the posts you linked, especially the last one.  These rely on having a function to plot, not discrete data.  You have discrete data, however, you can convert it to a function using `Interpolation`.  Set `InterpolationOrder -> 1` if that's what you need (this is what `List(Line)Plot` does).

Comment: @Szabolcs The use of the interpolation function and the last linked question worked well and seemed pretty easy and short to implement. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TWJcY.png) is the new figure.

Comment: And in case anyone else is wondering how to easily upload Mathematic graphics, see the question [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes/32#32).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Mathematica 12.1 it is possible to do this with `HatchFilling`:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{15 - x, 2 Sin[x] + x}, {x, 0, 15, 0.1}], 
    PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> Bottom, 
    FillingStyle -> {1 -> HatchFilling[-Pi/4], 2 -> HatchFilling[Pi/4]}, 
    Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Of course, the hashing can be styled in many ways.

Answer (score 12):

This is what I've ended up doing.

```
data1 = exPDMIABSA[[1]];
data2 = exPDMIAwater[[1]];
Show[ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Black], Black}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, FillingStyle -> Gray], 
 RegionPlot[
  y < Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] && y > 0, {x, 
   300, 375}, {y, 0, 17000}, Mesh -> 50, MeshFunctions -> {1000 #1 - #2 &}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> Thickness[.005], 
  PlotStyle -> Transparent]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The RegionPlot is based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-can-i-make-hatching-filling-of-plot) question after a suggestion in the comments to the question by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).

Of course the same could be done for the other region in the opposite direction by switching the sign in the `MeshFunctions`. Also, because of the scale, the slope of the `MeshFunctions` was changed. The number of hatchings can be changed by changing `Mesh`. The default lines were a little thin for me so I thickened them with `MeshStyle -> Thickness[.005]`.

For certain circumstances, it might be easier to define interpolation functions for each data set such as `data1func = Interpolation[data1, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` and just `Plot` that.

To me this seemed a little simpler, faster, and more general than the answer by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) to this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the fastest way but I think it is fast and short enough. And, first of all, clear.

```
dat = RandomReal[2, 10];
dat2 = RandomReal[2, 10];
poly = ListLinePlot[{dat, dat2}, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel@.5
       ] // Normal // Cases[#, Polygon[x_] :> x, \[Infinity]] &;

inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0

With[{copt = Sequence[MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> Black,
                      Mesh -> {Range[0, 15, .1]}, MeshStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> None]},
 Show[
  Quiet@RegionPlot[ inPolyQ[poly[[1]], {x, y}], {x, 0, 11}, {y, -.1, 2.1}, 
                    MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &}, copt],
  Quiet@RegionPlot[ inPolyQ[poly[[2]], {x, y}], {x, 0, 11}, {y, -.1, 2.1}, 
                    MeshFunctions -> {# - #2 &}, copt],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600]]
```

[image]

Based on:

[RegionPlot (or FillingStyle) using hash lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7730/5478) by [Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46/heike)

and

[How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/5478) by [rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf)

Comment: Thanks @Kuba! That is a pretty graphic. I think I'll go with @Szabolcs suggestion in the comments to the question as that seems easier to me, and I understand it better. I might just post it as my own answer for others who might be wondering.