# For "RegionPlot", how to fill lines, points, or grids in different areas?

Tags: plotting, regions, mesh, graphics

For "RegionPlot", how to fill lines, points, or grids in different areas?

I have tried "Mesh", but it fills all region in same mesh.

I want to get the result just like this picture,

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your expression about the regions.

Answer (score 14):

```
regions = {(x - 2)^2 < (y - 2)^3 + 1, (x - 2)^2 > (y - 2)^3 + 1 && 
    y > x - 3, y < Min[2, x - 3], x - 3 > y > 2 && x > 5};
```

You can specify `PlotStyle` using [`PatternFiling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFiling.html):

```
plotstyles = MapThread[PatternFilling[{#, #2}, ImageScaled[#3]] &, 
    {{"Diamond", "HalftoneGrid", "Grid", "Chevron"}, 
    ColorData[97] /@ Range[4], {1/40, 1/40, 1/40, 1/50}}];

RegionPlot[regions, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 700, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend["Expressions", LegendMarkerSize -> 40], 
  PlotStyle -> plotstyles] /. 
 s_SwatchLegend :> (s /. ImageScaled[a_] :> ImageScaled[10 a])
```

[image]

Replace the last entry in `plotstyles` with [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html):

```
plotstyles[[4]] = Directive[ColorData[97] @ 4, HatchFilling["Horizontal"]];
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think it's perfect, is this specific to 13? I'm still using 12, and maybe I need to update.

Comment: @hu_rrr, `HatchFilling` and `PatternFilling`  were introduced in version 12.1

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot.

Comment: @hu_rrr, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: May I ask what the meaning of /. s_SwatchLegend :> (s /. ImageScaled[a_] :> ImageScaled[10 a])?

Comment: @HANGYU, this piece of code replaces any expression with head `SwatchLegend` (`s_SwatchLegend`) with  a new expression  where subexpressions in `s` that match the pattern `ImageScaled[something]` are replaced with `ImageScaled[10 something]` (see [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in the docs)

Comment: @kglr, oh, I see, thank you very much, this command adjusts the Legends and makes them more clear.

Answer (score 5):

If it is good enough for you, you may fill with colors, using the option `Filling`:

```
Plot[{Sin[2 x], 1 + x^2, 2 + x}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I also want to get 3 regions that are "color1+line/point/mesh1","color2+line/point/mesh1", and "color1+line/point/mesh2".

Comment: Related,  see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49202/hatched-filling-for-listplot/49206#49206

Comment: I have understood, thank you very much!!!