# Single RegionPlot with different mesh functions

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a set of inequations, which i'd like to plot as different regions with RegionPlot, which I defined by:

```
a = {-15 + p + q >= 0};
b = {4 p + q, 4 q + p, 20 - p, -10 + 5 q};
regions = Table[And[Not @@ a, And @@ (b <=  i // Thread)], {i, b}];
```

Then I'm plotting them like this:

```
RegionPlot[{a, regions}, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {p, q}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 &}, Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[Automatic, Prepend[b, "Infeasible: " And @@ a], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}]]
```

This produces:

[image: example]

Now, I'd actually like the mesh to only be applied to the first region (the one marked Infeasible), but instead it seems to be applied to the combinations of the regions plotted.

I know that it should be possible to `Show`, but then I don't see how I can combine the plots, create a proper Legend, which combines all parts of the plots. When I also to create a list of RegionPlots, I could not save the result of the RegionPlot (it simply showed up as Null).

Related questions, that don't quite answer my issue:

- [Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets)
  [Making a rectangular label for RegionPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41963/making-a-rectangular-label-for-regionplot)
- [RegionPlot (or FillingStyle) using hash lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/regionplot-or-fillingstyle-using-hash-lines) (this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/regionplot-or-fillingstyle-using-hash-lines#answer-7730) came closest)

As a bonus, if you can show me at the same time how to make the line-spacing of the mesh independent of the size of the region, that would be greatly appreciated too.

Comment: Your code produces a different outcome than the plot you posted: http://imgur.com/a/tk9bP. Also, the `PlotLegends -> ....` is irrelevant for the question asked. Finally, I'm quite surprised that `MeshFunctions -> 
 ConditionalExpression[{#1 + #2 &, #1 &}, -15 + #1 + #2 >= 0 &]` (and its variations) doesn't work.

Comment: That's odd... even after clearing my globals, I still get a different plot than you. http://i.imgur.com/NOuHBEs.png As you see I'm using MM11.1 (on Windows 10). Were you under the impression that ConditionalExpression should have worked here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to draw the mesh in a second plot and draw it over the original one:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
  {a, regions}, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10},
  FrameLabel -> {p, q},
  MaxRecursion -> 3,
  PlotLegends -> 
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, Prepend[b, "Infeasible: " And @@ a], 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}]
  ],
 RegionPlot[
  a, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10},
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 &},
  Mesh -> {Range[0, 20, 1]},
  MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}]
 ]
```

[image]

The code above also demonstrates how to achieve size independent mesh spacing. The only thing to watch out for is that you might need to adjust the bounds of the `Range` to cover the values returned by your mesh functions.

Comment: That is great. Somehow I messed up the Legends call, by adding it to the second one.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** It turns out we can use a simple modifications of the option setting in OP for `MeshFunctions` to get the desired result:

**1. Boole:**

```
RegionPlot[{a, regions}, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10},
 FrameLabel -> {p, q}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Boole[# + #2 >= 15] (#1 + #2) &, Boole[# + #2 >= 15] #1 &}, 
 Mesh -> {30, 20}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic, Prepend[b, "Infeasible: " And @@ a], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, specify  a list of values for each mesh function using, for example, `Mesh -> {Range[15, 30, .5], Range[0, 10, .25]}` to get

[image]

**2. Piecewise:**

We can also use

```
MeshFunctions -> {Piecewise[{{#1 + #2, # + #2 >= 15}}] &, 
  Piecewise[{{#1, # + #2 >= 15}}] &}
```

to get the same result.

**3. ConditionalExpression:**

Finally, we can use `ConditionalExpression` if we use list of values for the `Mesh` option setting (and increase `PlotPoints` to remove artifacts):

```
RegionPlot[{a, regions}, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10},
 FrameLabel -> {p, q}, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[#1 + #2, # + #2 >= 15] &, 
   ConditionalExpression[#1, # + #2 >= 15] &}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 20, .5], Range[0, 10, .5]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends ->  SwatchLegend[Automatic, Prepend[b, "Infeasible: " And @@ a], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

An alternative approach: Use [`Texture[img]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) as the `PlotStyle` setting for the desired regions using `img` of your choice:

```
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[4];

texture1 = Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]];

legendmarker1 = Graphics[{texture1, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> Automatic]}];

RegionPlot[{a, regions}, {p, 0, 10}, {q, 0, 10}, FrameLabel -> {p, q},
 MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotStyle -> Prepend[colors, texture1],
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> (Rescale[{#, #2}, {0, 10}/2] &),
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Prepend[colors, texture1], 
   Prepend[b, Row[{"Infeasible:  ", And @@ a}]], 
   LegendMarkers -> Prepend[ConstantArray[Automatic, Length@b], legendmarker1],
   LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}]]
```

[image]

To use a hatched image instead of `"Mandrill"`, you can use a simplified version of the function `hatchingF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64178/125)

```
ClearAll[hatchedTexture]
hatchedTexture[ps_: None, cols_: {Red, Orange}, m_: {10, 10}, 
  t_: AbsoluteThickness[5]] := 
 RegionPlot[True, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &, # &}, Mesh -> m, MeshShading -> None, 
  MeshStyle -> (Directive[t, #] & /@ cols), Frame -> False, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotStyle -> ps, BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[], 
  BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

Replace `texture1` and `legendmarker1` above with

```
texture2 = Texture[Rasterize @ hatchedTexture[]];
legendmarker2 = Graphics[{texture2, Polygon[coords = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> (coords/2)]}];
```

to get

[image]

Use `texture2 = Texture[Rasterize @ hatchedTexture[LightBlue]]` to get

[image]

Use `texture2 = Texture[Rasterize @ hatchedTexture[texture1, {Black, Black}]]` if you wish to be cruel and put `"Mandrill"` behind bars:

[image]