# Save selection as PDF - non-image format

Tags: output-formatting, pdf-format

I am trying to save the following plot as a pdf, so that I can import it into LaTeX:

```
Grid[{{RegionPlot[{x<y,x>y},{x,-2-1/10,2+1/10},{y,-1/10,3+1/10},PlotPoints->20,PlotStyle->{Texture[Graphics[Table[Circle[{i,j},1/4],{i,20},{j,20}]]],Texture[Graphics[Table[Polygon[{{1+i,0+j},{0+i,Sqrt[3]+j},{-1+i,0+j}}],{i,2,80,4},{j,2,80,4}]]]},BoundaryStyle->Black,PlotRange->{{-2,2},{0,3}},ImageSize->350],Grid[{{Graphics[Table[Circle[{i,j},1/4],{i,3},{j,3}],ImageSize->30,Frame->True,FrameTicks->None],"(Min, Min) & (Mix, Max)"},{Graphics[Table[Polygon[{{1+i,0+j},{0+i,Sqrt[3]+j},{-1+i,0+j}}],{i,2,10,4},{j,2,10,4}],ImageSize->30,Frame->True,FrameTicks->None],"(Mix, Max)"}},Spacings->{1,1/2}]}},Spacings->{2,1}]
```

However, if I right-click on the output and click 'save selection as', the pdf I get changes the `RegionPlot` into a image (probably jpeg). However, it does manage to keep the `Graphics`, to the right of the `RegionPlot`, as a non-image pdf code.

I believe this is due to the function `Texture`, which turns the `Graphics` inside `Texture` into an image.

How can I get the full output into non-image pdf code?

Comment: As you say, it's because of `Texture`. The reason is that `Texture` always rasterizes its input. So this is not a problem with `Save Selection` but with the way the original `RegionPlot` is created. You have to choose a different approach to create the main plot. This would probably involve the answers here: [Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3723/245).

Comment: Thanks! I managed by making clever use of polygons.

Answer (score -1):

plt1 = Grid[{{RegionPlot[{x < y, x > y}, {x, -2 - 1/10, 
      2 + 1/10}, {y, -1/10, 3 + 1/10}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
     PlotStyle -> {Texture[
        Graphics[Table[Circle[{i, j}, 1/4], {i, 20}, {j, 20}]]], 
       Texture[Graphics[
         Table[Polygon[{{1 + i, 0 + j}, {0 + i, Sqrt[3] + j}, {-1 + i,
              0 + j}}], {i, 2, 80, 4}, {j, 2, 80, 4}]]]}, 
     BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 3}}, 
     ImageSize -> 350], 
    Grid[{{Graphics[Table[Circle[{i, j}, 1/4], {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 
        ImageSize -> 30, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None], 
       "(Min, Min) & (Mix, Max)"}, {Graphics[
        Table[Polygon[{{1 + i, 0 + j}, {0 + i, Sqrt[3] + j}, {-1 + i, 
            0 + j}}], {i, 2, 10, 4}, {j, 2, 10, 4}], ImageSize -> 30, 
        Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None], "(Mix, Max)"}}, 
     Spacings -> {1, 1/2}]}}, Spacings -> {2, 1}];

Export["Desktop/example.pdf", plt1]

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.