# Weird behaviour of HighlightImage—bug or not?

Tags: graphics, bugs, image-processing, image

For background, check my answer under [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120972/6084).

It is clearly stated in the documentation of `HighlightImage` that the 2nd argument,`roi`, (region of interest) can be any form of `Graphics` primitives. So, in my interpretation, all sorts of things that can be presented in `Graphics` shall work here.

It seems that in most occasions, this rule works quite well, but check this:

```
img=Graphics[FilledCurve[{{Line[{Scaled[{0.66, 0.21}], 
  Scaled[{0.83, 0.5}], Scaled[{0.66, 0.78}], Scaled[{0.33, 0.78}],
   Scaled[{0.16, 0.5`}], 
  Scaled[{0.33, 0.21}]}]}, {Line[{Scaled[{0.58, 0.35}], 
  Scaled[{0.66, 0.5`}], Scaled[{0.58, 0.64}], 
  Scaled[{0.41, 0.64}], Scaled[{0.33, 0.5`}], 
  Scaled[{0.41, 0.35}]}]}}]]

HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], img, {"Desaturate", .7}]
```

[image: problem]

I suppose the result image of `HighlightImage` shall desaturate the part inside and outside the `FilledCurve`, but in fact, `HighlightImage` seemingly ignore `FilledCurve`'s filling totally and highlighted only the edge part. Weird. Is this a bug?

---

The second problem is even more serious and wierder.

Maybe we can say `HighlightImage` will failed to recognize `FilledCurve` or so, but It can, of course, recognize `Disk`:

```
HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], 
 Disk[Scaled@{1/2, 1/2}, Scaled[1/4]], {"Lighten", .7}]
```

[image: img1]

But simply a style change will make it fail: change "Lighten" to "Blur"

```
HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], 
 Disk[Scaled@{1/2, 1/2}, Scaled[1/4]], {"Blur", 3}]
```

[image: img2]

Even more weird.

---

**So, is this a bug or I wrote the code in a wrong way? How can I fix it?**

Comment: I think maybe not a bug.Just because of the white part in the margin

Comment: The FilledCurve example is a bug. Filed.
The last one is not. If I do `HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], 
 Disk[Scaled@{1, 1/2}, Scaled[1/4]], {"Blur", 20}]` I can clearly see the blurred blue disk.

Comment: I now agree that there is a bug in `HighlightImage`

Comment: I have also reported the issue to Wolfram Research tech support. I will update my answer further when I receive an answer from them.

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is sloppy documentation, rather than an implementation bug. A lot of current documentation is incomplete, misleading, or just plain wrong. Here is another example of bad documentation taken from `HighlightImage`.

> The following wrappers can be used
>   ...
>   $\qquad$`Tooltip[e, label]        attach an arbitrary tooltip to the element`

But it doesn't tell us what an 'element' is. One might reasonably assume tha a tooltip could be attached to either the 1st or the 2nd argument, but it turns out that only the 2nd (the region-of-interest) can take a tooltip.

I demonstrate this using your filled curve. Note, I also give a work-around for the region-of-interest issue you raise.

```
roi = 
  Graphics[
    {White,
     FilledCurve[
       {{Line[
          {Scaled[{0.66, 0.21}], Scaled[{0.83, 0.5}], Scaled[{0.66, 0.78}], 
           Scaled[{0.33, 0.78}], Scaled[{0.16, 0.5`}], Scaled[{0.33, 0.21}]}]}, 
        {Line[
          {Scaled[{0.58, 0.35}], Scaled[{0.66, 0.5`}], Scaled[{0.58, 0.64}], 
           Scaled[{0.41, 0.64}], Scaled[{0.33, 0.5`}], Scaled[{0.41, 0.35}]}]}}]];
mask = Image[roi];
HighlightImage[
  Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], Tooltip[mask, "region of interest"], {"Desaturate", .7}]
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[
  Tooltip[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], "not interesting"], mask, {"Desaturate", .7}]
```

[image: error]

#### Update

Wjx's comment below got me thinking about this problem again. What set me off is the statement, "I'm just wondering why it will failed to recognize the 'inside part' of an graphics object." I knew that was wrong because adding a tooltip wrapper clearly shows that recognizing the 'inside part' is not causing the failure. The region-of-interest is being recognized correctly. Try

```
HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], 
  Tooltip[roi, "region of interest"], {"Desaturate", .7}]
```

and see for yourself. So I wondered what would happen if I did't specify a 3rd argument, but accepted the default background styling.

```
HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], Tooltip[roi, "region of interest"]]
```

[image]

Well, this version works as expected. Now that is really weird.

So I recant my theory that Wjx has been misled by sloppy documentation. I now take the stand that there is a bug, but not the bug Wjx suggested. The work-around is still to make a mask of the region-of-interest from the vector graphics.

Comment: Are you certain you are answering the question at hand? It's not about `Tooltip`, but rather improper highlighting of a region specified with `FilledCurve`. At least as far as I understand...

Comment: @kirma. I think I answered the question. I'm arguing that there is no implementation bug, but that rather the OP was mislead by bad docs. The application of a tooltip is just another example of where the docs on `HighlightImage` can not be trusted. Also, you might note that the example I gave also gives a work-around to the OP's problem.

Comment: `HighlightImage[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], Disk[Scaled[{1, 1}/2], Scaled[1/4]], {"Desaturate", .7}]` performs correct highlighting, but `FilledCurve` doesn't. There might be something I don't exactly understand about your answer... :o

Comment: @kirma. Yes, there might be, but I don't know what. The OP says the docs imply that any graphics object can be used, and I agree that's what the docs say. But I say, "Don't trust the docs; only some graphics objects work".

Comment: It may not be stated in the notes, but the syntax box lists `HighlightImage[image,{\[Ellipsis],w[Subscript[roi, i]],\[Ellipsis]}]`.

Comment: Yes, converting graphics into image will solve the problem, but at a low speed. It may due to the poor ducumentation, but I'm just wondering why it will failed to recognize the 'inside part' of an graphics object.