# How to increase the thickness of the edge in a random image

Tags: image-processing

This is a Voronoi Diagram. I really want to know how to change the thickness of the "wall" of each V-cell, in another words, the thickness of the edge in this diagram. [image: Voronoi Cell for 500 random dots]

Comment: [Here](http://www.locationequipmentsupply.com/img/products/LES-0322-L-Magic-Marker-Magnum-Black.jpg) or `MinFilter[img, 2]`

Comment: How did you make the diagram? I don't think you much chance of getting a useful response if you don't add the code you used to generate the diagram to your post.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/animating-a-voronoi-diagram  That is how I make the diagram.

Comment: @Ciao That is so useful. Thanks!

Comment: I vote to leave this question open for nikie's answer if nothing else.  I hadn't realized the importance of using `DiskMatrix` in a case like this until now.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Erosion[image, DiskMatrix[radius]]`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVmnm.jpg"];
Erosion[img, DiskMatrix[2]]
```

[image]

Intuitively, you can imagine that this places a disk with radius 2 at every black pixel. If you're more concerned about speed than accuracy, you can also use `Erosion[image, radius]` which places a *square* with some radius at every black pixel - which of course makes diagonal lines thicker than horizontal or vertical lines:

```
circle = Image[
   Rasterize[Graphics[{Circle[]}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5]], 
   ImageSize -> All];
Row[{Labeled[Erosion[circle, DiskMatrix[10]], 
   "Erosion[...,Disk[10]]"], 
  Labeled[Erosion[circle, 10], 
   "Erosion[..., 10] or MinFilter[..., 10]"]}]
```

[image]

Note: `MinFilter` seems to do mostly the same thing `Erosion` does, except it can only use rectangular masks. The differences between `MinFilter` and `Erosion` seem to be:

- `Erosion` can use non-rectangular structuring elements (like `Disk` above)
- `MinFilter` can process `TimeSeries` data
- for color images `Erosion` processes each channel separately, while `MinFilter` replaces each pixel with the (r,g,b) value of the darkest pixel in the neighborhood.

(There may be more differences - I had to guess these these from the documentation. No idea why there is no mention in each function's "Properties and Relations" section. IMHO, `MinFilter` could have been implemented as `Method` option to `Erosion` instead of a new function.)