# How to quickly calculate intersections of filled curves?

Tags: graphics, algorithm, performance-tuning

I am trying to quickly calculate the intersection of polygons with more than 6,000 points. A compiled solution would be preferable.

Here is one example of the problem:

```
o = First[
       First[ImportString[
         ExportString[
          Style["O", Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
          "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];

p = First[
   First[ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Style["P", Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
      "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], ColorData["Crayola", "Sunglow"], {o, p}}]
```

Another:

```
    Module[{a = FilledCurve[{{Line[{{2, 3}, {0.8125, 0.625}}],
      BezierCurve[{{0.6875, 0.375}, {0.375, 0.25}, {1.125, 0.25}}, 
       SplineDegree -> 2], 
      BezierCurve[{{0.8125, 0.375}, {0.9375, 0.625}}],
      Line[{{1.3125, 1.375}, {2.4375, 1.375}, {2.8125, 0.625}}],
      BezierCurve[{{2.9375, 0.375}, {2.625, 0.25}, {3.625, 0.25}}, 
       SplineDegree -> 2], 
      BezierCurve[{{3.3125, 0.375}, {3.1875, 0.625}}]},
     {Line[{{1.875, 2.5}, {1.375, 1.5}, {2.375, 1.5}}]}}]}, 
 Graphics[Table[{EdgeForm[Black], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    Translate[Rotate[Scale[a, RandomReal[5]], RandomReal[2 Pi]], 
     RandomReal[20, {2}]]}, {30}]]]
```

**So in the problem is:** how to intersect of multiple (or two at a time) polygons (with or without) holes (and with up to 6000 points in their triangulations)?

I have tried using the [Weiler–Atherton clipping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler-Atherton_clipping_algorithm) but my implementation was too slow (anything relying on bitmaps is too slow). Perhaps there is a solution that uses LibraryLink to harness a standard library? I found one here http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/gpc.html

### Updates

It was suggested in the comments that Graphics`Mesh` be used but this is way too slow in even 100 points and doesn't handle holes:

```
a = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
b = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
AbsoluteTiming[c = Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection[a, b]]
Graphics[{Blue, a, Red, b, Yellow, Polygon /@ List @@ c}]
```

[image]

Here is a sample input polygon for the letter G:

```
 G = Polygon[{{-0.466796, -0.0328696}, {-0.466336, 0.0186753}, {-0.463089, 
   0.0682893}, {-0.459379, 0.100181}, {-0.451495, 
   0.146241}, {-0.444693, 0.175763}, {-0.432171, 0.21827}, {-0.422278,
    0.245423}, {-0.411147, 0.271628}, {-0.39878, 0.296886}, {-0.37791,
    0.332996}, {-0.362451, 0.355885}, {-0.345756, 
   0.377826}, {-0.327823, 0.398819}, {-0.300607, 
   0.426707}, {-0.281598, 0.443668}, {-0.251786, 
   0.466663}, {-0.231046, 0.480362}, {-0.198638, 
   0.498465}, {-0.176168, 0.508902}, {-0.141165, 
   0.522112}, {-0.116964, 0.529288}, {-0.0793649, 
   0.537605}, {-0.0534337, 0.541519}, {-0.013239, 
   0.544944}, {0.0144228, 0.545596}, {0.0521431, 
   0.544603}, {0.0973423, 0.540566}, {0.140374, 0.533423}, {0.181237, 
   0.523175}, {0.212366, 0.512741}, {0.249327, 0.496903}, {0.283288, 
   0.47845}, {0.310993, 0.459561}, {0.336333, 0.438254}, {0.359309, 
   0.414528}, {0.379921, 0.388384}, {0.398168, 0.359821}, {0.414052, 
   0.328839}, {0.427571, 0.295438}, {0.438725, 0.259618}, {0.444849, 
   0.234395}, {0.449921, 0.208096}, {0.309296, 0.208096}, {0.299494, 
   0.244597}, {0.29219, 0.264834}, {0.283819, 0.283824}, {0.267496, 
   0.312703}, {0.256279, 0.328367}, {0.243996, 0.342784}, {0.235215, 
   0.351703}, {0.221153, 0.364041}, {0.206024, 0.375133}, {0.189953, 
   0.385077}, {0.161346, 0.399325}, {0.14309, 0.406478}, {0.124015, 
   0.412584}, {0.0904026, 0.420435}, {0.0691431, 0.42375}, {0.0470644,
    0.426018}, {0.00844619, 0.427471}, {-0.0284694, 
   0.425533}, {-0.0551123, 0.421535}, {-0.0892443, 
   0.412813}, {-0.121786, 0.400214}, {-0.152737, 
   0.383739}, {-0.182097, 0.363387}, {-0.209866, 
   0.339158}, {-0.235987, 0.311056}, {-0.248019, 
   0.295569}, {-0.259191, 0.279133}, {-0.269503, 
   0.261747}, {-0.278956, 0.243411}, {-0.291525, 
   0.214127}, {-0.298829, 0.193418}, {-0.305275, 
   0.171759}, {-0.313331, 0.137489}, {-0.321066, 
   0.0884734}, {-0.325362, 
   0.0356589}, {-0.32624, -0.0188127}, {-0.324105, -0.0667413}, \
{-0.319123, -0.112199}, {-0.311294, -0.155187}, {-0.300618, \
-0.195705}, {-0.294213, -0.215037}, {-0.28327, -0.242878}, \
{-0.270726, -0.269329}, {-0.25151, -0.302436}, {-0.235136, \
-0.325433}, {-0.216766, -0.346138}, {-0.196376, -0.3645}, {-0.173967, \
-0.380518}, {-0.149538, -0.394191}, {-0.123089, -0.405521}, \
{-0.104334, -0.411771}, {-0.0846818, -0.41698}, {-0.0535202, \
-0.422841}, {-0.0203389, -0.426357}, {0.0148622, -0.427529}, \
{0.0509528, -0.426065}, {0.0853497, -0.421672}, {0.118053, \
-0.414352}, {0.149062, -0.404104}, {0.171208, -0.394496}, {0.1924, \
-0.383241}, {0.212641, -0.370339}, {0.231928, -0.35579}, {0.250217, \
-0.339572}, {0.266916, -0.321406}, {0.281843, -0.301207}, {0.290811, \
-0.286611}, {0.302785, -0.263022}, {0.312987, -0.237399}, {0.321418, \
-0.209743}, {0.326054, -0.190175}, {0.331531, -0.159129}, {0.334198, \
-0.137302}, {0.336722, -0.102866}, {0.337421, -0.0787786}, {0.174296, \
-0.0787786}, {0.0111708, -0.0787786}, {0.0111708, 
   0.0393464}, {0.238983, 0.0393464}, {0.466796, 
   0.0393464}, {0.466796, -0.517529}, {0.377235, -0.517529}, \
{0.343661, -0.386923}, {0.320697, -0.411362}, {0.294314, -0.43722}, \
{0.26921, -0.459296}, {0.245385, -0.477589}, {0.222841, -0.492099}, \
{0.200503, -0.503935}, {0.174026, -0.515381}, {0.145794, -0.524995}, \
{0.108033, -0.534437}, {0.0758485, -0.539931}, {0.0331483, \
-0.544223}, {-0.0029876, -0.545596}, {-0.0362581, -0.545124}, \
{-0.0713561, -0.542341}, {-0.10544, -0.537172}, {-0.138509, \
-0.529619}, {-0.170564, -0.51968}, {-0.191371, -0.511729}, \
{-0.211727, -0.502717}, {-0.231632, -0.492646}, {-0.260644, \
-0.475551}, {-0.279422, -0.462829}, {-0.29775, -0.449047}, \
{-0.315626, -0.434205}, {-0.324396, -0.426386}, {-0.34277, \
-0.405934}, {-0.367955, -0.373398}, {-0.390289, -0.338633}, \
{-0.403595, -0.314218}, {-0.415633, -0.288813}, {-0.426404, \
-0.262417}, {-0.440185, -0.220965}, {-0.447788, -0.192092}, \
{-0.456817, -0.146926}, {-0.461252, -0.115577}, {-0.465529, \
-0.0666954}, {-0.466796, -0.0328696}}];
```

Comment: Great question! I've often wondered this myself...

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/non-convex-polygon-union-and-intersection-functions only solved unions

Comment: The library you point to appears to be an outstanding option, particularly if you think you'll need to solve this problem many times and quickly each time. As a library, one could probably link to it relatively easily via a MathLink program.  Also, the parent page points to a java port, which could be linked to via JLink. Both of those options would take a bit of time, though. (By parent page, I mean here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090213122910/http://www.seisw.com/GPCJ/GPCJ.html

Comment: What about using some existing java routine, see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution/6376#6376, http://sourceforge.net/projects/geom-java/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20090213122910/http://www.seisw.com/GPCJ/GPCJ.html

Comment: There`s ``Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection`` to check out perhaps?

Comment: @rojo thanks, I looked at that but it doesn't work well enough.

Comment: @s0rce I'm on OSX 10.8 and when I run the reloader I get the error: JCompileLoad::cmperr: The following compilation errors were encountered: sh: /Users/tw/Documents/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Java/MacOSX-x86-64/bin/javac: No such file or directory

Comment: @s0rce Has anyone on Mac been able to get that reloader working?

Comment: I suggest that a custom program using openCL 2D mode to do all the tests in parallel might be a viable solution.  [Go here for video introduction.](http://developer.amd.com/Resources/documentation/videos/OpenCLTechnicalOverviewVideoSeries/Pages/default.aspx)

Comment: @freddaneilkline Opencllink is very dicey, even simple questions on this are difficult to answer. Not to mention he probably wants a solution that is device independent.

Comment: @M.R., I posted my comment as an answer because I wasn't aware of your comment. (name misspelled)

Comment: Some of these links are broken or very old. I'd sugest if someone knows the algorithm it would be useful to summarise here for archive purpose instead of just using links.

Comment: I think it's more difficult in your examples than just calculating intersection of polygons because of involving Bezier/spline curves in almost all modern computer fonts.

Answer (score 14):

`` Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection[] `` is not documented; it builds full polygon triangulations. To handle holes, you can use:

```
PolygonIntersection[a, b, FillingMethod -> "OddEvenRule"]
```

or

```
PolygonIntersection[a, b, FillingMethod -> "WindingRule"]
```

To create the visualization:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
a = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
b = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
c = Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection[a, b, FillingMethod -> "OddEvenRule"];
Graphics[{Blue, Opacity[.5], a, Red, Opacity[.5], b, EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Yellow], 
          Polygon /@ List @@ c}]
```

[image: intersections of two self-intersecting polygons]

Comment: @rm-rf Alternatively, executing ``Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]`` loads the full context, including any dependencies.

Comment: Hey Ulises! Welcome to the party! Got any more hidden gems for us?

Comment: Right, `PolygonIntersection[]` is defined in the `Graphics\`Mesh\`` context. Just wanted to show which option needed to be set to make it more useful. As pointed out, it is not as fast as we want it to be, that is why is undocumented. Hi Yves!, if you are in town for the technology conference next month, we can discuss hidden and not so hidden features ...

Comment: @UlisesCervantes If I try ``Graphics`Mesh`PolygonIntersection[a, b, FillingMethod -> "OddEvenRule"]`` I get no result where `a` and `b` is defined by `Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]`!!

Comment: In Mathematica V8.0.4. (or even 8.0): Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
a = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
b = Polygon@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
c = PolygonIntersection[a, b, FillingMethod -> "OddEvenRule"];
Graphics[{Blue, a, Red, b, Yellow, Polygon /@ List @@ c}]      ![Valid XHTML](http://members.wolfram.com/ulises/images/polydiff.png).

Comment: The timing of the previous comment is around 1 order of magnitude slower versus the Java library mentioned before. Part of the reason is because these functions construct full triangulations of the polygons. By the way, sorry for the bad formatting in the previous answer, trying to figure out how to add an image...

Comment: @UlisesCervantes you should register, you can interact with the site better.

Answer (score 0):

I worked through this problem some years ago (Sorry I don't have mathematica code to share.)
It turns out the most efficient algorithm is the fairly obvious direct approach.
(assuming you want a 'precise' result..so rastering wont do)

1) compute all possible edge-edge intersections

2) decompose original polygons into edge sets on those boundaries

3) order edge sets by angle at each intersection point

4) construct sub-regions by following smallest angle at each intersection point

finally depending on what you want as output do an insideness test on each sub-region against the original input polygons.

The approaches discussed so far (meshing, etc) address the last parts, while for the problem posed with thousands of edges step 1 is by far the most expensive part of the calculation.  Meshing actually makes that worse as now you have a least 2-3 x as many edges to deal with.

Now for the original example (Not the random table thing) we have thousands of mostly small segments. For this case you  can dramatically reduce the O(N^2) edge-intersection problem by binning edges onto a regular grid and only check those edges that are near enough each other to possibly intersect.