# Efficiently determining if a morphological component overlaps a polygon with vertices at real number coordinates

Tags: image-processing, algorithm, geometry

I have a list of morphological components $m$, a set of vertices for a polytope $P$ (at real number coordinates), and I'd like to be able to calculate a list of morphological components $m'$ that anywhere overlap the area of $P$.  I can do this by approximating each pixel as a point, and calculating a winding number for these points with respect to $P$ to determine if they fall within the polygon's area.  However, this is hardly an efficient strategy, and it's not as exact as I would like.  My hope is to have a scheme to detect if the polygon crosses *any* square bright pixel region.  Is there a clever way to do this that works very quickly?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30631/5478

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the quickest approach will be to rasterize the polygon. For example

Create an example component matrix:

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@
    Rasterize[Graphics[Disk /@ RandomReal[{0, 20}, {40, 2}]], ImageSize -> {300, 300}]];

m // Colorize
```

[image]

Define the polygon and rasterize it:

```
poly = Polygon[{{50, 50}, {50, 250}, {200, 200}}];
polyimage = Binarize @ Graphics[poly, PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, {0, 300}}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Identify values in `m` which overlap with zeros in `polyimage` (excluding the background component)

```
overlaps = Complement[Flatten @ Pick[m, ImageData[polyimage], 0], {0}]
(* {6, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19} *)
```

Check that the identified components do indeed overlap the polygon:

```
ImageCompose[
 SelectComponents[m, "Label", MemberQ[overlaps, #] &] // Colorize, {polyimage, 0.3}]
```

[image]