# Define function that goes from one point to another parametrically

Tags: parametric-functions, piecewise

I have two points p1 and p2, and I want to get the parametric equation of a linear function that passes through those, but ranging from one point to another.

For example, if I have 2 points {0,0} and {1,1/2}, the equation would be {t,t/2}.

> The goal of having a **parametric equation** is to have the function defined even when the slope is $\infty$.

I tried this (here the angle[] function is [Atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), is basically [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArcTan.html) but ranging from 0-2π):

```
Piecewise[
 {
  {{t, Last@p1 + Tan@angle[p1, p2] (t - First@p1)}, 
   Min[First@p1, First@p2] <= t && t <= Max[First@p1, First@p2]},
  {{First@p1, t}, First@p1 == First@p2}
  },
 Indeterminate
 ]
```

But when a point is on top of the other the function is a vertical line, ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$; I would only want the function to be defined from Last@p1 to Last@p2.

In other words, I want a Graphics' [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Line.html), but using parametric equations.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: `p1 + t (p2 - p1)` ?

Comment: @Kuba That gives the complete line. I want the line to be defined from one point to another, not outside.

Comment: @Arcotick You just got to restrict t to between 0 and 1. (You can use `Piecewise` for this.)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what do you want. Please specify arguments/domain and expected result/codomain.

Comment: @Pickett But I want the function itself to be undefined when 1<t<0

Comment: `line[t_] := p1 + t (p2 - p1) /; 0 <= t <= 1` but your question is still unclear. Please refer to my previous question. And focus on what you are writing.

Comment: Why can't you just use `Line` in your plot? You can insert `Graphics` into a plot with `Prolog` or 'Epilog`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Because I want to get the intersection point of that line and another function. And I need an equation for that.

Comment: You can still proceed with the function I've given, just `Solve`/`NMinimize` for `t1, t2` with restrictions. Also, take a look at [Line intersection algorithm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13712/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line[t_, p1_, p2_] := p1 + t (p2 - p1)

Solve[Join[
        {line[t1, {0, 0}, {1, 1}] == line[t2, {0, 1}, {1.2, 0}]},
        {0 <= t1 <= 1, 0 <= t2 <= 1}],
      {t1, t2}]
```

> ```
> {{t1 -> 0.545455, t2 -> 0.454545}}
> ```

```
{line[t1, {0, 0}, {1, 1}], line[t2, {0, 1}, {1.2, 0}]} /. %
```

> ```
> {{{0.545455, 0.545455}, 
>   {0.545455, 0.545455}}}
> ```

[Implementation of Balaban's Line intersection algorithm in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/implementation-of-balabans-line-intersection-algorithm-in-mathematica) is also very closely related.